# Javascript com Vetores de Objetos

Tags: javascript

```
var Carro = function(){
    var marca;
    var modelo;
    //this.setMarca = setMarca;
    this.setMarca = function(_marca){
        this.marca = _marca;
    }

    this.setModelo = function(_modelo){
        this.modelo = _modelo;
    }
    this.getMarca = function() {
        return this.marca;
    }
    this.getModelo = function(){
        return this.modelo;
    }

}

var carro = new Carro();
var marca = [];
var modelo = [];
var i;
var string = " ";
carro.setMarca("Volkswagen");   
carro.setModelo("Camaro");  
alert(carro.getMarca() + " " + carro.getModelo());

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    marca[i] = carro.getMarca() + " " + i;
    modelo[i] = carro.getModelo() + " " + i; 
    string = string.concat(marca[i] + "\n");        
    string = string.concat(modelo[i] + "\n");   
}
alert(string);
```

eu tenho uma classe do tipo carro, nele tem getters e setters pra marca e o modelo.

tem como guardar os dados em um só vetor? eu separei em dois vetores assim:

```
var marca = [];
var modelo = [];
```

existe uma outra maneira de juntar ambos os dados em um só vetor?
por exemplo:

```
var car = [];
car|0|->marca = carro.getMarca();
car|0|->modelo = carro.getModelo();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já possui uma classe `Carro`, tudo o que você precisa fazer é instanciá-la e guardar os itens no seu vetor:

```
var car = [];
car[0] = new Carro(); // Novo carro na posição 1
car[1] = new Carro(); // Novo carro na posição 2
car.push(new Carro()); // Novo carro na última posição
```

Então você pode acessá-los como quer:

```
car[0].setMarca("xxx");
car[2].getModelo();
```

Algumas outras coisas que observei no seu código:

- O `var marca; var modelo;` no início do seu construtor é desnecessário - você está simplesmente criando duas variáveis locais, que não são acessadas em lugar algum. Você até *poderia* usá-las para fazer encapsulamento, dessa forma:

  ```
  var Carro = function(){
      var marca; // Privado, pois somente é acessível dentro do código do construtor
      this.setMarca = function(_marca){
          marca = _marca; // Pode acessar marca, pois está num closure
      }
      this.getMarca = function() {
          return marca; // Pode acessar marca, pois está num closure
      }
  }
  ```
- Se você deseja mesmo usar *getters* e *setters*, mas não quer encapsular os dados num [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215) (como no exemplo acima), é mais eficiente colocar esses métodos no [*prototype*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44191/215). Assim você evita fazer uma cópia deles para cada objeto `Carro`, existindo uma única cópia compartilhada por todos os objetos:

  ```
  function Carro() { }
  Carro.prototype.setMarca = function(_marca) {
      this.marca = _marca;
  };
  Carro.prototype.getMarca = function() {
      return this.marca;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, cada posição do vetor pode ser um objeto:

```
var marcaModelo = [];
for ( var i = 0, ii = carros.length; i < ii; i++ ) {
    marcaModelo.push({
        marca: carros.getMarca(),
        modelo: carros.getModelo()
    });
}
```

E você pode acessar os dados no vetor do seguinte modo:

```
console.log(marcaModelo[0].marca, marcaModelo[0].modelo);
```

Provavelmente você terá dados duplicados (objetos com a mesma marca e modelo em mais que um índice do vetor). Fica como exercício navegar pelo vetor e apenas realizar a inserção sem criar duplicidade.