# O que é programação baseada em protótipos?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, protótipo

Lendo sobre javascript me deparei com o termo **programação baseada em protótipos**, e vi também que no [devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/orientacao-a-objetos-com-javascript/33718) afirmam que javascript é uma linguagem orientada a objetos baseada em protótipos.

Enfim gostaria de entender melhor o conceito de programação baseada em protótipos, onde ela se aplica, se possível com exemplos.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata de alguma dessas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44191/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141645/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126886/101

Comment: @bigown Eu pesquisei bastante antes de perguntar encontrei algumas que tu colocou aqui, mas realmente não tinha encontrado essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript tecnicamente não é a mesma pergunta mas a resposta me serve, devo excluir essa?

Comment: Oi Mathias, pode deixar esta pergunta aqui, ela é útil para ajudar outros a encontrar a resposta linkada (buscas podem trazer pra cá e a pessoa segue o link). Se tiver alguma dúvida sobre a minha resposta, comenta lá.