# Qual é a diferença entre criar um método dentro do construtor ou dentro da propriedade prototype?

Tags: javascript

Quando eu vejo o código JS de outros programadores alguns definem os métodos dentro dos próprios construtores outros definem os métodos na propriedade `prototype` como, por exemplo:

```
function Mouse() {
   this.btnLeft = function() { // Método no construtor.
       alert('Click 1');
   }
}

Mouse.prototype.btnRight = function() { // Método na propriedade prototype.
   alert('Click 2');
};
```

Qual é a diferença entre definir um método para um objeto no caso dos dois exemplos acima, entre o construtor e a propriedade `prototype`? existe alguma relevância em usar um ou outro?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44191/qual-a-diferença-entre-utilizar-o-metodo-da-classe-e-o-prototype-javascript Olá, pelo que pude entender pela resposta que achei no link acima a grande diferença é em questão de memória e de unicidade. também tem esse texto bem legal do DevMedia sobre prototype que talvez possa lhe ajudar ! https://www.devmedia.com.br/prototype-javascript/7063 Espero ter ajudado !!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a diferença entre utilizar o metodo da classe e o prototype Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44191/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-utilizar-o-metodo-da-classe-e-o-prototype-javascript)

Comment: Não é a diferença principal, mas no primeiro caso o btnLeft só existirá para instancias, ou seja manipular a "classe" para sobreescreve-la será impossivel da forma que você fez, já no segundo o prototype é o objeto da "classe" (estou chamando de classe mas não é bem o nome correto), então o prototipe retorna um objeto que se modificado irá representar para todas instancias existentes. Tem um pouco mais sobre isso, mas vou ver se não tem uma resposta já mais completa sobre o assunto.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento, porque na propriedade `prototype` mostra os métodos definidos, mas não as propriedades não era para demostrar tudo? já que na propriedade `prototype` é definido as coisas que serão herdadas?

Comment: Não é só isso, é bem mais, como disse no prototype o comportamento é diferente, no primeiro código só existe em instancias, no segundo existe um objeto que representa todas instancias de uma classe e até na classe (não na instancia) existirá um "objeto" dentro que representa a interface do que você descrever.

Answer (score 0):

Com o prototype, seus objetos compartilharam a mesma "tabela" de funções, (herdando as funções do prototype), enquanto que declarando as funções dentro do construtor ira criar ponteiro para cada tabela de cada instancia, permite você decidir com laços se declara ou não uma função, ou se ela vai ser diferente da de outra instancia, eles também poderão ser individualmente sobrescritos depois...

o prototype ajuda a padroniza e diminui o uso de memoria...embora seja bem pouco...

```
[Obj][Obj][Obj][Obj]
  v    v    v    v
[prototype (ponteiro para função_1) (ponteiro para função_2)]

[Obj (ponteiro para função_1) (ponteiro para função_2)]
[Obj (ponteiro para função_1) (ponteiro para função_2)]
[Obj (ponteiro para função_1) (ponteiro para função_2)]
[Obj (ponteiro para função_1) (ponteiro para função_2)]
```

então, o prototype seria o 'static' da classe, propriedades comum a todas as instâncias, como em uma linguagem C like..., mas como javascript é muito mais permissivo que uma linguagem compilada, é um pouco difícil comparar, espero ter ajudado..., embora parece um pouco confuso...

+OBS: propriedades também podem ser atribuídas ao prototype, uma vez que funções na verdade é que são tratadas como váriaveis em javascript.

oque torna o seguinte cenário possível:

```
var minha_string="string qualquer";
String.prototype.CONSTANTE_TEXTO = "TEXTO";
console.log(minha_string.CONSTANTE_TEXTO);
console.log("outra string".CONSTANTE_TEXTO);
//sim, os dois retornaram "TEXTO" ao console
```

e a adição de ganchos (**Hooks**) em codigos objetos já declarados, sem ter de acessar cada um, oque pode ser útil para descobrir como algum código funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Completando a resposta

quando um objeto recebe uma mensagem (para acessar um atributo ou um método), primeiramente é verificado se tal propriedade existe no objeto, caso não exista, ele vai no prototype para ver se existe

quando você altera o prototype, voce altera todas as instancias de uma classe / função

quando voce altera no construtor, você altera apenas para aquela instância

```
function A(val) { this.my_func = function() { return val; }};
A.prototype.my_func = function() { return "default"; };

a = new A(10);

A.prototype.my_other_func = function() { return "other"; };

a = new A(10);
b = new B(20);

a.my_func(); // retorna 10
a.my_other_func(); // retorna "other"
a.my_other_func = function () { return 100; };
a.my_other_func(); // retorna 100

b.my_func(); // retorna 20
b.my_other_func(); // retorna "other"
```

Observe que:

- a declaração de `my_other_func` foi feita após a instancia `a` ser inicializada e ainda funciona
- ainda posso alterar a instancia `a` sem problemas alterando o seus métodos
- alterações feitas à inst `a`não afetam a instância `b`