# Como retornar o número da posição do input dentro de um formulário?

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para recuperar a posição do input com javascript, quando ele for clicado.

Quando clicar no primeiro input, ele me retornaria o valor `0`; No segundo input, o valor `1`, e assim por diante. O objetivo final é conseguir executar o código dentro do `if`, mas somente quando a lista de input corresponder com apenas o input clicado/selecionado pelo usuário.

Segue o código para vocês verem como estou fazendo.

```js
var descendentes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-edit input");
//alert(descendentes.length); //Aqui ele retorna a quantidade de inputs que tenho, que são 3.
for(var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++){
  descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", function (e){
    //alert("Ok!"); 
    
    for(var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++){
      var clicado = document.forms[0].elements[i]; //É neta linha que tento retornar o número, mas ele me retorna outra coisa(Ele informa que é um objeto html)
      alert(clicado); //No caso aqui, exibiria o número do input clicado
      /*if(clicado == i){
        alert("Funcinou!");
      }*/ //O if, neste caso, caso eu clicar no input que eu desejo, eu entro numa seção de códigos para serem executados.
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<form class="form-edit">
  <div id="teste">
    Nome: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Idade: <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Lore: <select>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Ipsum</option>
      <option>Dolor </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você seguiu o caminho certo mas errou em um pequeno detalhe:

```
document.forms[0].elements[i]
```

vai retornar o *elemento* html. O índice correto é o próprio *i*.

```
  descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", function (e){
    for(var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++){
      var clicado = document.forms[0].elements[i]; // esse é o ELEMENTO clicado e não o índice
        if(clicado == this) { // elemento no índice i é igual ao elemento que foi clicado?
            alert(i); // sim! então o indice desse input é i
            break;
        }

    }
  });
```

Comment: Os outros comentários acima estão perfeitos também, mas o que eu compreendi foi o seu!
Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Seus loops aninhados estão redefinindo o valor de `i` e criando uma confusão. O correto nesse caso seria criar uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript) que capture o valor atual do loop mais externo, para não precisar fazer outro:

```js
var descendentes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-edit input");
//alert(descendentes.length); //Aqui ele retorna a quantidade de inputs que tenho, que são 3.
for(var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++){
  descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", criaListener(i));
}

function criaListener(i) {
    return function() {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="form-edit">
  <div id="teste">
    Nome: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Idade: <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Lore: <select>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Ipsum</option>
      <option>Dolor </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Se preferir, pode usar uma função imediatamente executada em vez de criar a `criaListener`:

```
descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", (function(iAtual){
    return function() {
        alert(iAtual);
    }
}(i)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer assim, procurando o elemento pai e escolhendo os inputs filhos. Podes ser mais generalista ou usar mesmo `el.parentNode.children`.
Mas se no código percorres todos os elementos para lhes adicionar o event handler, então a [ideia do bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46261/129) é a melhor.

```js
var descendentes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-edit input");
//alert(descendentes.length); //Aqui ele retorna a quantidade de inputs que tenho, que são 3.
for(var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++){
  descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", getIndex);
}

function getIndex(){
    var el = this;
    var siblings = [].slice.call(el.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input'));
    var index = siblings.indexOf(el);
    alert(index);
    return index;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-edit">
  <div id="teste">
    Nome: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Idade: <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Lore: <select>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Ipsum</option>
      <option>Dolor </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```