# Como utilizar blocos em Ruby?

Tags: funções, ruby, closures

Estou tendo muita dificuldade em entender blocos em Ruby. Alguém poderia me explicar como por que a gente utiliza ele?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você conhece [*closures*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29))? [É a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101). Você pode ver mais em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101) feita aqui no site. Não é a mesma linguagem mas a ideia é a mesma. O [Java 8 possui o mesmo recurso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) - embora com pequenos detalhes um pouco diferentes.

O bloco é um trecho de código que, a grosso modo, pode ser vinculado a uma variável. E obviamente pode ser passado como parâmetro. Então você define um código em determinado momento mas sua invocação só acontecerá em outro momento, em outro local.

Isto é muito usado para personalizar comportamentos. Então você pode ter algum método que precisa executar uma tarefa, mas ele não sabe executar todas as partes. Assim ele pode ser mais flexível. Essas partes serão definidas por outra parte do código da aplicação. Em geral, este método recebe o que ele deve executar por parâmetro ou pega isto através de um membro da classe ou mesmo chamando um outro método que forneça o trecho desejado.

É claro que durante a execução não estamos falando do código fonte sendo transportado pra lá e pra cá. Depois de compilado este trecho de código estará disponível em um endereço de memória e na verdade é este endereço que será usado para indicar o trecho. Mas isto é detalhe de implementação, você não precisa saber disto para usar.

Mais ainda. O bloco conta com esse endereço e com um estrutura de dados que guarda possíveis variáveis que podem ter seus valores armazenados ali. Como estes blocos são clausuras, eles podem conter os valores de variáveis declaradas no escopo onde o bloco foi definido. Assim estes valores estarão disponíveis quando o bloco for executado efetivamente, mesmo que a variável que deu origem ao valor nem esteja mais disponível.

Então no fundo o que é chamado de *code block* é um objeto que contém valores de variáveis enclausuradas e o endereço de um trecho de código compilado.

Estes blocos podem ser considerados métodos sem nome. Como o método não possui nome, sua execução é feita através da variável onde ele está guardado.

Então:

```
codigo = {|x| x + 1 }
```

Isto é um método que recebe tem um parâmetro chamado `x´ e dentro dele ele pega o valor passado por` x` e soma 1, isto é o resultado do bloco de código.

Outra sintaxe:

```
do |texto|
    puts texto
end
```

Um exemplo prático:

```
[1,2,3].each {|x| puts "(#{x})" }
```

Isso irá imprimir os 2 números entre parênteses. Note que quem varre a coleção de dados é o método `each` que você não precisa saber como funciona, é um método existente que você só precisa saber que pode chamar para executar algo em todos os elementos de uma coleção qualquer e que o parâmetro que este método espera é um bloco de código. Este bloco vai dizer o que o método deve executar em cada elemento.

Claro que é possível obter o mesmo resultado de outra forma, mas pode ser que precise de código maior, pode ser que você esqueça de tratar todos os aspectos necessários fazendo manualmente, especialmente quando tem que fazer coisas mais complicadas. Então você encapsula uma lógica em um método e deixar ele fazer algo específico que será definido pelo bloco.

Outro exemplo:

```
def metodo(exec)
    exec.call "Vinicius"
end
codigo = proc do |nome|
    puts "Ola, #{nome}"
end
#ainda não executou nada aqui
metodo(codigo)
#agora executou a impressão do nome
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fork/Kch0Ou). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fhprwruy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Closure.rb).

Perceba que o método `metodo` não sabe o que ele vai fazer, só sabe que vai fazer alguma coisa a ser definida pelo parâmetro recebido. A definição foi feita fora dele, de forma independente.

Agora veja com uma variável enclausurada:

```
def metodo(exec)
    exec.call "Vinicius"
end
idade = 20
codigo = proc do |nome|
    puts "Ola, #{nome}, voce tem #{idade} anos"
end
metodo(codigo)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/CQiABS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ozkycnae-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Closure2.rb).

O código é só um exemplo. Neste caso o nome será definido dentro do `metodo` mas a idade já está indo junto com o `codigo`. Então `nome` é parâmetro do bloco, `idade` é variável enclausurada.

Uma explicação geral é esta. Dependendo da sua bagagem de aprendizado de programação, pode ainda não ficar tão claro mas vai lendo mais coisas sobre o mesmo assunto que vai consolidando e esclarecendo. Claro que pode ter aspectos específicos que você não entende e pode ir abrindo novas perguntas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Foi muito esclarecedora. Consegui entender o conceito de closures, as vezes eu fico meio confuso com algumas utilizações de blocks no rails. Por exemplo o método respond_to, que espera um bloco. Nesse caso, a definição do método, já tem a programação definida para a resposta, mas, ele não sabe o formato de resposta que você quer, por isso espera um bloco de código, que informe?

Comment: Não conheço RoR mas é isto, o `respond_to` é justamente para você "configurar" uma ação a ser executada quando algo acontecer. Ou seja, o RoR sabe que ele tem que fazer alguma coisa ali mas ele não sabe o exato procedimento a realizar, você o criador da aplicação vai dizer que código deve ser executado. Pode ser desde pegar um simples campo do modelo ou fazer um processamento complexo, provavelmente usando várias informações do modelo.

Comment: otima explicação @bigown

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar blocos usando a *keyword* `lambda`.

```
diga_ola = lambda {|nome| puts "Olá, #{nome}!" }
diga_ola.call 'Fulano' # "Olá, Fulano!"
```

Isso permite a você passar um bloco para um método:

```
def executar(bloco)
  # faça algo
  bloco.call
  # faça mais algo
end

bloco = lambda { puts 'foo' }
executar bloco
```

Mas por favor, não utilize dessa forma em Ruby, pois há um *syntax sugar* que torna tudo mais elegante, usando a *keyword* `yield`.

```
def executar
  puts 'Antes do bloco'
  yield 'Fulano'
  puts 'Depois do bloco'
end

executar do |nome|
  puts "Olá, #{nome}!" # "Olá, Fulano!"
end

# ou
# executar {|nome| puts "Olá, #{nome}!" }
```

`yield` executa o bloco, podendo passar parâmetros para ele. Se quiser acessar o bloco como variável, também pode adicionar `&block` como úlltimo parâmetro do método:

```
def cumprimente(cumprimento, &block)
  nome = block.call
  puts "#{cumprimento}, #{nome}"
end

cumprimente 'Olá' do
  return 'Fulano'
end
```

`block_given?` vai retornar se um bloco foi passado como parâmetro:

```
def do_something
  puts 'Hello'
  if block_given?
    yield
  end
  puts 'Bye
end
```

Na verdade existe uma diferença entre um *lambda*, um *proc* e um *block*, mas isso é complexo e não vou tentar explicar aqui.

Blocos em Ruby são poderosos, e várias bibliotecas e *frameworks* o utilizam para criar *Domain Specific Languages* (DSL). ([Ref1](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico), [Ref2](http://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html)).

Um exemplo disso são as migrations do Rails:

```
create_table :pessoas do |t|
  t.string :nome, null: false
  t.integer :idade
  t.belongs_to :organizacao, foreign_key: true
end
```

A execução acima é um método normal (`create_table`é um método). Mas a sintaxe foi tão bem pensada que nem parece Ruby, parece uma "linguagem" própria pra criar migrations, quase uma poesia.

Blocos também são usados para programar de forma funcional em Ruby:

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dobro = numeros.map {|n| n*2 } # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Para o caso do método create_table do rails, é utilizado bloco por que os campos da tabela são dinâmicos, correto?

Comment: @Vinícius Desculpe, eu não entendi sua pergunta. Pode deixar mais claro?

Comment: No método create_table, é necessária a utilização de bloco como parâmetro, para indicar os campos da tabela do banco, correto? e variável que é passada como parâmetro para o bloco seria uma instância?

Comment: Exatamente. `t`, que é recebido como parâmetro no bloco, é uma instância que representa a tabela do banco. `string`, `integer`, etc. são métodos dessa instância. Ao final da execução do bloco, o Rails utiliza os dados que você entrou para gerar o SQL (`CREATE TABLE...`)