# Função de Sobrecarga de Método JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

Estou lendo um livro chamado "Segredos do Ninja JavaScript" e nele, me deparei com uma função de sobrecarga de método. Até ai tudo bem, eu entendi o que ela faz, entendi que ela faz com que dependendo da quantidade de parâmetros passados à função um método diferente será chamado.

A função que aparece no livro é a seguinte:

```js
function addMethod(object, name, fn){
  var old = object[name];
  object[name]=function(){
    if(fn.length == arguments.length)
      return fn.apply(this, arguments)
    else if (typeof old == 'function')
      return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

var ninjas = {
  values : ["Dean Edwards", "Sam Stephenson", "Alex Russel"]
};

addMethod(ninjas, "find", function(){
  return this.values;
});

addMethod(ninjas, "find", function(name){
  var ret = [];
  for (var i =0; i < this.values.length; i++)
    if(this.values[i].indexOf(name) == 0)
      ret.push(this.values[i]);
  return ret;
});
```

Se você chamar no seu console o método `ninjas.find()` ele retornará o Array completo da propriedade `values` do objeto `ninjas`, caso chame algo como `ninjas.find("Dean")`, será retornado apenas o nome correspondente à pesquisa.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Quando fazemos a segunda atribuição da função `find` por meio de `addMethod()`, por que ela não sobrescreve a anterior? Ou melhor, quero entender o que está acontecendo pra que as duas funções `find` possam existir simultaneamente.

Comment: Acho que você sobrescreveu (com addMethod) o método sem parâmetros. Quando você chama o método com parâmetros, o método chamado é o que já existia não o que você injetou.

Comment: Sim, mas se depois de chamar o método com parâmetros você chamar o sem parâmetros, ele ainda está lá

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [resposta do Eduardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90373) explica o que está acontecendo, e eu vou tentar ilustrar. Cada vez que `addMethod` é chamada, ela guarda como `old` o que estiver em `object[name]`, cria uma nova função, e guarda no lugar da antiga. E a cada chamada o `addMethod` cria um novo `old`, [acessível apenas pela função que o método cria em seguida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859).

Limpando o código, fica mais claro:

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn){
  var old = object[name];
  object[name] = function(){
    // ...
  };
}
```

Por exemplo, se você tiver 3 funções, `A`, `B` e `C`, e passar uma de cada vez, você cria 3 novas funções, cada uma com acesso a um `old` diferente:

```
addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", A); // old é undefined
addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", B); // old é uma closure com acesso a A
addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", C); // old é uma closure com acesso a B
```

Veja que tem uma cadeia de acessos aí. E a função criada em `addMethod` se aproveita disso, ela decide se chama a função passada ou a old conforme o número de argumentos:

```
if(fn.length == arguments.length)
  return fn.apply(this, arguments)   // chama a função passada, fn

else if (typeof old == 'function')
  return old.apply(this, arguments); // chama a função em old, que tem
                                     // acesso ao que foi passado
                                     // na chamada anterior
```

Suponha que `A` não tenha argumentos, `B` tenha um e `C` tenha dois:

```
function A() {}
function B(um) {}
function C(um, dois) {}

addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", A); // Chamada #1
addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", B); // Chamada #2
addMethod(obj, "nomeDoMetodo", C); // Chamada #3

// ATENÇÃO: chamada sem nenhum argumento
obj.nomeDoMetodo();
```

O que acontece quando chamamos `obj.nomeDoMetodo()`, sem argumentos? Vejamos linha por linha.

```
// Código da função criada na Chamada #3 a addMethod
if(fn.length == arguments.length)    // false: fn da Chamada #3 é
                                     // C, que tem 2 argumentos, e agora
                                     // nenhum foi passado
  return fn.apply(this, arguments)   // (não executa)

else if (typeof old == 'function')   // cai aqui
  return old.apply(this, arguments); // chama a função em old, que tem
                                     // acesso a B
```

Então uma função igual, mas criada na Chamada #2 a `addMethod`, é invocada:

```
// Código da função criada na Chamada #2 a addMethod
if(fn.length == arguments.length)    // false: fn da Chamada #2 é
                                     // B, que tem 1 argumento, e agora
                                     // nenhum foi passado
  return fn.apply(this, arguments)   // (não executa)

else if (typeof old == 'function')   // cai aqui
  return old.apply(this, arguments); // chama a função em old, que tem
                                     // acesso a A
```

E chegamos na função criada na Chamada #1:

```
// Código da função criada na Chamada #1 a addMethod
if(fn.length == arguments.length)    // true: fn da Chamada #1 é
                                     // A, que não tem argumentos.
  return fn.apply(this, arguments)   // Executa A
```

Comment: Então ele faz um processamento em camadas até encontrar uma que seja adequada, certo? Só mais uma dúvida, como ele invoca mais de uma vez a função, quer dizer, como o if é avaliado mais de uma vez sem o uso de um for?

Comment: É mais ou menos "em camadas". Não é a mesma função sendo chamada várias vezes, são várias "cópias" função. Cada cópia tem valores diferentes em `fn` e `old`. Quando você chama o novo método adicionado, a função ou usa o `fn` dela, ou passa para a `old`, que também pode usar o seu próprio valor de `fn`, ou chamar sua própria `old`, e por aí vai. Ficou mais claro? @LucasMuller

Comment: Ficou sim, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ótima explicação, tudo fica melhor com exemplos :D

Comment: Poderia só me  auxiliar com um duvida? Creio que esta pratica então é ruim, pois cria "copias" do objeto, o que poderia se tornar custoso para a memória, esta correto?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Até dá pra evitar a criação de cópias. Pensei numa maneira via cadeia de protótipos, mas nem vou entrar em detalhes. Se isso vai se tornar custoso em termos de memória, depende muito do caso de uso. Por isso eu não descartaria essa solução como "má prática" só por causa disso, tem que ver caso a caso.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que encontrei a explicação aqui:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Vamos ver se eu consigo explicar.

A função addMethod() está atribuindo uma função para a variável object, que por se tratar de um objeto é um ponteiro (as modificações feitas em object dentro de addObject vão persistir no objeto final).

Isso torna a função object[name] uma closure() que em javascript é um objeto especial que guarda duas coisas: a função em si e o ambiente onde ela foi criada.

Logo, a variável old, no contexto da função object[name] terá valor quando a função find for executada permitindo que aquele IF que testa qual das versões executar funcione, já que a variável old terá valor.

Isso faz algum sentido? Foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: É exatamente isso que está acontecendo, +1.

Comment: O interessante é que é uma cadeia de closures. Cada função tem um `old` diferente.

Comment: Ainda não entendi totalmente mas já esclareceu muito, vou esperar mais um pouco antes de aceitar a resposta, mas obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Aproveitando, esse site do MDN para javascript é muito bom. Eu não sei como está a tradução dele para português. Mas é uma ótima referência pra estudar o funcionamento do Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Galera, estou postando como resposta mas só quero mostrar por meio da imagem abaixo o conceito de closures citado nas respostas anteriores.

Obs. Criei uma função a mais com três parâmetros para ficar mais claro.

Simplesmente rodei o código no meu console e depois digitei `ninjas` para ver o objeto e tudo que há nele. Então dá pra ver que ele tem duas propriedades apenas: `values` e `find` (na verdade um método). Até ai nenhuma novidade, mas aí fui ver o que tinha nesse `find`, e lá eu encontrei um escopo e dentro dele uma closure e nela a minha duas váriaveis criadas pela `addMethod()`, a `fn` e a `old`. Na `fn` estava minha função de 2 parâmetros e na `old` tinha um outro escopo.

Dentro dessa `old` havia uma nova `closure`, nessa `closure` havia mais uma `fn` e mais uma `old`. A `fn` com a função de 1 parâmetro e a `old` com mais uma `closure`.

Nessa nova `closure` também havia uma variável `fn` e uma `old`, a `fn` era a função sem parâmetros e a `old` era indefinida.

Isso mostra que a cada vez que o `addMethod` rodou ele criou um novo escopo, uma nova `closure`, e é por isso que o código roda em camadas.

Pois se a condição dos parâmetros for satisfeita ele roda a `fn` da camada (`closure`) que está, caso contrário roda o `old`, entrando em uma nova camada na qual novamente será avaliada a condição e assim por diante.

[image: Closures criadas na execução do código]