# Pegar callbacks de um ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo:

```
var teste = $.ajax({...}).done( function() { alert('Callback Done!') } );
```

Pra onde vai essa função definida no done()? Já procurei no objeto inteirinho usando o console do Chome, mas não achei onde são registrados esses callbacks ( `console.log( teste )` )

Se eu conseguisse pelo menos disparar os "done's" do ajax como se fosse um `teste.trigger("done")` já adiantava.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Explica melhor o que queres dizer com "armazenadas". Referes-te ao jQuery? ou ao teu código? Podes explicar também o que pretendes fazer? Podes sempre defenia a função à parte `function fnTeste(){}` e depois passar para o ajax: `var teste = $.ajax({...}).done(fnTeste);` ou chamá-la diretamente `fnTeste();`.

Comment: Preciso pegar as funções "registradas" no done() de um ajax

Comment: Continuo a não entender o que queres ao certo.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá,

**Independente de seja o teu problema, "pegar" ou "rodar" o done não faz sentido.Vou explicar o porque.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como funciona**

O **Done:** é um método interno do jquery que é executado após o uma chamada ajax ser concluída. A sequência a grosso modo funciona assim:

- 1- Chamada é efetuada ($.ajax)
- 2- O retorno é processado
- 3- Com o retorno em mãos o jquery roda o done indicando que não
  ocorreram erros. Esse Done recebe os dados oriundos da resposta da
  requisição.

**E agora porque não faz sentido**

Não faz sentido justamente porque você precisaria passar os dados retornados de um requisição que só estão presente no escopo do próprio plugin. Justamente para expor tal dado existe o método Done.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta: não existe método nativo.

A função `jQuery.ajax()` retorna um objeto que implementa a [interface *Promise*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), que permite apenas a atribuição de *callbacks*.

Essa interface está associada a um [`Deferred Object`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), esse objeto encapsula em uma *closure* a lista de funções que você deseja acessar, e não existe nenhum método para acessar essa lista.

Sobre disparar as *callbacks*, a função que faria isso é [`deferred.resolve()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/), mas essa função também está encapsulada e não pode ser acessada diretamente.

A melhor alternativa é usar funções nomeadas, como sugerido pelo @Sergio nos comentários:

```
function fnTeste() { // cria função nomeada
  alert('Callback Done!')
}
var teste = $.ajax({...}).done(fnTeste); // adiciona como callback
fnTeste(); // para disparar callback "manualmente"
```

---

Leitura recomendada sobre *closures*: [Como funcionam closures em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1862/13561)

Comment: Como eu faria pra disparar o `done` de `teste`, conforme meu exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

**Primeiro entenda que existem diferentes conceitos sobre requisição HTTP.**

Quando se trata de uma requisição Cliente/Servidor, a URL que é enviada via POST, GET, PUT ou DELETE, feita através de uma requisição AJAX, é enviada diretamente para o Servidor, e o processo de leitura do arquivo que estará esperando essa requesição só receberá os dados, depois que identificar o protocolo da sua requisição e passar por todo o processo no lado do servidor, geralmente, costuma ser o apache, mas pode ser um IIS...(não irei discutir isso aqui!)

Dentro do servidor há uma outra camada pré-configurada que vai tratar a sua saída HTTP, é lá onde estarão as regras habilitadas, de como..., quanto tempo..., quais as limitações, as permissões etc... para depois enviar para dentro do documento onde contém a linguagem PHP, ou a linguagem  que estará sendo utilizada para essa dinâmica.

E esse arquivo, irá ler e identificar as chamadas através de variáveis da linguagem, no PHP temos:

- `$chamada = $_REQUEST['chamada'];`
- `$chamada = $_POST['chamada'];`
- `$chamada = $_REQUEST['chamada'];`
- `$chamada = fopen("php://input", "r");`
- etc

Após o tratamento desses dados, na linguagem, entrará a requisição final, que é do navegador, propriamente dito, e este recebará, outros dados de leitura, que geralmente ficam no header do seu escopo, lá ele irá identificar informações do navegador:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: spesa.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) Gecko/20061201 Firefox/2.0.0.3 (Ubuntu-feisty)
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
```

Para acessar essas informações em Resful no console do Chrome, entre na aba **Network** > selecione a opção **XHR**, e clique sobre o arquivo enviado na sua requisição, se ele não estiver listado, faça uma requisição novamente para que seja listado, lá tem todas as opções que você quer ver sobre o comportamento do objeto e da sua requisição.

**PS:** Outra coisa que é importante saber, é que um método closures com **callback**, só terá saída dentro dele mesmo, vc não pode utilizar um **callback** fora de seu escopo. O que você pode fazer é chamar um método externo para dentro desse método, mas ainda assim, ele irá executar dentro dele.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é definir uma variável externa fora do seu método callback, atribuí-la um retorno após a mudança do retorno de um callback, e depois retornar essa variável, o que chamamos de "promise". Exemplo:

```
   var methodAction = function() {


        var promise = $.ajax({
              url: "/action.php",
              method: "POST",
              dataType:"json"
         });
            promise.when(whenFunction);
            promise.done(successFunction);
            promise.fail(errorFunction);
            promise.always(alwaysFunction);

     }


var successFunction = function(data) {
      return data;
}
var errorFunction = function(data) {
     $('#loading').text('erro no processo!');
}
var alwaysFunction = function(data) {
     $('#loading').text('processado!')
}
var whenFunction = function(data) {
     $('#loading').text('processando...')
}

methodAction();
```

Há um método do próprio jQuery, para isso:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

[**Deferred Object** - Objeto diferido (prolongado)](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
[**Documentação**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)
[**Leia mais aqui**](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)
[**Mais leitura útil**](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html)