# Valor de variável não é alterado dentro do ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

estou tentando atribuir um valor a uma variável dentro do sucess de um ajax, porém, ao verificar o valor dessa variável, esse valor está com o valor de criação da variável, segue:

```
var emailPessoa = '';

 $.ajax({
   url: api/aluno/id,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(r){
     emailPessoa = r[0].email;
     console.log(emailPessoa); // saida-exemplo: email@stack.com
   }
 }); 
 console.log(emailPessoa) // saida: ''
```

Sacaram o problema? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: [Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151216/o-que-são-processamentos-assíncronos-e-processamentos-síncronos) pode te ajudar. Você precisa entender um pouco sobre métodos síncronos e assíncronos.

Comment: Quando você abre um site ele demora um pouco pra carregar, nem que sejam alguns segundos ou fração de segundos, certo? O Ajax é a mesma coisa, ele vai "abrir" outra página para então retornar alguma coisa. Enquanto o Ajax tá chamando a outra página, o seu `console.log` fora do Ajax já "trabalhou" e já foi dormir. Quando o Ajax volta com o valor, o `console.log` já tinha sido executado. Por isso o nome é Ajax (XML e JavaScript Assíncrono).

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, essa chamada é assíncrona. Isso significa que você não pode acessar o valor dessa forma.

Como é um tema um pouco extenso para escrever nesta resposta, segue um link que explica tudo que você precisa saber.

[Requisições AJAX síncronas e assíncronas em jQuery](https://blognti.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/requisicoes-ajax-sincronas-e-assincronas-em-jquery/)

Obs: complementando o link, chamadas síncronas costumam bloquear a execução enquanto a requisição está em andamento, então tome cuidado.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Mas não entendo... Se eu guardo o valor da variável em uma outra variável antes declarada, por que o valor dela se perde?

Comment: Ela não se perde. Na verdade, o seu último console.log é executado antes mesmo do primeiro console.log conseguir algum valor. Recomendo ler sobre esse tema, é bastante importante!

Answer (score 1):

#### Requisição assíncrona

Quando você executa um método em Ajax está realizando uma requisição assíncrona, criado implicitamente pelo objeto [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest). Essa função fica a **espera** de uma resposta, isso significa que enquanto você não recebê-la, nada que você colocou no parâmetro *success* ou em qualquer outro [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98543/5043) será executado. Em outras palavras, quando você realiza uma requisição assíncrona ela **não é** executada imediatamente.

No seu código o `console.log(emailPessoa);` está sendo executado antes da sua requisição retornar uma resposta, no caso *success*. Isso acontece com qualquer coisa que você colocar fora do escopo do método de resposta.

```js
var emailPessoa = '';

 $.ajax({
   url: api/aluno/id,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(r){
     emailPessoa = r[0].email;
     console.log(emailPessoa); // saida-exemplo: email@stack.com
   }
 });
 
 console.log(emailPessoa) // isso vai ser executado antes do ajax
 
 var teste = "Teste"; // Isso também
 
 // essa funcao vai ser declarada
 function funcaoTeste(){
  console.log("Executou funcaoTeste");
 };
 
 // essa funcao também foi executada antes do ajax
 funcaoTeste();
```

A sua variável `emailPessoa` só será alterada depois que a requisição obter uma resposta. Quando você executa `console.log(emailPessoa)` ele simplesmente exibe o que você definiu na variável lá em cima: `''`, ou seja, nada.

[Neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Requisicoes_sincronas_e_assincronas) explica claramente a diferença entre métodos e requisições Síncronos e Assíncronos.