# Por que o incrementador se "perde" no laço?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loop

Fazendo um simples laço `FOR`, encontrei um comportamento estranho que não consegui entender.

A contagem se "perde" na requisição AJAX, mantendo o valor do incrementador com o último. A requisição a URL sempre retorna `200` e mesmo assim não influencia em nada para a execução correta.

Há algo relacionado com escopo da variável?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

  console.log("For:" + i);

  var urlMapas = "http://servicomapas.ibge.gov.br/api/mapas/" + i + '/1';

  $.ajax({
    url: urlMapas,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("AJAX:" + i);

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eu testei seu código e a variável é incrementada um a um até chegar no 60. Eu testei com o console do Chrome.

Comment: Eduardo, você verificou a variável dentro do AJAX? A de fora da requisição é contada normalmente mas a de dentro não.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript

Comment: Eu entendi o que você quer fazer. Se você der um `console.log` na variável `data`, você vai ver que as requisições para cada URL estão sendo retornadas. Se você quiser um loop dentro de `.success()` terá que criar outro for, pois trata-se de uma `callback`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ele não se perde, ele faz exatamente o que foi mandado fazer. O laço é uma coisa e a função passada para o jQuery é outra completamente separada. Isto ocorre porque a função é uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101). Ela captura a variável, mas não seu estado. Então só o estado final é considerado.

Como pode ser observado no console o laço conta de 0 à 60 perfeitamente e o `i` fica com este valor quando encerra.

A solução é criar uma função e passar a variável do laço como parâmetro para esta função. E esta função é que deve chamar o AJAX.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    console.log("For:" + i);
    (function(p) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://servicomapas.ibge.gov.br/api/mapas/" + p + '/1',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("AJAX:" + p);
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/AJAX/jQueryExample.js).

Por isso que eu digo que a *closure* só deveria ser usada em último caso, quando a pessoa sabe todas as consequências dela. jQuery abusa de *closures*.

Comment: Entendido, @bigown. O link passado pelo Pablo também deu uma esclarecida.