# Como deixar variáveis de forma privada em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Como deixar uma variável privada, pois tive problema em utilizar o mesmo nome de variável que já estava implementado em outro arquivo JS e que eu não lembrava.

Como criar essa variável privada para ser utilizar apenas no arquivo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No arquivo basta usar um `var` pra declarar a variável. Ainda assim não é o ideal. Variáveis devem ser mais locais ainda. O ideal é declarar variáveis somente dentro de funções. Também pode fazer isso em objetos. Só que variáveis de objetos costuma ter visibilidade pública (ainda que o escopo seja privado).

Se quiser criar variáveis com visibilidade privado é possível com um truque. Isto é feito no construtor do objeto com variáveis locais ao construtor. Assim:

```js
function Container(param) {
    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    this.service = function () {
        return dec() ? that.member : null;
    };
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
var obj = new Container('abc');
console.log(obj.service());
console.log(obj.service());
console.log(obj.service());
console.log(obj.service());
console.log(obj.secret); //isto dá erro
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/PrivateVariable.js).

A técnica com mais detalhes pode ser vista do [artigo famoso do Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Todas as três variáveis são locais (o parâmetro é sempre local), e por definição só acessível dentro do construtor. O `this.member` é um membro público do objeto. O JS é ainda mais restrito do que outras linguagens. Esses membros do objeto só podem ser acessado por método privados. Nem mesmo métodos públicos do objeto podem acessá-los diretamente.

Métodos privados são as funções declaradas dentro do construtor. É o caso de `dec()`. Para fazer a comunicação entre métodos privados e públicos criamos um método dentro do construtor mas através do `this`, assim ele é ao mesmo tempo privado (ao construtor) e público (acessível pela referência do objeto), portanto é um método privilegiado. Este é o método `service()`. Ele pode chamar `dec()` e acessar `that` que são privados, e é acessível fora do objeto.

O mecanismo que permite isso pode ser melhor entendido na [pergunta sobre *closures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101).

Answer (score 3):

Marcio, primeiro você precisa entender um pouco sobre o escopo das variáveis.

Então vamos começar pelo escopo global:

```
//se declarado fora de qual quer função/objeto.
var variavel = "Hello World!";
//se declarado em qual quer ponto do codigo.
window["variavel"] = "Hello World!";
window.variavel = "Hello World!";
```

as três declarações acima apontam para a mesma variavel, no caso a variavel global `variavel`.

se você deseja que a sua variável seja em todo o código, porém não possa ser editada, você pode fazer uso do [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, "variavel", {
  value: "Hello Wolrd!"
});

console.log(variavel); // "Hello Wolrd!"
variavel = "Tentativa de Editar";
console.log(variavel); // "Hello Wolrd!", a atribuição acima não surtiu efeito.
```

Porém, acredito que no seu caso, o melhor seja definir um escopo, para tal existem algumas tecnicas, como uma [`IIFE`](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```js
(function () {
  var variavel = "Hello World";
  console.log("dentro do IIFE -> " + variavel); //"Hello World"
  window.setTimeout(function () {    
    console.log("dentro do IIFE -> " + variavel); //"Hello World"
    console.log("global dentro do IIFE -> " + window.variavel); //"Tentativa de Editar"
  }, 2000);
})();

variavel = "Tentativa de Editar";
console.log("fora do IIFE -> " + variavel); //"Tentativa de Editar"
window.setTimeout(function () {    
  console.log("fora do IIFE -> " + variavel); //"Tentativa de Editar"
}, 2000);
```

Note que dentro do `IIFE` a `variavel` continua com o valor `Hello World`, apesar de que no escopo global ela ter recebido o valor `Tentativa de Editar`