# Devo utilizar uma variável que pega um elemento HTML como global ou local?

Tags: javascript, html, variáveis

```
function message (className, text) {
    /*Esta variável*/var message = document.getElementById("message");/*Esta variável*/
    message.className = className;
    message.innerHTML = text;
    setTimeout(function () {
        message.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Eu só vou usar essa variável dentro dessa função, mas acredito que se eu deixá-la como local a cada vez que eu chame essa função o JavaScript vai ter que acessar o HTML novamente para buscar este elemento, e se eu deixá-la como global o elemento já vai estar pego. O que é mais performático?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variáveis declaradas dentro de funções são apagadas da memória depois da função executar. Assim em termos de gerencia de memória é melhor a variável dentro da função. Outra questão que é bom ter em conta é não sobrecarregar o espaço global com nomes de variáveis que acidentalmente podem ser sobrescritas.

Há ainda outra possibilidade, com uma IIFE, que deixa a variável local mas que não precisa ir ao DOM a cada vez que a função executa que é

```js
var message = (function(el) {
  return function(className, text) {
    el.className = className;
    el.innerHTML = text;
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
  }
})(document.getElementById("message"));
```

Assim o elemento/objeto fica na memória da função e não global (que é melhor ainda que fique guardado em memória permanentemente), não polui o espaço global e não é preciso ir ao DOM buscar a cada vez que a função é executada.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas, ajudou muito porque eu não conhecia essas formas de se fazer, mas agora vou passar a utilizar.

Answer (score 4):

Veja [Variável global em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32251/101) e [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/101).

Então use sempre variável local. Embora este seja um caso pra se pensar se global não é vantajoso. Se você tem certeza que o HTML nunca mudará, mas tem que ter certeza mesmo, que **nunca** mudará, nem sempre pode garantir isso, então é possível usar alguma técnica para evitar esse processamento. Não sei se compensa, não sei se vale o risco.

Existe uma técnica chamada [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104014/101). É possível fazer isto em JavaScript mantendo a [variável do objeto privada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130931/101) através do [uso do `this`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/101).