# Qual a finalidade de declarar uma função dentro de uma função?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Em Python é possível declarar uma função dentro de outra função, como é mostrado no código a seguir.

```
def foo(palavra=None):
    print(palavra)
    def bar(outra_palavra=None):
        print(outra_palavra)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(palavra='metodo main')
```

Porém qual é a finalidade prática de tal flexibilidade da linguagem? Em qual cenário fazer uso de tal ferramenta possibilita um ganho?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Um motivo é o encapsulamento. Se a função interna será chamada só por esta função não tem porque colocar fora. Colocando dentro garante que ninguém mais pode chamar.

Uma coisa que eu noto é que as pessoas aprendem programar sem entender o que está fazendo e uma das coisas que as pessoas não entendem é a função da função (trocadilho intencional :) ). Funções servem para abstrair algoritmos. Servem para indicar com mais claridade e organização ao que está fazendo ao mesmo tempo que cria uma forma canônica daquela operação., um conceito conhecido como [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

É possível que algo que a função externa faz se repita e faz sentido abstrair em uma função. Como só ela precisa disto é melhor não expor para outras partes. Quanto menos expor menos preocupação tem e mais fácil de dar manutenção.

Uma característica legal é que você pode retornar a própria função, ou seja seu método prepara a função e entrega para quem precise usar interna. Isto é feito com uma técnica chamada de função anônima. Assim você cria uma função nomeada e usa seu nome como se fosse uma variável, então a função não é executada e sim repassada como se fosse um dado (isto é otimizado através de ponteiro). Algo assim:

```
def GeraCondicao(valor):
    def Condicao(item):
        return item > valor
    return Condicao

condicao = GeraCondicao(5)
for i in range(0, 10):
    if condicao(i)
        print i
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Inner.py).

Imprimirá de 6 à 10.

No caso usei uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) ([outra definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)) já que um dado da função externa foi capturada pela função interna

Obviamente que pode gerar essa condição de várias formas, pode chamar outras funções que criam funções anônimas e compor do jeito que precisar.

Claro que não precisa nem retornar, pode só passar para outra função que está chamando ali mesmo onde a função interna foi criada.

Answer (score 7):

Tem alguns usos possíveis. Os principais são esses dois:

## fábrica de funções

Esse talvez seja o uso principal. Como funções são objetos de primeira classe em em Python, cada vez que uma função que contém outras é chamada, as funções declaradas internamente são recriadas (Mas não compiladas de novo: o bytecode das funções aninhadas é criado em um passo anterior). Elas terão acesso as variáveis da função externa, que serão também separadas a cada chamada (que cria um "closure").

Acho que um dos usos mais comuns é na quando se escreve um decorador em Python. Decoradores em Python são funções que recebem como único parâmetro uma outra função. Eles retornam um objeto chamável, em geral uma função também, que pode executar algum código antes e depois da chamada da função original. Então o código de um decorador simples fica assim:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # código anterior a chamada original
        ...
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # código posterior a chamada original
        ...
        return result
    return wrapper


@decorator
def minha_funcao():
   ...
```

Nesse caso, cada vez que "minha_funcao" for chamada, o que será executado será a função `wrapper` declada dentro do `decorator` - mas uma função `wrapper` em que a variável `func` vai ser exatamente o parâmetro da função `decorator` que recebe `minha_funcao` original como parâmetro.

Se o decorador for usado mais de uma vez, `func` receberá as outras funções decoradas, e será criada uma função `wrapper` distinta para cada uso.

É interessante ter em mente que uma função aninhada pode acessar as variáveis das funções externas, e, em Python 3, até atribuir novos valores a essas variáveis , com o uso da declaração `nonlocal` (em Python 2, as variáveis externas eram somente de leitura).

## legibilidade

Python deliberadamente restringe as funções do tipo "lambda" a serem apenas uma expressão. Em geral, funções do tipo "lambda" são usadas como parâmetros para outras funções, por exemplo, para obter a chave de ordenação de uma sequência no método `sort`, ou um comando a ser executado quando é clicado um botão de um programa gráfico.

Se a função a ser passada como parâmetro for um pouco mais complexa, e precisar ter variáveis, `if`s, etc... já vale a pena declara-la como uma função independente, aninhada.

Nada impediria que impediria que essa função aninhada estivesse fora do código principal - mas a declaração aninhada permite que ela esteja próxima do ponto onde é usada uma única vez - e se aquela lógica estiver relacionada com a função de fora.

Answer (score 3):

Não confunda `métodos de classe` com `funções`.

Não é possível que um `Método de Classe` contenha um outro `Método de Classe` declarado dentro do seu escopo.

`Métodos de Classe` estão **sempre** associados a `Classes`. Só podem ser declarados dentro de uma `Classe`. `Métodos de Classe` só podem ser chamados a partir da especificação do nome de sua `Classe` (*método estáticos*) e/ou a partir de uma instância de sua `Classe`.

Já uma `função` é independente, elas podem ser declaradas dentro de outras `funções` bem como dentro de `Métodos de Classe`. Repare que `Funções` declaradas dentro de `Classes`, na verdade, são `Métodos de Classe`!

Permitir que `funções` sejam declaradas dentro do escopo de outras `funções` e/ou `Métodos de Classe` flexibiliza muito o `encapsulamento`.

Repare que até mesmo programas escritos de forma estruturada podem `encapsular` suas funções, publicando para o escopo de fora (o cliente) somente as funções que realmente importam.

No seu exemplo, lê-se que: *A função `foo()` encapsula a função `bar()`; Não é interessante que função `bar()` seja visível pelo o escopo de fora; A função `bar()` é intimamente acoplada a função `foo()`;Ninguém fora do escopo de `foo()` é capaz de chamar `bar()`.*

O encapsulamento, se aplicado de forma adequada, aumenta muito a legibilidade e o reaproveitamento do código, que por sua vez facilita muito seu desenvolvimento e manutenção.