# Closures básico

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, closures

Senhores,

estudo Python há 4 meses aproximadamente e agora tenho adentrado os conceitos mais complexos da linguagem. Estou tendo um pouco da dificuldade para assimilar `decoradores` mas entendi que antes devo dominar o conceito de `closures`.

Segue um script para análise:

```
def incremento(n, x):
    return n + x

def incremento(n):
    def incrementado(x):
        return x + n
    return incrementado

z = incremento(8)
print(z) # não executa
print(z(18))
print(z(255))
print(z(1))
y = incremento(200)
print(y(1))
print(y(5))
```

Não se estou seguindo a correta linha de raciocínio mas neste exemplo pude entender um pouco mais sobre o conceito. A primeira função não tem `closure` e eu me perguntava o porquê de usar se eu podia construir uma função normal rapidamente. 
Depois percebi, inclusive entendendo a terminologia, que eu podia dar uma espécie de lock no valor do parâmetro da função superior para depois ir trabalhando vários valores a serem manipulados na função inferior. Percebam como eu fui 'brincando' com os valores, criando instâncias, etc. Acho que isso pode ser realmente útil!
É esta mesmo a grande sacada dos `closures`? Podem me dar exemplos um pouco mais complexos de uso? Ou adicionarem observações em relação ao exemplo usado?

Comment: Relacionados: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252596/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31414/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/112052 (não sei se é duplicada, mas esses links já dão uma boa ideia do conceito de closures)

Comment: Acho que esses links respondem a pergunta, não sendo necessário uma resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você entendeu corretamente o uso. Mas tem umas armadilhas que ainda podem te pegar - o pattern como você escreveu no seu exemplo, não traz grandes vantagens sobre uma abordagem orientada a objetos, ou mesmo uma abordagem estruturada normal: simplesmente passe todos os parâmetros em uma chamada.

Tem algumas armadilhas que podem te pegar - e esses conceitos as vezes aparecem mais naturalmente quando estamos desenvolvendo patterns que façam realmente uso dessas closures.

## Armadilha comum: as variáveis do closure são 'vivas' e tem o valor do momento em que são lidas

Por exemplo: as variáveis "não locais" que são "enxergadas" pelas funções nas closures sempre vão aparecer com o valor do momento que elas têm no momento que a função interna for chamada, não o valor que tinham quando foi criada.

é uma armadilha quando se monta interfaces gráficas com Tkinter ou Qt, por exemplo, em que é comum criar pequenas funções usando a palavra chave `lambda` para incluir, por exemplo, um identificador:

Veja esse código:

```py
import tkinter


def dizer_botao(mensagem, botao):
    mensagem["text"] = f"O botão {botao} foi pressionado"

def main():
    window = tkinter.Tk()

    mensagem = tkinter.Label(window, text="                           ")
    mensagem.pack()

    for i in range(5):
        b = tkinter.Button(
            window, 
            text=f"Botão {i}",
            command=lambda: dizer_botao(mensagem, i)
        )
        b.pack()

    tkinter.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A primeira vista, quando qualquer botão for pressionado, parece que ele vai chamar o "lambda" dentro do for, que criou o botão, e chamar a função que exibe a mensagem com o número do botão, na varíavel "i".

Se você rodar o código, no entanto, vai ver que para qualquer botão é exibido o número '4' do último botão: por que ao final do `for` esse é o valor da variável `i`.

A forma de resolver isso é "congelar" o valor de "i" pra cada um dos lambdas criados:

```py
import tkinter


def dizer_botao(mensagem, botao):
    mensagem["text"] = f"O botão {botao} foi pressionado"

def main():
    window = tkinter.Tk()

    mensagem = tkinter.Label(window, text="                           ")
    mensagem.pack()

    for i in range(5):
        b = tkinter.Button(
            window, 
            text=f"Botão {i}",
            command= (lambda i:
                lambda: dizer_botao(mensagem, i)
                )(i)
            )
        b.pack()
    tkinter.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Perceba que agora foi criada uma nova função em volta do `lambda` da listagem acima: essa função é *chamada* imediatamente, dentro do `for` para cada valor de `i`- e cria uma nova closure, para o lambda interno, que vai "enxergar" esse valor
congelado.

(Há outras formas de resolver isso, com valores default de parâmetro, por exemplo,
mas não tem a ver com o assunto de closures).

## considere se seu problema realmente fica mais simples com closures

Fora isso, acho que outro ensinamento importante é esse: se você tiver que pensar muito, ou dar muitas voltas pra resolver seu problema com essa abordagem, provavelmente ela não é a melhor.

O seu exemplo do "incremento" por exemplo, pode ficar mais legível, 
e mais ou menos com o mesmo tamanho, numa abordagem orientada a objetos:

```
class Incremento:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + self.n
```

(Aqui, o metodo especial `__call__` implica em que as instancias dessa classe podem ser chamadas, assim como funções).

Essa classe vai funcionar exatamente como a sua função "incremento" - a maior diferença é que (1) os atributos que vão ser usados pelo `__call__` são visíveis e não opacos, e podem até ser mudados; (2) você pode ter vários métodos diferentes para operar nos dados forencidos ao criar a instância - (ok, uma closure poderia criar e devolver várias funções); e (3) embora não tenha tanta importância na grande maiora das aplicações, uma instância de classe, vai ser mais rápida de ser criada, e, com algum cuidado, muito menor em termos de uso de memória do que uma cópia de uma função, retornada pela closure.  Nesse caso, só precisamos guardar realmente o atributo "n" junto com a instância, por exemplo.

E por fim, tem sim, casos em que o pattern de closure vai ser bem mais legível - o exemplo acima com tkinter, por exemplo.