# acessar variavel dentro do setInterval

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, estou tentando saber como acessa um atributo declarado em uma função setInterval/setTimeOut em outra função. Com o pouco de estudo que tenho sobre JavaScript, uma variável declarada em escopo local não pode ser acessada em outro escolo local(uma função acessando atributos de outra) a não ser que seja `this.variavel` pois a torna "publica" e você instancie um objeto dessa variável na outra função `obj = new NomeDaFuncao()`. Infelizmente não sei como instanciar um objeto de uma função setInterval/setTimeOut. Abaixo tem o exemplo do que estou tentado fazer.

```js
setInterval(() =>
    {
        this.btn = document.querySelector(".remove-button");
    },0);
    
function FazAlgo()
    {
      btnRemove = new setInterval();
      console.log(btnRemove.btn.value);
    }
```

Comment: Explica melhor o que você quer conseguir com isso porque o código está bem confuso.

Comment: é uma longa história... finja que só tem uma variavel=10 ali no setInterval kkkk

Comment: é pq esse botão `.remove-button` é adicionado dinamicamente, ele não está na pagina html, ainda, então botei esse loop ai pra selecionar ele quando ser gerado '-'

Comment: Usar `this` só faz sentido se você estiver trabalhando dentro de um objeto / definição de classe. Senão, o this vai apontar pra janela e você vai acabar criando uma variável global – que pode até resolver o seu problema, mas é uma má ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Não dá pra dizer qual seria a melhor solução no seu contexto, por não conhecermos mais detalhes do código. Mas uma possibilidade é tirar vantagem do funcionamento das [closures](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript). Em resumo, defina a variável no escopo externo, e as funções dos escopos mais internos terão acesso a ela:

```js
let minhaVar = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    minhaVar += 10;
},1000);
    
function fn() {
    console.log('valor da variável (a cada 2s)', minhaVar);
}

console.log('valor inicial da variável', minhaVar);
setInterval(fn, 2000);
```