# Funções em JavaScript compartilhando informação?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se é possível duas funções em Javascript compartilharem uma informação que está em uma delas.

Exemplo:

```
function a(){
    var nome = prompt("digite seu nome")
}

function b(){
    alert(nome)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo ao pé da letra ao que você disse:

> Gostaria de saber se é possível duas funções em Javascript compartilharem uma informação que está em uma delas.

Sim, é possível. Existem basicamente dois mecanismos para isso: escopo e passagem/retorno de valores.

## Compartilhamento de Escopo

Cada função cria um novo escopo, e tudo o que é declarado (com `var`, `let`, `const`) em um escopo não é visível fora dele:

```
// aqui é o escopo global
var a = 'escopo global';

function f() {
    // f enxerga o escopo global
    console.log('f enxerga ' + a);

    // f também tem seu próprio escopo
    var b = 'escopo local de f';
    console.log('f enxerga ' + b);
}

// O escopo global não enxerga o escopo local de f
console.log(b); // ReferenceError
```

Como uma função pode ser declarada dentro da outra, isso permite criar uma [cadeia de escopos aninhados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript/1862#1862). Você pode explorar esse mecanismo e construir o seu código de modo a ter acesso onde precisa.

## Passagem e retorno de valores

Uma função, por definição, é algo que recebe um valor e retorna outro – embora em JS funções também possam funcionar como subrotinas, não precisando receber nem retornar nada.

Quando uma função vai trabalhar em cima de um determinado valor, esse valor pode ser passado para ela na hora da chamada. Por exemplo:

```
function ola(nome) {
    console.log('Olá, ' + nome + '!');
}
ola('Douglas');
```

Ela também pode retornar um valor:

```
function ola(nome) {
    return 'Olá, ' + nome + '!';
}

console.log(ola('Douglas'));
```

## Conclusão

Em relação ao código da pergunta, não dá pra dizer nada porque ele não mostra a sua intenção real. Os exemplos aqui servem para orientar sobre como as coisas funcionam, e cabe a você decidir qual abordagem usar em cada caso.

Ambas as soluções parecem simples, e na verdade são simples mesmo. O difícil é aprender a manejar esses recursos básicos para garantir que o código fique claro, legível e modular. Isso você só aprende na prática, e muita prática.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a sua variável fora da função, tornando ela uma variável global que pode ser acessada e modificada de qualquer lugar do código.

```
    var nome = "";

    function a(){
        nome = prompt("digite seu nome") }

    function b(){
        alert(nome) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chamar a função `b` que retornará o que foi digitado no prompt da função `a`. Esse retorno será o valor da variável `nome` no escopo da função `a`:

```js
function a(){
   var nome = b(prompt("digite seu nome"));
   console.log(nome);
}

function b(nome){
   alert(nome);
   return nome;
}

a();
```

Comment: Não entendi porque definir a variável `nome` com o retorno de `b` sendo que `b` é somente um alerta. Ficou bem confuso o código, mas acho que você se confundiu e trocou as coisas por engano. A intenção não seria retornar de `a` o valor lido e em `b` dar o alerta sobre o retorno de `a`? Pelo menos parece fazer mais sentido para mim.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, e não fez muito sentido por que eu estou aplicando esse conceito em um jogo rpg, mas como está ficando grande, n daria para colocar aqui. E também, a primeira função está no contexto de ler o nome do player, então eu queria que a segunda função tivesse acesso a esse nome.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É porque (pelo menos me parece) a variável `nome` será ainda usada no escopo da função `a`.

Comment: É, ao colocar o `return` muda tudo :D

Comment: @Sam será que não seria melhor uma variável global? Pelo que entendi o OP gostaria de compartilhar o valor entre multiplas funções, assumo que o caso da pergunta seja só um exemplo. O que acha de pelo menos incluir essa alternativa na sua resposta?

Comment: @Paz Poderia ser tb, apesar de ser sempre melhor evitar variáveis globais. Mas como a outra resposta já tratou disso, eu vou deixar a minha como está. Obg!