# Executar função após objeto criado por clique

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, objetos, click

Segue abaixo o que eu consegui fazer:
Quando clico no em um botão com a classe `.btn-comprar-na-pagina`, ele dispara a função abaixo.

```
$(function () {
var itens = [];
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-comprar-na-pagina", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefSelf = $(this).parent().parent().find('.buy-in-page-button').attr('href');
    var sku = txt[0].replace("sku=", "");
    var qtd = $(this).parents('.box_produtos').find("input.qtd.pull-left, .input-number").val();

    //remove sku se existir em itens
    itens.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (sku.indexOf(item.id) > -1)
            itens.splice(index, 1)
    });

    var item = {
        id: sku,
        quantity: qtd,
        seller: '1'
    };

    itens.push(item);

});
});
```

Usando o *array* em outra função:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".btn-2", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();


       checkout.insertToCart(items, null)
        .done(function (order) {
            alert('Kit adicionado ao carrinho');
        });


});
```

Comment: se essa lista é uma variável global vc pode acessar ela de qualquer método

Comment: A tua pergunta está pouco clara... podes juntar mais código?

Comment: e simpels de fazer, problema e como esta seu codigo, tipo, e complicado adivinhar o que vai funcionar pra voce

Comment: Editei a pergunta...vê se ficou mais claro.

Comment: @wbp, caso a resposta a abaixo resolva o seu problema, marque-a como resolvida; caso contrário, poste sua solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seu erro esta em isolar as duas funções.
Você precisa estudar sobre closure, entender o scope das funções.

Achei esse artigo sobre closure aqui no stackoverflow
[Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)

Esse artigo no Mozilla Developer Network explica oque são closure
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Esses videos também pode ajudar a entender um pouco mais sobre closure

Closures em Javascript
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8URgQdnjAFU

JavaScript Funcional (AULA 5) Closures
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9wDh4HvlxI

```js
$(function () {
  var itens = []; //scope global fora das funções

  $(document).on("click", ".btn-comprar-na-pagina", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefSelf = $(this).parent().parent().find('.buy-in-page-button').attr('href');
    var sku = txt[0].replace("sku=", "");
    var qtd = $(this).parents('.box_produtos').find("input.qtd.pull-left, .input-number").val();

    //remove sku se existir em itens
    itens.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (sku.indexOf(item.id) > -1)
            itens.splice(index, 1)
    });

    var item = {
        id: sku,
        quantity: qtd,
        seller: '1'
    };

    itens.push(item);
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-2", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkout.insertToCart(items, null)
    .done(function (order) {
        alert('Kit adicionado ao carrinho');
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo assim que você quer fazer?
Usar no final da execução outra função com os valores sendo passada pela a primeira?

```js
let itens = [
 {
    id: 2000017893,
    quantity: 1,
    seller: '1'
  }, 
  {
    id: 43546363,
    quantity: 2,
    seller: '1'
  }, 
  {
    id: 987858565,
    quantity: 1,
    seller: '1'
  }
];

let add = () => {
 let quantity = document.querySelector('#quantity').value
 let seller = document.querySelector('#seller').value
  let id = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)
  
  itens.push({
   id: id,
    quantity: +quantity,
    seller: seller
  });
  
  console.log(itens)
  funcao(itens)
}

let funcao = (arr) => {
 let copyItens = arr
  let result = document.querySelector('#result')
  result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(copyItens)
}
```

```html
<label>
  <p>Quantidade</p>
  <input id="quantity" type="number">
</label>
<label>
  <p>Seller</p>
  <input id="seller" type="number">
</label>
<hr>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="funcao()">Botao Secondario</button>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: lucaslimax, editei a minha pergunta pra ficar mais claro. Como sou iniciante estou tentando entender sua sugestão...rsrs..

Comment: Então minha sugestão foi escrito com javascript puro, como você não tinha mostrado o cenário que estava trabalhando apenas o array. Nesse exemplo eu passo no mesmo evento do click a função com o array como parâmetro dela.