# Dificuldade na interpretação de arrow functions que retornam arrow functions em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, arrow-functions

Estava vendo injeção de dependência em JavaScript e me deparei com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
() => () => {}
```

Sei que `() => {}` é uma *arrow function* que, em resumo, é uma maneira diferente de criar uma função em que não é necessário dar um nome, que nos parênteses ficam os parâmetros e que nas chaves fica o código da função.

Porém não consigo entender quando há 2 parenteses:

```
() => () => {}
```

Vocês podem me explicar para que serve o primeiro `() =>` no exemplo acima?

Um exemplo:

Arquivo `calcular.js`:

```
const Celular = (carregador) => () => {
    const carregar = (){
        return carregador.enviaEnergia()
    }
    return{
        carregar
    }
}
modules.exports = celular
```

Outro arquivo:

```
const Celular = require('./celular')
const Carregador = require('./carregador')
const carregador = Carregador(5)
const celular = Celular(carregador)()
```

Sei que carregador é um modulo qualquer que irá fazer injeção dentro de dependência em celular.

Comment: pode colocar um exemplo na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa sintaxe não implica injeção de dependência, apenas significa que uma função está retornando outra. De modo mais explícito, o que está ocorrendo é o seguinte:

```
function Carregar() {
  return function() {

  };
}
```

No entanto, esse tipo de construção te permite alcançar alguns objetivos com maior facilidade em razão do sistema de closures do JavaScript. O padrão acima também recebe o nome de  função fábrica ou *factory function* em inglês, em que `Carregar` é a fábrica. Nesse caso, `Carregar` é a função fábrica, que sempre que for chamada criará uma nova função, retornando-a.

De algum modo, esse padrão se assemelha levemente a uma classe, que criará uma instância de algo. Nesse caso, a *factory function* sempre criará uma nova função.

Você pode atingir várias coisas com esse tipo de construção, como criar algum tipo de contador que mantém um estado interno e privado:

```js
function createCounter() {
  let current = 0;
  
  function getCurrent() {
    return current;
  }
  
  function increment(step = 1) {
    current += step;
  }
  
  return {
    getCurrent,
    increment
  };
}

const counter1 = createCounter();
counter1.increment(5);
counter1.increment(3);

const counter2 = createCounter();
counter2.increment(4);

console.log('Valor do contador 1:', counter1.getCurrent()); // 8
console.log('Valor do contador 2:', counter2.getCurrent()); // 4
```

Note que no exemplo acima deixamos de retornar uma função, mas sim um objeto com várias funções. Note também que cada contador tem um estado diferente, o que se deve ao sistema de [closures do JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/112052). Cada função tem o seu próprio closure, o que permite esse tipo de armazenamento de estado.

Isso também pode ser usado como forma de atingir a injeção de dependência em funções, de modo que você usa a função superior para passar as dependências e a(s) função(ões) retornada(s) não precisam mais de receber esse tipo de valor em seus argumentos. Veja a diferença:

```js
// A nossa "dependência":
const consoleLogSender = {
  send: (message) => console.log(message)
};

function sum(sender, a, b) {
  const result = a + b;
  sender.send(a + b);
}

// Para usar:
sum(consoleLogSender, 2, 2); // 4
sum(consoleLogSender, 3, 5); // 8
```

Agora, com esse padrão de *factory function*:

```js
// A nossa "dependência":
const consoleLogSender = {
  send: (message) => console.log(message)
};

function createSum(sender) {
  return function sum(a, b) {
    const result = a + b;
    sender.send(a + b);
  }
}

const consoleLogSum = createSum(consoleLogSender);

consoleLogSum(2, 2); // 4
consoleLogSum(3, 5); // 8
```

Note que o resultado é o mesmo, mas algumas pessoas preferem essa segunda maneira, principalmente buscando uma arquitetura desacoplada, algo em partes atingível pela injeção de dependência.

Agora, voltando as *arrow functions*, o código acima pode ser escrito como:

```js
// A nossa "dependência":
const consoleLogSender = {
  send: (message) => console.log(message)
};

const createSum = (sender) => (a, b) =>
  sender.send(a + b);

const consoleLogSum = createSum(consoleLogSender);

consoleLogSum(2, 2); // 4
consoleLogSum(3, 5); // 8
```

No entanto, a legibilidade é comprometida. Eu pessoalmente sempre irei optar por usar declarações de funções em casos como esse. Ademais, *arrow functions* não têm esse objetivo. Às vezes as pessoas usam algo desnecessariamente só por achar "bonito", o que é o caso aí.

Answer (score 6):

Agora entendi... vi isso num curso, esse recurso chama-se *curry* ou *curryng*.

Basicamente é usado quando uma *function* recebe mais de um parâmetro e, no lugar de passar todos os parâmtros juntos para dentro da *function*, passamos cada parâmtro separado e retornamos uma *function* após cada parâmetro.

No seu exemplo não fez muito sentido porque o segundo parâmetro foi omitido, sendo só `()`, mas se houvesse um parâmetro seria mais fácil de entender.

Para ficar mais fácil, vamos portar uma *function* para *curry* para ver a diferença:

```js
var soma = (a, b) => { return a + b; }

var somaCurried = (a) => (b) => { return a + b; }

alert(soma(2,3));

alert (somaCurried(2)(3));
```

Veja que o resultado é o mesmo, mas na prática, a segunda *function* retorna uma *function* após receber o primeiro valor, e em seguida, passa o resultado para a segunda.

Quando vi isso, foi explicado algumas aplicações que sinceramente não precebi bem onde usar, mas uma me chamou a atenção: injetar um valor em uma das *functions* em cadeia sem alterar a *function* principal. Talvez seja esse o objetivo desse seu exemplo.

Tentei mostrar um exemplo pegando parte do seu código e mostrando como aplicar:

```js
var CelularFunction = function(carregador, aparelho) {
  return "Voltagem: " + carregador + ", aparelho:" + aparelho;
};


var CelularCurry = (carregador) => (aparelho) => {
    return "Voltagem: " + carregador + ", aparelho:" + aparelho;
}

// criei uma nova func "injetando" o primeiro valor:
var CelularInject = CelularCurry("500V");

alert(CelularFunction("110v", "Samsung"));
alert(CelularCurry("220v")("Nokia"));

// faço call da function só com o segundo parâmetro, que na prática vai ser passado para a segunda function
alert(CelularInject("Motorola"));
```

Veja que nesse exemplo, a *function* `CelularInject`, "injeta" um valor para o primeiro parâmetro da cadeia, que vai para a primeira *function*, e em seguida chama a segunda. O resultado pode ser visto ao executar.

Espero que dê pra entender a ideia. cada `()=>` com ou sem parâmetro gera uma function na cadeia de *curry*, que vai retornar um valor, e como vimos, pode ser manipulada separadamente, o que daria trabalho para fazer numa *function* comum.