# resolução do escopo de variavel em php

Tags: php, scope

não estou conseguindo entender como funciona o escopo das variaveis em php, eu tento usar uma variavel, declarada fora de uma função, dentro dessa e ela fica como nula

```
 $DSN = $dsn;
    echo $DSN;
    function insert_in_DB($query){
        echo $DSN;
```

no caso o echo em cima funciona, mas o echo embaixo não

Answer (score 2):

No PHP as funções não são automaticamente [clausuras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript/1862#1862), portanto as funções não têm acesso às variáveis de fora, a não ser que sejam declaradas como `global` dentro da função, ou explicitamente declaradas como closure, listando as variáveis de fora a que ela deve ter acesso.

Mas em geral é mais recomendado passar o valor para a função, em vez de apelar para variáveis globais.

Answer (score -2):

Não funciona por 2 motivos:

1. Sua função está errada (chave não fechada);
2. A função foi definida, mas não chamada.

Pra funcionar deveria ser:

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'algo'; //Não constava
$DSN = $dsn;
echo $DSN;
function insert_in_DB($query) {
  echo $DSN;
}

insert_in_DB('algo aqui'); //A saída será: 'algo'
```

Comment: Justificando meu downvote: https://ideone.com/7MGmEH