# Uma função criada dentro de outra função é criada a cada chamada ou persistida por referência?

Tags: javascript, funções, característica-linguagem

Na chamada da declaração `const minhaFuncao = fora()`, eu estou armazenando o resultado da execução da função `fora`, que no caso seria a função `dentro` em `minhaFuncao`. Nesse caso, estou criando uma nova função? Ou estou apenas apontando para o local onde a função foi definida?

```
const x = 'Global';

function fora() {
    const x = 'Local';
    function dentro() {
        return x;
    }
    return dentro;
};

const minhaFuncao = fora(); 
console.log(minhaFuncao());
```

Answer (score 9):

Antes de tudo, precisa-se compreender o fato de que sempre que uma função é chamada, o bloco que ela define é executado. Uma função (por si só) não consegue manter estado entre duas ou mais chamadas diferentes.

Observe que, dentro da função `fora`, define-se a função `dentro`. Desse modo, *sempre* que a função `fora` for chamada, será criada uma *nova* função `dentro`, que será retornada para o chamador.

Pode-se verificar esse comportamento comparando o retorno de duas chamadas à mesma função, `fora`. Veja:

```js
function fora() {
  const x = 'Local';
  function dentro() {
    return x;
  }
  return dentro;
};

const fn1 = fora(); // Criou uma função `dentro` (e retornou)
const fn2 = fora(); // Criou outra função `dentro` (e retornou)

console.log(fn1 === fn2); //=> false
```

Como funções são, em sua essência, objetos (que implementam a operação abstrata `[[Call]]`), o operador `===` analisa se duas funções possuem *mesma referência*. Como recebemos `false` acima, confirma-se que toda vez que uma função é chamada, as funções nela definidas são recriadas.

<sup>Apenas como curiosidade, é por esse motivo que `useCallback` existe no React. Em alguns casos, recriar uma mesma função em colossal quantidade pode ser relativamente custoso. Desse modo, utiliza-se a [**memoização**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) para evitar que a função seja recriada em cada renderização.</sup>

Comment: Mas então mesmo se as funções são recriadas ainda terão acesso a variável `x` que foi declarada no corpo da função parente `fora`, a função `dentro` é considerado um closure que é algo que não entendi muito bem como isso funciona.

Comment: Em tese a variável `x` também é recriada toda vez que `fora` é chamada, mas como _strings_ são imutáveis (e está ali _hard-coded_) nesse caso faz pouca diferença. Se fosse um objeto literal ao invés de string, por exemplo, também poderíamos confirmar que `x` é recriada a cada chamada de `fora`. Em relação ao funcionamento de _closures_, sugiro ler [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/69296).