# Como fazer com que depois de executar o alert(e), voltar para a primeira linha de Código

Tags: javascript

Eu queria fazer com que depois do `alert` com erro, o código voltasse para a primeira linha, no caso: `var p=parseFloat(prompt("Digite um numero"));`.

Eu tentei colocar um `return` depois do `alert`, mas não funcionou. Alguém sabe como fazer?

```
var p=parseFloat(prompt("Digite um numero"));
try{
    if(isNaN(numbers)){
        throw new Error();
    }
   escrever(p);
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}

function escrever(numbers){
    const doc=document.querySelector("#seletor");
    doc.innerHTML=numbers;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript (felizmente? :P) não tem `goto` explícito. Uma forma de se fazer isso é com `while`, mas a lógica é _um pouco_ diferente. :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe não entendi, poderia explicar melhor ou fazer um código mostrando um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: Tente melhorar a sua pergunta primeiro. :) Por exemplo, ao invés de colocar código por imagem, coloque em texto. Também tente descrever o problema um pouco melhor.

Comment: @LuizFelipe formulei melhor

Answer (score 4):

Se quer que algo se repita várias vezes, use um *loop* - é para isso que eles servem :-)

Além disso, não faz sentido lançar um `Error` dentro do bloco `try` só para capturá-lo logo em seguida. E o `Error` que você criou nem tem mensagem, então nada de útil será mostrado (apenas "Error").

Não precisa de `Error` nem de `try`/`catch`. Se quer que uma mensagem de erro seja mostrada caso o resultado seja `NaN`, coloque-a dentro do `if` mesmo:

```js
function escrever(numbers) {
    const doc = document.querySelector("#seletor");
    doc.innerHTML = numbers;
}

while (true) {
    var p = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número"));
    if (isNaN(p)) {
        alert('Não foi digitado um número');
    } else {
        escrever(p);
        break; // sai do while
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="seletor"></p>
```

`while (true)` cria um *loop* "infinito" - ele se repete até que se encontre algum `break`, e nesse caso o `break` só é chamado quando é digitado um número válido (mas se quer que isso fique se repetindo indefinidamente, basta remover o `break`).

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493671/112052) sugeriu usar recursão (ou seja, criar uma função e chamá-la dentro dela mesma), mas isso não é uma boa ideia, porque cada chamada recursiva vai [ocupando espaço na pilha de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/112052), e isso pode estourar a pilha se ocorrer muitas vezes. Mesmo que não estoure, não faz sentido ficar chamando várias vezes a mesma função dentro dela mesma, quando um simples *loop* resolve.

Outro detalhe é que na mesma resposta, a função `escrever` é criada dentro da função `setNumber`, e [isso faz com que uma nova função seja criada toda vez que `setNumber` for chamada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493372/112052). Ou seja, além de usar indevidamente recursão (ocupando a pilha de execução sem necessidade), ainda fica criando várias funções à toa. Resumindo, não faça isso :-) Use o *loop* acima que já é suficiente.

Para saber mais sobre recursão (o que é, e principalmente quando não usar), leia [aqui](/q/21551/112052), [aqui](/q/107657/112052), [aqui](/q/184494/112052), [aqui](/q/4282/112052) e [aqui](/q/362825/112052).

Answer (score -1):

Uma das alternativas é escopar a chamada do prompt em uma função (pode até em uma variavel func), para ser reutilizada toda vez que cair no catch. Tente, por exemplo:

```js
openPrompt("Digite um numero");
var p;

try {
  if (isNaN(numbers)) throw new Error();
  escrever(p);

} catch(e) {
  alert(e);
  openPrompt("Digite um numero");
}

function escrever(numbers) {
  const doc = document.querySelector("#seletor");
  doc.innerHTML = numbers;
}

function openPrompt(message) {
  return p = parseFloat(prompt(message));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar um loop [do-while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) e uma variável para indicar se o loop deve repetir ou encerrar (`repetirLoop`).

```
var repetirLoop;
do {
    repetirLoop = false;
    var p=parseFloat(prompt("Digite um numero"));
    try{
        if(isNaN(numbers)){
            throw new Error();
        }
    escrever(p);
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
        repetirLoop = true;
    }

    function escrever(numbers){
        const doc=document.querySelector("#seletor");
        doc.innerHTML=numbers;
    }
}
while (repetirLoop);
```