# Verificar se a string só contém letra e espaço em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Quero que o usuário digite seu nome completo, mas, se ele colocar algo diferente de letras, deve exibir uma mensagem de alerta.

O problema é que o nome completo do usuário exige espaço entre as palavras, e o meu programa está considerando esses espaços como um caractere diferente de letra.

Como faço para resolver esse problema e fazer meu programa aceitar as letras e espaços?

Código abaixo:

```
def nome(msg):
    valido = False
    value = ""
    while True:
        frase = str(input(msg))
        if frase.isalpha() and len(frase) >= 12:
            value = str(frase)
            valido = True
        else:
            print("\033[0;31mOPS! Valores inválidos ou nome curto demais.\033[m")
        if valido:
            break
    return value


nome_completo = nome("Digite seu nome completo: ")
print("Seja muito bem-vindo, {0}. ".format(nome_completo))
```

Comment: Troque `frase.isalpha()` por `all(n.isalpha() for n in frase.split(" "))` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro acontece porque o método `str.isalpha` verifica se *todos* os caracteres da string são compostos por letras — "alphabetic", conforme a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.isalpha) coloca.

Uma opção é validar caractere por caractere da string e envolver a verificação na função `all`. Mais ou menos assim:

```
def is_alpha_space(string):
    return all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in string)
```

Nesse exemplo, uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) é utilizada para verificar se cada caractere da string `str` é verdadeiro para `isalpha` ou `isspace`. Após isso, utiliza-se a função `all` para garantir que essa verificação seja verdadeira para cada caractere da string.

Então, poderia fazer assim:

```
def is_alpha_space(str):
    return all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in str)


def nome(msg):
    while True:
        frase = input(msg)

        if not (is_alpha_space(frase) and len(frase) >= 12):
            # Se a frase não estiver válida, imprima a mensagem. Como não há
            # nada depois desse `print` a ser executado, o `while` continuará
            # a repetir este bloco até que o usuário digite um nome válido.
            print("\033[0;31mOPS! Valores inválidos ou nome curto demais.\033[m")
        else:
            # Caso contrário (se o nome estiver válido), retorne-o. O `return`,
            # como encerra a função, também interromperá o `while`.
            return frase


nome_completo = nome("Digite seu nome completo: ")
print("Seja muito bem-vindo, {0}. ".format(nome_completo))
```

Note que eu acabei simplificando a lógica da função `nome` de modo similar ao feito nesta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493678/69296). A conversão para string utilizando o construtor `str` também não é necessária para o retorno da função `input`, uma vez que ela já retorna uma string.

---

Uma outra alternativa para implementar a função `is_alpha_space` seria utilizar uma expressão regular, mas nesse caso acho que seria complicar à toa, uma vez que a solução acima já é bem elegante. :-)

Vide referência no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460426/7445826).

Comment: Opa! Muito bom o cometário, obrigado.