# Funções redutoras devem ser criadas fora ou dentro do meu componente React?

Tags: javascript, react, funções

Olhando a documentação do *hook* [`useReducer`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), verifiquei que a função redutora é criada **fora** do componente:

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Existe alguma vantagem/desvantagem em se utilizar a função redutiva fora da declaração do componente em comparação em utilizar dentro do componente?

Exemplo:

```
function Counter() {
  const initialState = { count: 0 };

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "increment":
        return { count: state.count + 1 };
      case "decrement":
        return { count: state.count - 1 };
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Esse código é criado fora mesmo, mas, tem um ponto todos os componentes podem utilizar, e nesse caso pouco importa porque a regra é clara onde toda a arvore tem a possibilidade de utilizar esse código, ou seja, fica disponível, se atualizar em algum lugar toda a arvore também é atualizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe alguma vantagem/desvantagem em se utilizar a função redutiva fora da declaração do componente em comparação em utilizar dentro do componente?

Sim. É mais vantajoso declará-las fora do componente. Não somente funções redutoras, mas qualquer função deveria ser, idealmente, declarada *fora* do componente.

---

Isso acontece porque, como componentes React nada mais são que meras funções JavaScript, sempre que o React renderiza (ou re-renderiza) um componente, ocorre uma nova chamada à função do componente.

Assim, como a função do componente será chamada *para cada renderização*, tudo o que está dentro da função será criado novamente. Eu expliquei um pouco melhor sobre esse comportamento do JavaScript [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493372/69296).

---

Portanto, é vantajoso definir qualquer função *fora* do componente para evitar recriações de funções (e até mesmo objetos) desnecessariamente.

Claro, isso nem sempre é possível, uma vez que eventualmente funções podem precisar de alguma propriedade que o componente recebe. Nessas situações, alguns caminhos podem ser tomados:

1. Fazer com que a função (declarada *fora* do componente) aceite algum argumento, pelo qual a propriedade será passada à função;
2. Declarar a função *dentro* do componente ao mesmo tempo em que se evita as recriações desnecessárias utilizando o *hook* [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), que [memoiza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) a função passada e só a cria novamente mediante alteração de algum valor passado ao array de dependências do *hook*. O custo disso é que a memoização pode implicar em um custo adicional de memória para o cliente.

Vale observar que o React também provê um *hook* para memoizar objetos mais genéricos, o [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).