# Pq as varias são declaradas vazias e depois recebem algum valor?

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Eu estava vendo 1 vídeo de um projeto de calculadora em javascript, e vi que o prof primeiro declarou uma variável global sem valor, e através de uma função de click, passou um valor para a variável ao invés criar a variável dentro do espoco da função. Qual o sentido desta ação? Não séria melhor criar a variável no espoco da função? Aqui está o código js. Coloquei 2 setas para tentar ajudar onde é que está o foco da pergunta. Muito obrigado:

```
const teclas = document.querySelectorAll('[id*=tecla');
const operadores = document.querySelectorAll('[id*=operador]');
const display = document.querySelector('#display');
var numeroNovo = true;

var numeroAntigo; //VARIAVEL GLOBAL SEM VALOR DO PROF <================

const calculadora = {

        inserirNumero:(evento)=>{
            calculadora.atualizarDisplay(evento.target.textContent);
        },

        inserirOperador:(evento)=>{
            if(!numeroNovo){
                calculadora.calcular(numeroAntigo);
                numeroNovo = true;
                operador = evento.target.textContent;
                console.log("NumeroAntigo: "+numeroAntigo)
                numeroAntigo = display.textContent; //ACRESCENTOU UM VALOR AQUI <===========
            }
        },

        calcular:(numeroAntigo)=>{
            var numeroAtual = display.textContent;
        },

        atualizarDisplay:(texto)=>{
            if(numeroNovo){
                display.innerHTML = texto;
                numeroNovo = false;

            }else{//numeroNovo = false
                display.innerHTML += texto;
                
        }
    }
};

teclas.forEach(tecla => {
    tecla.addEventListener("click", calculadora.inserirNumero);
});

operadores.forEach(operador =>{
    operador.addEventListener("click", calculadora.inserirOperador);
})
```

Comment: se declarar uma variável no contexto local do método, quando o método terminar o valor da variável será perdido, como foi usada a variável em dois métodos "talvez" tenha declarado no escopo public para reaproveitar, mas como passa por paramentro poderia ser local, mas olhando o código não ficou claro

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)

Comment: Existe uma coisa chamada *escopo*, que basicamente define onde cada variável "existe" e pode ser acessada por outras partes do código. Veja mais detalhes [aqui](/q/13034/112052) e [aqui](/q/47165/112052). No caso, se você declara a variável dentro de uma função, ela é local àquela função e não pode ser acessada fora dela. Ex: https://ideone.com/YilCRS - Então _provavelmente_ a intenção era essa, já que ele parece imprimir no console o valor que o display tinha anteriormente, mas como o display é alterado em outra função, o valor anterior tem que "sobreviver" às chamadas de cada uma.

Comment: Como não tem o HTML, não dá pra testar adequadamente, mas vc testou declarando a variável dentro da função? O valor dela "se perderia" depois que `inserirOperador` fosse chamada, e você não conseguiria ter o valor anterior do display guardado ali. Não sei também se o código está incompleto, já que a função `calcular` recebe o `numeroAntigo` como parâmetro, mas não use ele para nada (além da variável `operador`, que também é setada mas não é usada pra nada depois).

Comment: Fora o uso de *arrow functions*, que [a própria documentação recomenda que não seja usado como métodos de um objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Mas enfim, acho que é isso

Answer (score 0):

Se a variável fosse definida dentro do método `inserirOperador`, é como se a variável existisse apenas dentro desse método e fora dele não existiria.

Quando definimos fora e alteramos, qualquer outro método terá essa variável com o valor alterado.