# Escopo de variáveis dentro do $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, escopo-de-variáveis

A variável `role` recebe um novo valor em cada `Loop`, quando ela está dentro do `$.getJSON` ela pega o segundo valor do array e não muda mais. Há dois `console.log();` no código, coloquei o retorno deles ao lado do mesmo. Alguém sabe a causa disso e como me desfazer desse cenário indesejável?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var emails = ["phellipelins@gmail.com", "phellipelins@gmail.com"],
    TeamRole = ["founder", "manager"],
    hashMail;

  for (var i=0 ; i < emails.length ; i++){ 
    hashMail = "http://www.gravatar.com/" + md5(emails[i].toLowerCase().trim()) + ".json?callback=?";
    role = TeamRole[i];
    console.log(role); // > founder > manager

    $.getJSON(hashMail, function (data) {
      console.log(role); // > manager > manager
      $("#profile-container").append(
            "<div>" +
                "<img src='" + data.entry[0].thumbnailUrl + "?s=200>" +
                "<p>" + data.entry[0].displayName + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + self.role + "</p>" +
                "<p>" + data.entry[0].aboutMe + "</p>" +
            "</div>";
      );
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Como funcionam closures em javascript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215) (veja na [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1862/215) a parte que fala de "*pitfalls*")

Comment: Também relacionada (ou duplicata?): [Como usar o valor atual de uma variável numa função mais interna?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/como-usar-o-valor-atual-de-uma-variavel-numa-funcao-mais-interna/1239#1239)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que `getJSON` é assíncrono. Quando o *callback* executa, o *loop* já terminou. O escopo das suas variáveis é a função que as contém (no caso, o *callback* do document.ready), e não o bloco do *loop*. Uma solução é introduzir uma nova função, executada imediatamente, capturando cada valor da variável `role` separadamente:

```
for (var i=0 ; i < emails.length ; i++){ 
  hashMail = "http://www.gravatar.com/" + md5(emails[i].toLowerCase().trim()) + ".json?callback=?";
  var role = TeamRole[i];
  console.log(role); // > founder > manager
  (function(role) {
      $.getJSON(hashMail, function (data) {
        console.log(role); // > manager > manager
        $("#profile-container").append(
              "<div>" +
                  "<img src='" + data.entry[0].thumbnailUrl + "?s=200>" +
                  "<p>" + data.entry[0].displayName + "</p>" +
                  "<p>" + role + "</p>" +
                  "<p>" + data.entry[0].aboutMe + "</p>" +
              "</div>";
        );
      });
  }(role));
};
```

**Nota:** adicionei `var` para declarar sua variável `role`, pois ela estava virando global.

Comment: Funcionou, porém tem mais um comportamento "estranho". O array de emails, suponhamos que ele contenha "exemplo1@email.com" e "exemplo2@email.com". Apesar da função ser APPEND o código insere de trás pra frente.

Comment: Ele "appenda" na ordem em que as respostas chegarem. Não há garantia de ordem para recebimento das respostas de requisições assíncronas. A resposta que chegar primeiro é inserida primeiro, e fica antes na lista.

Comment: @PhellipeLins Se não conseguir resolver essa questão da ordem do append, sugiro postar uma pergunta separada, pois é um problema totalmente diferente.