# Comportamento não usual de variáveis capturadas por um clusure em um for

Tags: javascript

Considere um objeto `obj` qualquer:

```
obj = {q: 1, w: 2, e: 3, r: 4, t: 5, y: 6};
```

Agora estou iterando sob as chaves do objeto e criando uma função anônima que usa essa chave:

```
list = []
for (var key in obj) {
    list.push(function() {
        return key;
    });
}
```

Mas isso não funciona: `console.log(list[0]()) // isso mostra "y"`. É como se a variável `key` usada fosse sempre a da última iteração e não a da iteração que criou a função. Modificar assim não resolve o problema:

```
list = []
for (var key in obj) {
    var dummy = key;
    list.push(function() {
        return dummy;
    });
}
```

Mesmo eu tendo criado uma variável diferente em cada iteração e me referido ao valor dela especificamente, o resultado é o mesmo. Nem mesmo escrever algo como o seguinte funciona.

```
list = []
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    var key = keys[i];
    list.push(function() {
        return key;
    });
}
```

Por que? O que está acontecendo aqui? Como escrever um código que faça o proposto?

Comment: Parece o mesmo problema de [uma pergunta que fiz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1237/227) há algum tempo. Ou não?

Comment: @utluiz É exatamente a mesma coisa, só que propriedades em vez de índices numéricos. Votei pra fechar como duplicata.

Comment: E só pra não deixar sem resposta, essas variáveis **não** estão capturadas: o escopo léxico de JavaScript é por função, não por bloco: o `key` (ou `dummy`) criado dentro do `for` é o mesmo para todas as iterações do `for`. Quando o `for` muda, a variável muda. Para capturar aquele valor, veja o penúltimo exemplo da [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1239/215) à pergunta duplicada.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Discordo de você num detalhe: as variáveis são sim capturadas pelas funções anônimas do exemplo. Todo o escopo de fora (e aqui suponho que seja o escopo global) é capturado, incluindo as variáveis em questão. Como você mesmo já disse numa resposta (se bem me lembro), *closures* em js nada mais são que uma consequência da maneira como funciona a cadeia de escopo na linguagem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Verdade, me expressei mal. Quis dizer que essas variáveis não têm seu valor fixado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Duplicata de [**Como usar o valor atual de uma variável numa função mais interna?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/como-usar-o-valor-atual-de-uma-variavel-numa-funcao-mais-interna)

**Solução:** Usar uma função imediatamente invocada para dar um escopo para a variável.

```
list = []
for (var key in obj) {
    (function(key) {
        list.push(function() {
            return key;
        });
    })(key);
}
```