# Google Maps API - janela abre sempre a ultima

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? estou trabalhando no maps da Google, pegando os clientes no meu banco e colocando os Markers no mapa conforme sua latitude e longitude, quando clica no marker abre uma janela exibindo informações, até aqui tudo bem, o meu problema é:

quando eu clico em algum marker, ele sempre abre o ultimo

meu codigo:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({                                      
                url: url, 
                format: 'json',
                success: function(rows){
                        rows = $.parseJSON(rows);
                        for (var i in rows){    
                                var row = rows[i],          
                                    id = row[0],
                                    nome = row[1],
                                    lat = row[9],
                                    lon = row[10];
                                    codigo += '';
```

Aqui começa o marker - 
1ª - pego a posicao

```
                                    var Posicao = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
```

2ª - faço o Marker

```
                                    var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: Posicao,
                                            map: map,
                                            center: Posicao,
                                            icon: imagemPin,
                                            title:"LUGAR",
                                            zIndex: 3});
```

3ª - as info da janela

```
                                    var textoInfo = "<img src='img/logo.png' style='width: 60%;'><p>Ola"+nome+", voce ta por aqui!</p>";                

                                    var infoLocal = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: textoInfo
                                    });
```

4ª - aqui o evento quando eu clicar em um Marker

```
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "click", function() {
                                        infoLocal.open(map,Marker);
                                    });

                                    //END MARKER

                        } 
                } 
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está lá no final, no evento:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "click", function() {
    infoLocal.open(map,Marker);
});
```

Acontece que no momento do clique, `Marker` já não é mais aquele que você espera, e sim o último do loop. Trata-se do problema discutido na pergunta *[Como usar o valor atual de uma variável numa função mais interna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/como-usar-o-valor-atual-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-numa-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mais-interna)*

Solução rápida:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "click", (function(mrk, info) {
    return function() {
        info.open(map,mrk);
    };
}(Marker, infoLocal)));
```

O que o código acima faz é criar uma função anônima e invocá-la imediatamente, passando o `Marker` atual. Dentro dessa função ele tem um novo nome, `mrk`, que será "lembrado" (via [closure](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)) separadamente para cada iteração do seu loop. Essa função gera e retorna o listener que é passado ao `google.maps.event.addListener`.

Comment: ta dando esse erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; - no final ali : (Marker));

Comment: Corrigido, tente agora

Comment: obrigado @bfavaretto, seu codigo esta correto, funcionou!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, precisava fazer o mesmo com o conteúdo.