# Não consigo aprender sintaxe for

Tags: javascript, loop

Eu consigo aprender subjetivamente por alguns segundos, mas não consigo fixar por mais que eu tente. já repeti aulas, fiz exercícios e tudo, mas a sintaxe e suas variações simplesmente não fixam pra mim.

Por exemplo, se eu faço:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ 
    alert(i); 
}
```

Chamando o `alert` dentro do *loop*, alerta 9 janelas de cada vez acrescendo 1 numero até 10, normal. Mas não entendo porque se chamar o `alert(i)` fora do *loop* aparece apenas 10.

Comment: Se você não esta entendendo porque `alert(i)` fora do `for` exibe "10", você não esta entendendo escopo, não como funciona um `for`. Mostre o código inteiro (Javascript apenas) que esta utilizando para poder explicar melhor.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1237/129

Answer (score 19):

Sintaxe do for:

```
for(
   INICIALIZACAO;
   CONDICAO para executar o CODIGO entre { };
   tarefa para fazer depois de cada execucao do CODIGO
)
{
   CODIGO a ser executado repetidas vezes, enquanto a CONDICAO for verdadeira
}
```

Vou mostrar uma descrição passo a passo. Para isso, numerei as linhas e diminuí pra 3 loops apenas:

```
1. for( var i=0; i<3; i++ )
2. {
3.    alert(i);
4. }
5. alert(i);
```

Ok, veja o como esse código é entendido pelo seu sistema:

```
a) Estamos na linha 1. Aqui foi "criado" um for, e definido que i é zero;  
b) o programa avança para a linha 2, com i valendo zero;
c) avançamos para a linha 3 e é exibido o valor de i, que é zero;  
d) o programa avança para a linha 4. Como o escopo do for encerrou, é executado i++ e testado se i<3
e) i agora é um, portanto SIM, i é menor que três, então VOLTAMOS para a linha 2
f) avançamos para a linha 3, e é exibido o valor de i, que é um;
g) o programa avança para a linha 4. Como o escopo do for encerrou, é executado i++ e testado se i<3
h) i agora é dois, portanto SIM, i é menor que três, então VOLTAMOS para a linha 2
i) avançamos para a linha 3, e é exibido o valor de i, que é dois;
j) o programa avança para a linha 4. Como o escopo do for encerrou, é executado i++ e testado se i<3
k) i é três, portanto NÃO É menor que três, portanto AVANÇAMOS para a linha 5.  
l) Pronto, acabou o loop, i vale 3
m) na linha 5, é exibido o valor de i, que é 3
```

Notar que eu simplifiquei absurdamente a lógica, as etapas são um pouco mais complexas internamente. Como mencionado pelo @mgibsonbr, **o teste de i<3 já acontece entre os passos (a) e (b)**, "pulando" de cara pra linha 5 caso não seja verdadeiro o resultado (mas não se preocupe com isso agora).

O melhor mesmo é entender que esse "vai e vem" da linha 2 até a 4 só acontece enquanto a condição ( i<3 ) for verdadeira.

O código acima equivale a esse aqui:

```
var i = 0; // iniciamos com i=0
for(;i<3;) // executamos repetidamente o que está entre "{" e "}" enquanto i<3
{
    alert(i); // mostramos i
    i++;      // incrementamos i
}
alert(i); // Somente quando i<3 for falso é que chegaremos nessa linha aqui
```

Comment: muito esclarecedor. você realmente me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 10):

Se você está aprendendo laços pela primeira vez, ajuda começar com um mais simples - como o `while` - e só então passar para o `for`. Isso vai ajudar a entender exatamente o que acontece no seu código.

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) { alert(i); }
```

É equivalente a:

```
// Iniciação
var i = 0;
// Teste da condição
while ( i < 10 ) {
    // Corpo
    alert(i);
    // Passo
    i++;
}
```

Observando dessa forma, você percebe que:

- A variável foi criada e atribuída a zero antes mesmo do loop, e [em JavaScript] ela continua existindo depois que acaba o loop;

  ```
      ...
  }
  alert(i); // A variável ainda existe aqui
  ```
- Existe a chance dele não entrar no loop nem uma vez!

  ```
  var i = 20;
  while ( i < 10 ) {
      ...
  ```
- O passo é executado antes de testar a condição; por isso, qualquer efeito colateral que ele tenha (no caso, o de incrementar `i`) ocorrerá não importa se o loop vai continuar ou vai parar:

  ```
      ...
      alert(i); // 9
      i++; // aumentou 1, pra 10
  } // Saiu do loop - pois a condição i < 10 ficou falsa
  alert(i); // 10
  ```

Eu sugiro você tentar dominar o `while` primeiro, pois tudo o que os outros laços fazem o `while` também dá conta de fazer - de forma mais simples, porém não tão concisa. Quando você estiver bem acostumado com ele, aí você pode começar a enxergar padrões no seu uso, e usar as outras formas para simplificar esses padrões:

- Um código é executado uma vez antes do loop, e é igual ao que está no corpo do loop:

  ```
  código
  while ( condição ) {
      código
  }
  ```

  Pode ser simplificado para:

  ```
  do {
      código
  } while(condição);
  ```
- Um código é executado antes do loop, e outro no final da fase que se repete:

  ```
  início
  while ( condição ) {
      código
      fim
  }
  ```

  Pode ser simplificado para:

  ```
  for ( início ; condição ; fim ) {
      código
  }
  ```

  A sequência executada, então, fica da seguinte forma:

  - Zero iterações:

    ```
    início, condição
    ```
  - Uma iteração:

    ```
    início, condição, código, fim, condição
    ```
  - Duas iterações:

    ```
    início, condição, código, fim, condição, código, fim, condição
    ```
  - Três iterações:

    ```
    início, condição, código, fim, condição, código, fim, condição, código, fim, condição
    ```
  - Etc.

Comment: perfeito. deu certo começar pelo while, agora já entendi tudo de forma + clara.

Answer (score 9):

A variavel nao sai de escopo (ela nao e "deletada") assim que o `for` acaba, entao o `i` fica com o ultimo valor dele.

A ultima comparacao no seu exemplo e com `i = 10`. Ele faz `10 < 10`, o que retorna falso, e sai do loop. Logo, ele vai imprimir `10` fora do loop.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, primeiramente é necessário saber quando será para que server o FOR.

Basicamente, o FOR serve para você repetir um algorítimo N vezes.

Sintaxe:

```
for(INICIO DAS VARIAVEIS; CONDIÇÃO ; CONSEQUENCIA ){
  //SEU CODIGO AQUI
}
```

Exemplo:

```
var cont;
var totalVoltas = 10;
  for(cont = 0;cont < totalVoltas ;cont++){
    alert("Volta número "+cont);
  }
```

Este código irá lhe *alertar* `10` vezes na tela, do mesmo modo que você fez na pergunta.
Neste código, eu `INICIALIZEI A VARIÁVEL` com o `valor 0`, logo após faço a `CONDIÇÃO`, e no fim `INCREMENTO` mais 1 na variável que inicializei no inicio do FOR.

O FOR é muito utilizado para percorrer Array, pois tem como acessar todos os índices fazendo este loop.
Exemplo:

```
var semanas = ["Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sábado"];
var cont;
var str = "Dias da Semana:\n";
//Como um array sempre começa na posição zero, o cont será zero.
for(cont = 0; cont < semanas.length;cont++){
  str += semanas[cont]+"\n";  //Aqui eu 'Acesso' o valor do array contido na posição referente ao valor de cont.
}
alert(str);
```

O do porque após o loop o valor de `i` é `10` é de que, o método de `INCREMENTO` altera a própria variável.
Sendo assim, ao término do loop, o cont foi `incrementado 10` vezes, chegando ao final com `10`.

Beleza, espero ter ajudado. :)

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que entender para memorizar !!
É como uma volta, uma repetição,

**Para i começando com 0 até 10 acrescentando ++ significa passo de um em um,**

alert(**1**);

**Volta**

**Para i começando com 1 até 10 acrescentando ++ significa passo de um em um,**

alert(**2**);

**Volta**

**E assim até 10**

```
for( var i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ 
 alert(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Diferentes estruturas de repetição: `Enquanto(while)`, `Para(for)`, `Repita(do)`

As três funcionam com o mesmo intuito, eles executam uma linha de código até que a condição pré estabelecida seja alcançada.... o `While` e o `Do` não tem em sua própria estrutura básica um contador, desse modo devemos criar um dentro dele

Já o `For` possui essa estrutura por default, enfim... os três são praticamente a mesma coisa, a unica coisa é que o for deixa o código a ser executado mais 'limpo'

> WHILE

```
Enquanto (condição) Faça
    (bloco de código)
Fim Enquanto
```

> DO

```
Repita
    (bloco de código)
Ate (condição)
```

Em ambas acima há a necessidade de se declarar um contador, e incrementa-lo dentro do bloco de códigos, senão o código fica em `loop` infinito, e na maioria dos casos, principalmente em linguagens de alto nível, não queremos que isso ocorra rs

> FOR

```
Para (V) De (vi) Até (vf) Passo (p) Faça
    (bloco de código)
Fim Para
```

Nesse caso não há a necessidade de se declarar o contador e incrementa-lo dentro do bloco de códigos, visto que já fizemos isso na condição pré estabelecida....

As três implementações servem o mesmo proposito, vai mais da sua facilidade de trabalhar com elas.....

Seria algo parecido com o `GOTO` tão aclamado em algumas linguagens "arcaicas"
Do mesmo modo poderiamos criar uma estrutura simples de `if` usando o `goto`

EXP:

```
linha de memoria 1: I = 0;
linha de memoria 2: Se (I<=5){
linha de memoria 3:    I += 1;
linha de memoria 4:    (bloco de código)
linha de memoria 5:    GOTO linha de memoria 2;
linha de memoria 6: Fim-Se
```

ENFIM... é complicado explicar, apenas devemos nos adentar que ele serve como um repetidor de código mais simples de ser escrito, por isso hj é tão utilizado, o contador vc já define e incrementa na própria condição

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que sua pergunta é "por que aparece de 1 até 10 quando eu coloco dentro das chaves e quando eu coloco fora aparece só 10"

no seu exemplo o FOR ta adicionando +1(tal do i++) na variavel "i" a cada vez que ele roda no FOR, então basicamente o foi feito a soma e depois mostrado o valor, diferente de quando é dentro do FOR que a cada +1 que acontece ele já invoca o "alert".

o que acontece dentro do computador quando você poem o alert dentro do for é:

```
i=0
Alert(0) //mostra mensagem
i=1 //0+1 = 1
alert(1)
i=2 //1+1 = 2
alert(2)
i=3 //2+1 = 3
alert(3)
```

e assim sucessivamente

No caso do alert fora do for o que acontece no computador é o seguinte:

```
i=0
i=1 //0+1
i=2 //1+1
i=3 //2+1
i=4 //3+1
i=5 //4+1
i=6 //5+1
```

então basicamente o que acontece é que ele soma tudo e depois ele mostra(quando ta fora do FOR) e quando ele ta dentro, a cada vez que ele somar 1 ele vai rodar o alert() também o que vai mostrar o numero ATUAL que está na variavel i...

Espero que tenha entendido a diferença de usar dentro ou fora do for

Answer (score 0):

Bom, o primeiro passo é aprender o que é escopo, que segundo Maurício Samy Silva (o consagrado Maujor), em JavaScript Guia do Programador:

> *Um conceito muito importante ao declararmos uma variável é o chamado escopo da variável, que é o ambiente ou, mais precisamente, o trecho ou região do script no qual a variável assume o valor que foi para ela declarado.*

Variáveis de escopo global, podem ser chamadas em qualquer parte do script, já variáveis de escopo local podem ser chamadas somente no trecho do script no qual foram declaradas. Para se declarar uma variável no escopo local utiliza-se a palavra-chave `var`, já para declarar uma variável no escopo global, omite-se a mesma:

```
var a = 5; // Variável "a" declarada no escopo local
b = 10; // Variável "b" declarada no escopo global
```

Exemplo que ilustra o funcionamento do escopo

```
a = 5;

primeira_funcao = function(){

var a = 15;

alert(a); // alerta 15

}

primeira_funcao(); // Chamada à primeira função

segunda_funcao = function(){

alert(a); // alerta 5

}

segunda_funcao(); // Chamada à segunda função

alert(a); // alerta 5
```

Como visto no exemplo acima, a variável `a` declarada inicialmente com o valor de `5`, foi alertada, tanto na segunda função quanto chamada fora das funções, com seu valor original, somente sendo alterado o valor da mesma na primeira função, onde foi declarado `var a = 15;` iniciando uma outra variável com o nome `a`, porém no escopo local, logo quando chamado `alert(a);` foi alertado `15` ao invés de `5`.

A sintaxe do for está muito bem explicada nas outras respostas, então não abordarei a mesma aqui, bons estudos ;)