# Como usar o laço para(for) em Portugol?

Tags: loop, portugol

Estou aprendendo algoritmo, mas fiquei na dúvida quanto ao uso de Laço `para` (`for`). Sei que é uma pergunta tola, mas infelizmente tenho pouco acesso a internet. Eu tenho o livro mas a duvida é essa!

Comment: Qual é a linguagem? O laço `for` costuma ser bem parecido de linguagem pra linguagem, mas ainda assim seria bom especificar. E não entendi bem sua pergunta: você disse que ficou na dúvida, mas em relação a que? Sua sintaxe, semântica, outra coisa... Se puder [edit] acrescentando mais detalhes seria muito bem vindo!

Comment: em portugol mesmo.

Comment: Relacionado: ["não consigo aprender sintaxe for"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33674/215)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O laço "para" é uma das formas de **desvio condicional**, ou seja, teste se uma determinada condição é satisfeita, e dependendo do resultado, desvie para uma instrução diferente ou siga pra próxima. Ela é composta de quatro partes:

```
para ( iniciação ; condição ; passo )
    corpo
fimpara

próxima instrução
```

1. A `iniciação` é simplesmente um código que executa antes de iniciar o laço; dependendo da linguagem, qualquer variável definida ali somente existirá dentro do código desse laço. Em outras, ela continua existindo fora dele.
2. A `condição` é um teste para verificar se deve continuar dentro do laço ou sair fora dele. Tipicamente ela é testada após a iniciação, de modo que se não for satisfeita ele sai do laço imediatamente - sem executar o `corpo` e o `passo` nenhuma vez - e segue para a próxima instrução.

   Se a condição for verdadeira, ele executa o `corpo`, depois o `passo`, e em seguida testa a condição novamente, para ver se ela continua verdadeira. Se continuar, repete essa etapa de novo e de novo. Apenas quando a condição se tornar falsa é que ele sai do laço, indo para a próxima instrução depois dele.
3. O `corpo` é o trecho principal de código, que será repetido zero ou mais vezes. Ele tem acesso às variáveis da `iniciação` e `condição`, e pode manipulá-las ou não. Também pode executar comandos que "forçam" a quebra do laço (`break`) ou que continuam a partir do `passo` (`continue`) antes de chegar ao final do `corpo`. Se esses comandos não forem utilizados, o corpo segue até o final, antes de passar pra próxima etapa.
4. O `passo` é simplesmente um código pequeno que executa após o `corpo`, mas antes de testar novamente a `condição`. Em geral, sua função é manipular a(s) variável(is) que compõe(m) a `condição`, de modo a dar-lhe a chance de sair do laço.

Um exemplo completo seria:

```
para ( seja i igual a 1 ; enquanto i for menor ou igual a 10 ; incremente i em 1 )
    imprima i vezes i, enter
fimpara
imprima "Fim"
```

Saída:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
Fim
```

Todas as partes, exceto a condição, são opcionais. Se você omitir a `iniciação` e o `passo`, [o resultado é o mesmo que um laço `enquanto` (*while*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33683/215):

```
para ( ; teste() ; )
    faça algo()
fimpara

enquanto ( teste() )
    faça algo()
fimenquanto
```

A sintaxe mais comum para o laço "para" é aquela da família do C (inclui Java, JavaScript e outras):

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", i*i);
}
```

Algumas linguagens, como Python e Ruby, não possuem esse laço, apenas um de nome parecido - o `for..in`, usado para percorrer os elementos de uma lista (real ou abstrata). Muitas vezes esses laços são referidos como simplesmente `for`, mas sua construção é diferente.

Em portugol, o laço "para" com uma única variável fica mais ou menos assim (não tenho certeza da sintaxe exata):

```
para ( i de 1 a 10 passo 1 ) faca
    escreva(i*i)
fimpara
```

Answer (score 4):

O `para` .. `faca` (faça) é uma estrutura de repetição do `portugol` com variáveis de controle, e serve para que você execute um determinado bloco de código interno por `n` vezes.

Um exemplo simples:

```
algoritmo "contador"
    var
    C: inteiro
inicio
      Para C <- 1 ate 10 faca
      Escreva (C)
      Fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

A saída deste algoritmo no [`Visualg`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg) será:

> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
>
> *** Fim da execução.
>   *** Feche esta janela para retornar ao Visualg.

Além da utilização do Visualg em seus estudos, aconselho também que você assista [esta aula](http://www.cursoemvideo.com/lesson/curso-algoritmos-11-estruturas-repeticao-parte-3/), e consulte [este manual](http://pt.slideshare.net/GabrielFaustino/manual-de-portugol).

Bons estudos.

Answer (score 3):

Em outras palavras a função irá fazer a mesma tarefa um certo número de vezes

Exemplo numa corrida:

Irá começar com a volta 0 // int x = 0; (no modelo do Lucas Henrique)

Terá 100 voltas // x <= 100; (no modelo do Lucas Henrique)

Para cada volta completada acrescente +1 //  x++; (no modelo do Lucas Henrique)

Abaixo desta declaração você informa o que o programa irá fazer, no caso da corrida iria executar a função correr até completar as 100 voltas.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: valeu.. ajudou muito

Comment: Então se puder, vote na questão, no lado esquero da minha resposta, sabe fazer isso?

Comment: O AP ainda não tem reputação suficiente para votar (precisa de 10). A propósito, `for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )` vai executar `101` vezes, não `100`.

Comment: Verdade mgibsonbr 101 vezes, ;)

Answer (score 2):

for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
{
   //código que irá ser incrementado
}

sendo que **int x = 0** => está criando uma variável inteira x que recebe 0, que é o ponto de partida do seu laço de repetição. Ou seja, ele vai começar em 0.

**x<= 10** => ele vai executar até que a condição seja menor ou igual a 10.

**x++** => é a incrementação do seu laço. Nesse caso, representa que ele vai somar o valor inicial a cada iteração.

Comment: "vai executar até que a condição seja" acho que você quis dizer "enquanto a condição seja", certo? (ou até que a condição seja falsa...)

Answer (score 1):

O `for` costuma ser usado para fazer iterações (definidas pela linguagem ou por um recurso da linguagem) ou também como um loop condicional definido da seguinte maneira:

1. Valor da variável de escopo a ser criada
2. Condição de existência do loop
3. Função incondicional do loop

Em relação às duas possibilidades, tomo Python e C. Iteradores:

```
for x in range(0,100):
    # faça o que quiser aqui com "x"
```

E com a condição:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
```

Comment: opa valeu ai!!!

Comment: @LeonardoSales Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, você deve escolher uma resposta, faça um tour para entender como funciona o : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour