# Lógica do laço de repetição com o for

Tags: javascript, loop, variáveis, for

Considere o código JavaScript abaixo.

```js
var r = [2, 5, 6, 18, 20, 10, 23, 12, 19, 10];
var s = [1, 5, 7, 13, 18, 21, 10, 25, 32, 17, 3];
var x = [0];
var i;

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  x[i] = r[i];
}

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  x[i + 10] = s[i];
}

document.write(x[13] + "<br>");
document.write(i);
```

Serão exibidos na tela os valores

- (A) 13 e 10.
- (B) 7 e 11.
- (C) 18 e 10.
- (D) 13 e 11.
- (E) 7 e 10.

Resposta:

> Resposta: Letra D

---

Executei o código e tudo *OK*, a resposta está correta, porém fiquei em duvida na letra **A** e me enrolei no `for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)`. Por que está incrementando mais uma vez e saindo `i=11` em vez de `i=10`? Executei a mesma função em java  e se eu fizer

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; contador = ++i) contador=11

for(int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; contador = i++) contador=10
```

Esse último exemplo não é igual ao exemplo da questão?

Comment: A variável `i` é incrementada após a execução do bloco `for`, logo, após a última execução válida para o bloco `for`, ainda vai rodar o último incremento. Porém, não vai cair na cláusula `i <= 10`. Logo, vai quebrar o loop do `for`.

Comment: O resultado é *11* pois o `for` irá somar o valor `i+1` (em `i++`) e só depois irá verificar a condição `i <= 10`.

Comment: Creio que está respondido aqui, em especial o ítem `m)` da resposta que contém o passo a passo [Não consigo aprender a sintaxe do `for`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33674/70)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagino que entenda que o laço vai até o 10, ou seja quando ainda estiver em 10, é igual a atende a condição de ser menor ou igual. Certo?

Quando o laço é encerrado? Quando for maior que 10, certo?  Quando isso ocorre? Quando o `i` vale 11 a condição fica falsa. Neste momento o laço é encerrado e nada dentro dele é executado.

O valor não volta pra trás sozinho, se o último valor de `i` era 11, continua sendo 11.

Note que entre um laço e outro o valor é 10. Aí pode estar perguntando porque quando entrou no segundo `for` e voltou para 0. E é respondido pelo `i = 0`, você mandou zerar.

Você mandou imprimir o valor atual de `i`, que, como vimos acima, é 11 quando saiu do laço.

A dificuldade provavelmente porque não está pesando logicamente, como o computador trabalha, em passos. O `for` não é um mecanismo que conta de 0 à 10 e pronto.

Colocando alguns "prints* dá para visualizar melhor:

```js
var r = [2, 5, 6, 18, 20, 10, 23, 12, 19, 10];
var s = [1, 5, 7, 13, 18, 21, 10, 25, 32, 17, 3];
var x = [0];
var i;
console.log("i = " + i);
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    x[i] = r[i];
    console.log("i = " + i);
}
console.log("i = " + i);
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    x[i + 10] = s[i];
    console.log("i = " + i);
}
console.log("i = " + i);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/For2.js).

- [Não consigo aprender sintaxe for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33674/101)
- [For com um ";" no começo do laço, o que significa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174153/101)

Answer (score 3):

A sintaxe do laço `for` é:

```
for ([inicialização]; [condição]; [expressão final])
   declaração
```

E a ordem de execução é:

1. Inicialização;
2. Verifica a condição;
3. Se a condição for verdadeira, executa a declaração;
4. Avalia a expressão final;
5. Volta ao passo 2;

Isto é, a expressão final sempre será avaliado no final de cada iteração. Como a última ocorre quando `i = 10`, ao se avaliar a expressão final, a variável passará a valer 11.

No computador seria algo como:

- Inicialização, `i = 0`;
- Verifica se `i <= 10`;
- Executa a declaração;
- Avalia a expressão final, ficando `i = 1`;
- Verifica se `i <= 10`;
- Executa a declaração;
- ...
- Avalia a expressão final, ficando `i = 10`;
- Verifica se `i <= 10`;
- Executa a declaração;
- Avalia a expressão final, ficando `i = 11`;
- Verifica se `i <= 10`;
- Encerra o laço;