# Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando "let" e "var"?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis

Desde que foi introduzida a palavra `let` no [ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) eu só tenho ouvido falar a respeito, até então não vi nenhum exemplo prático e para ser sincero não sei muito bem o que é uma variável `let` e como ela se comporta. A única coisa que entendi, e bem superficialmente, é que ela serve para declarar uma variável local, algo relacionado a escopo.

O que são variáveis `let`? Para que elas servem? Quando utilizá-las ao invés de `var`?

Comment: Além disso tudo que você já leu sobre o escopo de bloco, o let também não tem o comportamento de HOISTING que o var tem, que basicamente "joga" a variável para o topo do código, mesmo quando foi declarada mais em baixo

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Há uma diferença de escopo.

Você deve saber que qualquer variável "declarada" sem `let`, `var` ou `const` tem escopo global, ela vale para todo o *script*.

Talvez saiba que sempre deve usar o `var` para tornar o escopo local, ou seja, ele vale apenas dentro da função onde ela foi declarada (pode ser global se não está dentro de função).

Mas isso não era suficiente, precisa ter um um escopo de bloco. O `let` foi criado, e está disponível nas versões mais novas da linguagem justamente para prover este escopo mais limitado.

Exemplos:

```js
function exemplo() {
    console.log(x);
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        console.log(x);
    };
    console.log(x);
};
function exemplo2() {
    //console.log(x); //daria erro
    for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++ ) {
        console.log(x);
    };
    //console.log(x); //daria erro
}
exemplo();
console.log(" ");
exemplo2();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/LetVar.js).

[Documentação do `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) pode ser usado em versões mais novas da linguagem e equivale ao `let` só que é uma constante.

Como não é qualquer navegador que suporta estes comandos mais novos, eles devem ser evitados, até ter certeza que o objetivo é só rodar em *browsers* mais novos.

Quando der para usar de forma geral, o `let` é preferível, o escopo mais restrito sempre é preferível. Se bem que se você manter suas funções bem pequenas como manda as tais da "boas práticas" não fará tanta diferença assim usar um ou outro. E de fato às vezes o `var` é uma mão na roda quando precisa do valor "vivo" após o término de um escopo (não que não dê para fazer com `let` também).

Tem ainda um outro motivo para o `let` ter sido criado, é resolver uma questão de criar suas próprias referências em *closures*, eles não podiam mudar a semântica da linguagem em algo que já existia, eles criaram algo novo, assim a nova semântica seria *opt-in*. Vejamos este exemplo:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = () => console.log("Valor: " + i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Parece estranho, certo? O `var` deixa a variável viva por toda a função onde está declarada (neste caso é até global, mas dá na mesma), então a captura de uma *closure* pega uma referência para essa variável que é considerada universal para a função. Agora vejamos com o `let` que faz com que o escopo seja o menor possível, ou seja, a variável só existe no bloco `for`:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = () => console.log("Valor: " + i);
}
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Por isso desde que use o Edge, FireFox 44 pra frente, Chrome desde 49 (41 em modo estrito, desde a 4 se ligar manualmente), Safari 11 e outros baseados neles, prefira o `let`. O IE 11 aceita o `let`, mas não trata a *closure* corretamente. Ou seja onde não funciona a pessoa já está acostumada com muita coisa dando errado.

Só lembre-se que se você usar o `let` deve usar algum [transpilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) que gere um código mais adequado para versões antigas, ou ter certeza absoluta que sua página nunca será acessada por navegadores antigos. Garantindo isso, de forma geral, deve sempre preferir o `let`. O `var` fica para rodar em *browsers* antigos que você não rodará um [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) ou algo assim.

Answer (score 36):

> `let` e `var` têm muitas semelhanças mas algumas diferenças importantes.

## Diferenças:

#### - `let` não exporta para global

Uma variável em escopo global declarada com `let` não é exportada como global.

Exemplo ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/a74pz3v4/)):

```
var x = 'foo';
let y = 'bar';

console.log(window.x, window.y); // foo undefined
```

#### - `let` cria um escopo de bloco mesmo dentro de `if` statements.

Ao contrário de `var` que quando usado sobrepõe/re-inicia a variável e torna-a disponível dentro do escopo da função em que está, `let` é mais refinado/detalhado e permite diferenças em escopo de blocos. Isto é valido para blocos `if`, `for`, `while` por exemplo.

Exemplo ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/u9r7u599/1)):

```
var x = 'foo1';
let y = 'bar1';
if (true == true) {
  var x = 'foo2';
  let y = 'bar2';
  console.log(x, y); // foo2 bar2
}

console.log(x, y); // foo2 bar1
```

#### - re-declarar uma variável com `let`no mesmo escopo dá erro

Se re-declarar-mos uma variável duas vezes no mesmo escopo var dar erro. Isso previne erros difíceis de detectar.

```
var x = 'foo1';
let y = 'bar1';

var x = 'foo2';
let y = 'bar2'; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'y' has already been declared
```

#### - `let` só pode ser usada na linha seguinte

Com `var` é possivel declarar uma variável e usá-la dentro do escopo. Mesmo que o código ainda não tenha lido a linha que atribui o valor à variável ela já está iniciada e quanto muito dá `undefined`. Com `let` isso daria erro.

Ou seja, isto funciona:

```
console.log(x); // undefined
var x = 'foo';
```

mas isto dá erro:

```
console.log(x); // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
let x = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 26):

Conforme descrição na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> let permite que você declare variáveis limitando seu escopo no bloco, instrução, ou em uma expressão na qual ela é usada. Isso é inverso da keyword var, que define uma variável globalmente ou no escopo inteiro de uma função, independentemente do escopo de bloco.

Um exemplo bem simples usando o laço `for`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(i); // 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 9
}
alert(i); // i não está definida

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(i); // 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 9
}
alert(i); // 10
```

Answer (score 10):

Bom, fundamentalmente falando, `var` e `let` são modificadores da abrangência de escopo da variável, ou seja, definem até onde é possível referenciar tal variável dentro do escopo em questão.

## Explicações

## Modificador `var`

Como a maioria já conhece, o `var` serve para tornar a variável local, acessível apenas ao seu escopo de função, pois se você declarar uma variável sem nenhum modificador ela acaba tendo sua abrangência de escopo como uma variável global, ou seja você poderá obter a referência dela dentro de qualquer escopo.

#### Exemplo

```
z = 0;

function foo(){
  var x = 3;
  console.log(x); //resultará 3.
  console.log(z); //resultará 0.
  console.log(y); //aqui a variável y do escopo de bar() não é accesível, por isso resultará undefined.
}

function bar(){
  var y = 4;
  console.log(y); //resultará 4.
  console.log(z); //resultará 0.
  console.log(x); //aqui a variável x do escopo de foo() não é accesível, por isso resultará undefined.
}

console.log(z); //resultará 0.
console.log(x); //aqui a variável x do escopo de foo() não é acessível e resultará em undefined.
console.log(y); //aqui a variável y do escopo de bar() não é acessível e resultará em undefined.
```

Como você pode compreender acima, a variável `z` não foi atribuida com o modificador `var` e acaba por ser acessível em qualquer contexto de execução, agora para as variáveis atribuidas com o modificador `var` ficam acessíveis apenas ao seu contexto de execução atual.

## Modificador `let`

Já o `let` faz com que o escopo da variável declara se abstenha ao bloco de código ou expressão onde ela foi declarada **apenas**.

#### Exemplo

```
function foo(){
  var x = 1;
  let y = 3;
  if (true){
    var x = 2;
    let y = 4;
    console.log(x); //Irá resultar 2.
    console.log(y); //Irá resultar 4.
  }
  console.log(x); //Irá resultar 2 porque o escopo do 'var' abrangiu toda a função foo().
  console.log(y); //Irá resultar 3 porque o escopo do 'let' abrangiu apenas o bloco, diferente da atribuição na expressão if.
}
```

Perceba que a atribuição da variável `y` para o valor `3` fora da expressão if só vale para o log que encontra-se fora da expressão if, já a atribuição da variável `y` para o valor `4` dentro da expressão if, só vale para o log que está dentro da expressão if. Isso da a entender que o `let` só declara uma variável para uso em seu bloco/expressão, por isso dentro da expressão if ele já não teve o mesmo contexto.

## Conclusão

A diferença entre `var` e `let` é apenas especificar o escopo da variável em questão.

#### Fontes/Referências:

- [MDN: var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- [MDN: let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 8):

Complementando a resposta dos amigos, sempre é bom você usar LET ao invés de VAR, para evitar o chamado hoisting, o que é isso ?

Em JavaScript, funções e variáveis são hoisted (ou "levados ao topo"). Hoisting é um comportamento do JavaScript de mover declarações para o topo de um escopo (o escopo global ou da função em que se encontra).

Isso significa que você é capaz de usar uma função ou variável antes mesmo de tê-las declaradas, ou em outras palavras: uma função ou variável podem ser declaradas depois de já terem sido utilizadas.

Então, para evitar eventuais bugs, usamos na maioria das vezes o let, e deixamos as globais com uma const recebendo determinado valor.

você pode ler mais na publicação deste cara, explica direitinho como funciona ambas as novas tecnologias inseridas pelo ES6

[Medium](https://medium.com/collabcode/javascript-e-suas-vari%C3%A1veis-var-let-e-const-b035b44c2dab)

Answer (score 7):

Criando uma variável com **let**, ela existirá somente no escopo em questão.
Se usar com o **var**, a variável fica acessível no restante do código.

Por exemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(let a in lista){
   console.log(lista[a]);
}

//Variavel a não existirá aqui após a execução do laço



lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
   for(var a in lista){
    console.log(lista[a]);
}

//Variável a continua acessível mesmo após a execução do laço de repetição
```