# Try/catch em JS

Tags: javascript, variáveis, exceção, escopo-de-variáveis

Possuo um *array* chamado `agenciasUri`, o qual formato os dados antes de inserir nele. Após isso, monto o JSON `jsonObj`para enviar uma requisição. O que achei estranho é que está funcionando corretamente.

Por que eu consigo acessar `agenciasUri`? Como funciona a visibilidade de uma variável dentro de um laço em JavaScript (ciclo de vida)?

```
$scope.salvar = function () {
        var agenciasSeparadas = $scope.opcoes + '';
        agenciasSeparadas = agenciasSeparadas.split(',');
        try {
            var agenciasUri = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listaAgencias.length; i++) {
                var json = $scope.listaAgencias[i];
                for (var k = 0; k < agenciasSeparadas.length; k++) {
                    if (json.nome == agenciasSeparadas[k]) {
                        agenciasUri.push(json._links.self.href);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }

        var jsonObj = {
            nome: $scope.nome,
            tipo: $scope.tipo,
            agencias: agenciasUri
        };



        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
        veiculosAPI.postVeiculo(jsonObj)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.nome = null;
                $scope.tipo = null;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
                alert("Erro ao salvar dados do veiculo!");
                alert(data + "\t" + JSON.stringify(data));
            });

    };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A questão é que o JavaScript tem o escopo de variáveis declarada com `var` local à função e não ao bloco de execução, como ocorre em outras linguagens. Este fenômeno é conhecido por [*hoisting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Então não importa onde você declare a variável, ela existirá em toda a função. Mas não fora dela.

Somente variáveis declaradas fora da função é que possuem escopo global ou pelo menos regional. Por regional entenda que uma variável pode ser acessível dentro da função onde ela foi declarada e dentro de funções contidas nesta função.

Com o EcmaScript 6 é possível usar o [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) que permite o uso de escopo de bloco, como o encontrado em outras linguagens. Mais detalhes sobre a diferença entre eles podem ser encontrados [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101).

A ideia do escopo do `var` não é ruim, o problema é que ela foi mal implementada. Se você declarar duas vezes a mesma variável dentro de uma função, em blocos diferentes, é aceito sem erros. Isto não deveria acontecer. Mas pela filosofia da linguagem a segunda declaração funciona normalmente como se fosse uma atribuição. Isto é confuso. Outro problema é que a variável existe mesmo que ela tenha sido declarada depois do seu uso.

Desta forma, o estilo "moderno" de programar é usar sempre que possível, e sempre é em navegadores modernos, o `let`. É uma pena que ainda não há suporte garantido em navegadores que estão em pleno uso (isso mudou desde essa resposta, quase não tem mais esse problema).

Ou seja, isto não é algo específico do `try-catch`, é válido para qualquer bloco.

Mais informações nessa [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/221800).