# Erro em código usando switch e new date

Tags: javascript, data, switch

Tentei fazer uma função que retornasse o dia da semana que estamos, através de um `switch` em JS, mas de alguma maneira, não aparece o resultado. Depurei todo o código, mas não encontrei o erro.

#### Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> treinando js e switch</title>
</head>
<body>
     <p id="demo"> </p>


    <script>
    var day;
       function dia(){
        switch (new Date().getDay()) {
            case 0:
               day = "Segunda";
               break;
             case 1:
               day = "Terça";
               break;
             case 2:
               day = "Quarta" ;
               break;
             case 3:
               day = "Quinta";
               break;
             case 4:
               day = "Sexta";
               break;
             case 5:
               day = "Sabado";
               break;
             case 6:
               day = "Domingo";
                break;
         };
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTLM = "hoje é "   + day;
  
    }
  

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O principal erro é que o 0 é Domingo, depois vem os outros dias. O início estava um pouco confuso também, a variável `day` estava declarada fora da função sem razão aparente. Este tipo de função fazendo tudo isto não é o jeito mais legal de fazer, apesar de funcionar.

```js
function dia() {
    var day;
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
      case 0:
        day = "Domingo";
        break;
      case 1:
        day = "Segunda";
        break;
      case 2:
        day = "Terça";
        break;
      case 3:
        day = "Quarta" ;
        break;
      case 4:
        day = "Quinta";
        break;
      case 5:
        day = "Sexta";
        break;
      case 6:
        day = "Sábado";
        break;
    };
    console.log("hoje é " + day); //mudei para facilitar o teste
}
dia();
```

Assim pode ficar melhor:

```js
function diaDaSemanaHoje() {
    return ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"][new Date().getDay()];
}
console.log("Hoje é " + diaDaSemanaHoje());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/WeekDayExtension.js).

Comment: Poderia explicar por que isso funciona?

Comment: @CleitonOliveira O que funciona?

Comment: @bigown , Agradecido demais pela resposta agil, então o erro fora começar pelo dia da semana, era o fato da variavel de estar fora da função? detalhe, realmente em array é mais legal, só que preciso treinar switch ....rsrsrsrs obrigado

Comment: A variável fora até deixa funcionar, mas não é correto. Funcionar != correto. Essa é uma das coisas mais importantes de se aprender. Variáveis devem ter escopo contido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171327/101

Comment: @bigown perdão por não ter esclarecido. Não entendi o motivo do return funcionar dessa forma. Basicamente é um [ ][ ], um com uma lista de strings e outro com o dia atual, mas não consegui entender como isso funciona. Poderia explicar?

Comment: @CleitonOliveira acho que a explicação vai ficar um pouco longa para um comentário, quer abrir uma pergunta nova sobre isso? Pode até citar a resposta aqui, colocar o exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Vê se ajuda:

```js
var arrDay = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];

console.log("Hoje é " + arrDay[new Date().getDay()]);
```