# Modo incomum de se usar uma função em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

[Esta resposta para uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171565/erro-em-c%C3%B3digo-usando-switch-e-new-data-javascript/171566?noredirect=1#comment353631) trouxe algo que eu não conhecia: um `return` com dois pares de colchetes`return[][]` em uma função, resolvendo um problema de maneira simples porém desconhecida para mim. A pergunta pedia o retorno do dia correto da semana, com uma lista de dias da semana em um `switch`:

```
<script>
var day;
   function dia(){
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0: day = "Segunda"; break;
         case 1: day = "Terça"; break;
         case 2: day = "Quarta"; break;
         case 3: day = "Quinta"; break;
         case 4: day = "Sexta";  break;
         case 5: day = "Sabado"; break;
         case 6: day = "Domingo"; break;
     };
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTLM = "hoje é "   + day;
}
</script>
```

A resposta veio em jquery, resolvendo o problema com poucas linhas de código:

```
function {
return ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"][new Date().getDay()];
}
console.log("Hoje é " + diaDaSemanaHoje());
```

Alguém poderia me explicar, por favor, por que e como isso funciona?

Comment: Dentro do return esta a ser declarado um array dos dias da semana `["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"]` e depois é selecionado a posição no array, É o mesmo que fazer `a = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"]` e depois return `a[new Date().getDay()]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, [isso não é jQuery, é JavaScript puro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101).

```
["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"][new Date().getDay()]
```

Isso é um [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114473/101) de um *array* e o acesso a um de seus elementos. Vamos fazer o que o Jack manda, vamos por partes:

```
["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"]
```

Essa parte é o literal que define o *array*. Ele possui 7 elementos e todos são *strings*. Cada um é posicionado em um índice começando em 0, portanto o último será o 6.

Se quisesse atribuir isso para uma variável poderia ser assim:

```
var array = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
```

Se quiser acessar o elemento 0 desse *array* poderia ser:

```
array[0]
```

Se eu não souber no momento da criação do código qual é o número do índice poderia usar uma variável que terá seu valor vindo de algum lugar:

```
array[x]
```

Ou poderia usar uma [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163079/101) , afinal uma variável não deixa de ser uma expressão:

```
array[new Date().getDay()]
```

Sabe-se que [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) retorna um número de 0 à 6, de acordo com o dia da semana. É exatamente o que precisamos como valor para o índice do *array* que criamos. A função está aplicada a um objeto que acabou de ser criado, e este objeto é a data de hoje. É o mesmo princípio da variável substituída por um literal. Ambos são expressões adequadas para o contexto. Veja de outra forma:

```
var data = new Date();
var diaSemana = data.getDay();
console.log(diaSemana);
```

Como não precisamos das variáveis, usamos:

```
console.log(new Date().getDay());
```

Mas pensa bem, pra que criar uma variável? [Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) são locais de armazenamento de valores em memória com um nome. Se eu preciso "calcular" um valor, mas não preciso armazená-lo em lugar algum ali, porque eu precisaria de uma variável? Sem a variável, eu posso usar apenas o literal, então no lugar do nome `array` eu posso usar o valor que define esse *array*, assim:

```
var diaDaSemana = new Date().getDay();
return ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"][diaDaSemana];
```

Mas mesmo essa variável `diaDaSemana` não é necessária, eu posso usar um literal, posso usar o valor direto:

```
return ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"][new Date().getDay()];
```

No caso daquela resposta esse valor é usado para retornar na função. Se a variável é só um nome para um valor, eu posso usar o valor diretamente no lugar no nome. veja se entender melhor da forma com variáveis desnecessárias:

```js
function diaDaSemanaHoje() {
    var array = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
    var hoje = new Date();
    var diaDaSemanaHoje = hoje.getDay();
    var textoDiaDaSemanaHoje = array[diaDaSemanaHoje];
    return textoDiaDaSemanaHoje;
}
console.log("Hoje é " + diaDaSemanaHoje());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/GetWeekday.js).

## É mágica?

Isso não tem nada de mágico. É o normal da linguagem, não precisou nada especial. Dentro da [especificação da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101) o que é coerente, linear, simétrico, é funcionar assim.

Que eu me lembre a única linguagem *mainstream* que não permitia isso era PHP e hoje permite.

O ideal para programar é entender o porquê de cada espaço, cada vírgula existente no código. Só quando se domina isto é que se aprendeu programar de verdade. Aí sabe fazer qualquer coisa. Antes e chegar neste ponto está apenas repetindo receitas de bolo já feitas antes por outras pessoas. Mesmo quando a receita é tão curta quando usar uma variável.

Em tudo que se escreve no código precisa saber porque está fazendo aquilo. Precisa entender o papel de cada *token* do código. E como ele pode ser substituído de acordo com as regras da linguagem, que por incrível que pareça, no básico, variam menos do que as pessoas imaginam.

Programar é juntar um monte de peça de Lego. Tem que saber **tudo** sobre cada peça.

Bom ter perguntando :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var a=[1,2];
console.log(a[1]);
```

Igual:

```
console.log([1,2][1]);
```

simplesmente a array é definido e acedido na mesma linha!