# posso declarar uma variavel em javascript assim $variavel?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

posso declarar uma variável em javascript dessa forma `$variável` ?
 Caso não. O que seria essa sintaxe ?

Comment: Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171327, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resumidamente, pode, desde que não precise de proteção.

As variáveis em Javascript devem atender aos seguintes requisitos:

- devem ser compostas por letras, números, cifrão (`$`) ou underscore (`_`)
- não devem iniciar com números

  Além disso, ainda há a questão do escopo:
- variáveis declaradas sem `var` ou `let` possuem escopo "superglobal", por vezes até quebrando as regras do sistema e sendo usadas antes mesmo de serem declaradas
- variáveis declaradas com `var` possuem escopo global, e podem ser usadas em qualquer lugar do script após serem inicializadas
- variáveis declaradas com `let` possuem escopo de bloco, ou seja, fora do seu bloco de código, elas simplesmente não existem. São o tipo mais recomendável, tendo em vista que evitam erros de utilização e permitem limpar o espaço vago na memória
- variáveis do tipo `const` possuem escopo global e não podem ser modificadas após a criação (ideal pra aquele `const API = "192.168.10.12:8080/api/data"` que vai ser usado em 100% do código)

Em resumo, o que você fez foi simplesmente declarar uma variável superglobal.

Answer (score 4):

Não, essa é a sintaxe de criação de variáveis do PHP, no JavaScript declaramos variáveis usando `var`, `let` ou `const`, seguido do nome, e o valor:

`var exemplo = "valor"`

Lógico que o valor é opcional, no exemplo que você deu (`$variável`) no JavaScript ficaria assim: `var variável` apenas (colocar ";" no final das expressões é opcional também).

Outra opção é que você viu uma variável superglobal. Variáveis superglobais e/ou globais são um grande problema no JavaScript (e em qualquer linguagem que não esteja pronta pra isso), usando `var`, `let` ou `const`, você deixa a variável local (se você declarar ela dentro de um escopo)

E por último, você pode ter visto também: `var $exemplo`, ou seja, o $ no nome da variável, e não sendo usado na declaração.

As variáveis podem ter o nome começado por "_" (underline), $, ou uma letra, e não podem começar com números. Você também pode ter visto uma variável que já foi criada sendo referenciada.

Comment: Mas eu ja vi em JavaScript essa sintaxe `$algumacoisa`. Pensei que poderia ser variavel da mesma forma que é no PHP. Vcs sabem o que poderia ser essa sintaxe ? Vi isso em JS ES6

Comment: Então provavelmente você viu: `var $exemplo`, ou seja, o `$` no nome da variável, e não sendo usado na declaração, as variáveis podem ter o nome começado por "_" (underline), $, ou uma letra, e não podem começar com números

Comment: Você também pode ter visto uma variável que já foi criada sendo referenciada

Comment: @yurishimoki podes acrescentar esses comentários como complemento à resposta? na verdade em JS podes declarar uma variável `$algumacoisa = 'foo';`, isso funciona na prática e a tua resposta não dá a entender isso nem porque seria "fora da norma" em JS.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido hehe, agora que eu fui lembrar vlw