# como achar se contem texto dentro de um array em javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu criei dois arrays, um com perguntas e outro com respostas.

Segue o modelo.

```
perguntas[0] = "que sao dinossauros";
respostas[0] = ["Constituem um grupo de diversos animais membros do clado Dinosauria"];

perguntas[1] = "tipos de dinossauros que existiram";
respostas[1] = ["Terópodes, Saurópodes, Ceratopsídeos, Ornitópodes, Estegossauros, Anquilossauros,Paquicefalossauros"];
```

Bem, eu preciso fazer com que eu achar se determinado texto, esteja contido nesse array, sabendo em que posição ele achou, para eu poder retornar uma resposta.

Eu tentei da seguinte forma.

```
 if( $.inArray(pergunta, perguntas[i]) !== -1 ){
                alert("encontrei");
            }else{
                alert("não encontrado");
            };
```

Assim ele funciona, porém eu preciso achar qual posição foi achada, para enviar um retorno respectivo.

Criei uma repetição para poder identificar em qual posição foi achada, porém nunca encontra o texto.

```
for(var i = 0; i < perguntas.length; i++){

            if( $.inArray(pergunta, perguntas[i]) !== -1 ){
                alert("encontrei");
            }else{
                alert("não encontrado");
            };
        }
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você está procurando pela pergunta, no caso, e precisa saber qual é o índice desta pergunta na lista?

Comment: Esqueci de colocar na observação que o usuário que digita a pergunta. Ai vamos dizer que o cara digita "tiranossauro", se ele achar o conteudo, preciso saber em qual indice foi achado

Comment: Ok, então o usuário digita uma palavra, você quer pesquisar qual é a pergunta que possui esta palavra e obter o índice desta na lista?

Comment: Quero verificar se a palavra esta contida no array. Se estiver, preciso saber em qual indice está, para poder retornar a resposta correspondente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para buscar pela pergunta e exibir a respectiva resposta, basta utilizar `indexOf` na lista de perguntas para obter a posição da pergunta da lista e exibir a respectiva resposta utilizado `respostas[index]`. Veja o exemplo:

```js
// Objetos de manipulação do DOM -------------------------------------------------------
const lista    = document.getElementById("perguntas"),
      pergunta = document.getElementById("pergunta"),
      resposta = document.getElementById("resposta"),
      button   = document.getElementById("perguntar");
      
// Lista de perguntas e respostas ------------------------------------------------------
const perguntas = [],
      respostas = [];

// Adiciona-se as perguntas e respostas ------------------------------------------------
perguntas.push("O que são dinossauros?");
respostas.push("Constituem um grupo de diversos animais membros do clado Dinosauria");

perguntas.push("Quais os tipos de dinossauros que existiram?");
respostas.push("Terópodes, Saurópodes, Ceratopsídeos, Ornitópodes, Estegossauros, Anquilossauros,Paquicefalossauros");

perguntas.push("Onde é que eu tô? Será que tô na alagoinha?");
respostas.push("Não, você está no Stack Overflow em Português.");

// Exibe as perguntas para o usuário ---------------------------------------------------
// Não é necessário para a resolução da pergunta, mas ajuda o usuário.
for (let i in perguntas)
{
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = perguntas[i];
  
  li.onclick = function (event) {
    pergunta.value = perguntas[i];
  }
  
  lista.appendChild(li);
}

// Evento de click do botão ------------------------------------------------------------
button.onclick = function (event) {

  // Procura a pergunta na lista de perguntas:
  let index = perguntas.indexOf(pergunta.value);
  
  // Se encontrar, exibe a resposta, caso contrário exibe a mensagem de erro:
  resposta.innerHTML = (index >= 0) ? respostas[index] : "Pergunta não encontrada";
};
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul id="perguntas"></ul>

<input id="pergunta" type="text">
<button type="button" id="perguntar">Perguntar</button>

<div id="resposta"><div>
```

Comment: Perfeito meu caro, obrigado

Comment: Lembrando que muito do que eu usei na resposta serviu apenas para criar um exemplo completo e verificável. A lógica para a solução do problema é bastante simples e pode ser adaptada para o seu contexto.

Comment: sim, com isso já da para adaptar perfeitamente ao que necessito

Comment: obs, o que é esse let?

Comment: É de qual versão do javascript?

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Pode ler sobre em [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando “let” e “var”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/5878)

Comment: boa, valeu, mas já resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 1):

Você pode percorrer o array de respostas usando `forEach` e salvar a posição quando encontrar:

```js
var perguntas = [],
  respostas = [];
perguntas[0] = "que sao dinossauros";
respostas[0] = "Constituem um grupo de diversos animais membros do clado Dinosauria";

perguntas[1] = "tipos de dinossauros que existiram";
respostas[1] = "Terópodes, Saurópodes, Ceratopsídeos, Ornitópodes, Estegossauros, Anquilossauros,Paquicefalossauros";

var respondido = "Anquilossauros";
var idx;
respostas.forEach(function(item, i) {
  if (item.indexOf(respondido) > -1) 
    idx = i;
});

if (idx) {
  console.log('A resposta está na posição: ' + idx);
}
```

Exemplifiquei uma resposta para a pergunta *tipos de dinossauros que existiram*.

Comment: Não é bem por ai que preciso.
Vamos dizer que o cara pergunte.

Que tipos de dinossauros existiram? Ai a resposta ta no resposta[1]. Ai queria retornar ele

Comment: Então por que o valor de `resposta[1]` é um array?

Comment: só ta separado por virgulas, mas não é array, ele ta dentro de aspas

Comment: Ele começa com colchetes

Comment: ignora isso então

Comment: só preciso achar em qual posição contem o que o cara digitar, nesse array de perguntas

Comment: Editei a resposta @gabrielfalieri