# Parâmetros em funções em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

Para que servem os parâmetros nas funções e qual a necessidade deles?

Não entendo qual a diferença entre ter ou não um parâmetro na função, por exemplo

#### Sem parâmetros:

```
var V = prompt("Enrte com o valor da tensão");
var R = prompt("Entre com o  valor da resistência");

function calcula() {
  var l = V / R;
  return l;
}

var corrente = calcula();
document.write("O valor da corrente é ", corrente, "A");
```

#### Com parâmetros:

```
var V = prompt("Enrte com o valor da tensão");
var R = prompt("Entre com o  valor da resistência");

function calcula(V,R) {
  var l = V / R;
  return l;
}

var corrente = calcula(V,R);
document.write("O valor da corrente é ", corrente, "A");
```

Se tem os mesmos resultados por que usar?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

É uma questão de [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Toda variável criada em um escopo está disponível para todos os escopos que estão aninhados neste escopo. Por isso o primeiro código funciona. Algumas variáveis são criadas com escopo global mesmo em escopos mais internos e isto é terrível e deve ser evitado, por isto sempre use [`var` ou `let`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101).

Se você chamar a função `calcula()` em outro escopo ela não funcionará. Só funciona neste caso porque mesmo com `var` neste caso a variável assume um escopo global (poderia ser regional, mas neste caso é global mesmo. Este tipo de escopo costuma ser problemático, e deve ser evitado, só deve ser usado quando é muito importante e com muito cuidado.

Perceba que estas variáveis `V` e `R` podem até ser mudadas dentro da função, e isto é algo perigoso. Em uma base de código mais complexa ter acesso à uma variável com esse nome que sequer é o que você deseja.

Considere que ambos os códigos estão errados. Eles funcionam, mas não é o ideal fazer assim. Pode até fazer, mas tem que saber muito bem o que está fazendo, quando não sabe é melhor seguir o caminho mais seguro. Este código deveria ser assim:

```js
function main() {
    var V = prompt("Entre com o valor da tensão");
    var R = prompt("Entre com o  valor da resistência");
    var corrente = calcula(V, R);
    document.write("O valor da corrente é ", corrente, "A");
}

function calcula(V, R) {
    return V / R;
}
main()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/tree/master/JavaScript/Syntax).

Agora experimenta fazer sem parâmetro:

```js
function main() {
    var V = prompt("Enrte com o valor da tensão");
    var R = prompt("Entre com o  valor da resistência");
    var corrente = calcula(V, R);
    document.write("O valor da corrente é ", corrente, "A");
}

function calcula() {
    return V / R;
}
main()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Escope2.js).

O escopo local das duas variáveis impede delas serem enxergadas na outra função.

Só porque funciona não quer dizer que está certo.

[image: Fiat 147 caindo aos pedaços circulando na rua]

Comment: Acho que deu pra entender, e essa imagem aí, realmente faz sentido KK, obrigado

Comment: Essa imagem já é quase trademark seu! :D
Acho que é uma das que mais evidencia o ponto bastante importante que fez de `funcionar != certo`

Answer (score 1):

Busque aprender sobre [escopo variável global e local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx).

Exemplo:

```
var a = 1; // Esta disponivel para a função A e B
function A(){
    var somenteA = 11; // Esta disponivel somente para a função A

    console.log(a); // Mostra o valor de a, 1
    console.log(somenteA); // Mostra o valor de *somenteA*, 11
}

function B(){
    var somenteB = 12; // Esta disponivel somente para a função B

    console.log(a); // Mostra o valor de a, 1
    console.log(somenteB); // Mostra o valor de *somenteB*, 12
    console.log(somenteA); // Não consegue acessar o valor de *somenteA* pq ela foi declarada dentro da *function A*
}
```

Uma maneira melhor de escrever o código:

```
function calcula(V,R) {
  return v/r;
}

document.write("O valor da corrente é ", calcula(5,5), "A");
```

Comment: Sobre escopo eu entendo o básico, o negócio era mais sobre os parâmetros mesmo, não sabia que tinha a ver com escopo

Comment: @SteveAlisson Algumas coisas são questão de prática, com o tempo vai ficando mais claro ;)

Comment: Até que ponto devo aprender Javascript? a ponto de conseguir desenvolver qualquer coisa? (Meu interesse é em website apenas, basicamente coisas visuais)

Comment: @SteveAlisson N se limite a isso, sempre esteja aberto a aprender mais ;)

Comment: Pode crer, estou sempre tentando aprender mais! obrigado pela ajuda, abraço!