# Parâmetro de uma função

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

Como o código rodou certinho se o parâmetro da função `experiencia` não tem o mesmo nome da variável `anosEstudo`. Como o JavaScript entende que são a mesma coisa?

```
<script>
        var anosEstudo = 1;

        function experiencia(anos) {
            if (anos <= 1) {
                return 'Iniciante';
            } else if (anos <= 3) {
                return 'Intermediário';
            } else if (anos <= 6) {
                return 'Avançado';
            } else {
                return 'Jedi Master';
            }
        }

        console.log(experiencia(anosEstudo));
    </script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não são a mesma coisa, são coisas completamente diferentes. Mesmo que tivesse o mesmo nome seriam coisas diferentes. Para entender mais sobre isso deve ver [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Provavelmente deve ler também [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). E deve seguir todos os *links* dessas respostas para aprender os conceitos de forma correta e não ficar só seguindo receitas de bolo, porque seguir receitas não é programar. Fez bem em perguntar, anda raro isso acontecer.

Quando chama uma função e passa um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) está desviando o fluxo de execução do código dentro da função e copiando os argumentos para os parâmetros da função.

Então nesse caso está copiando o valor que está na variável `anosEstudo` para a variável local dentro de `experiencia` que é chamada de `anos`.

A ideia é justamente isolar uma variável da outra. Mesmo que o parâmetro chamasse `anosEstudo` ainda seria outra variável e escopo diferente. Ainda bem. Imagina administrar um sistema com milhares ou milhões de variáveis onde todas são visíveis em todo lugar, e que se tivesse o mesmo nome fosse a mesma variável. Seria uma loucura, não dá.

A técnica mais usada em programação, que a maioria dos programadores ignoram, mesmo quando a aplicam sem perceber, é a Dividir para Conquistar. E isso vale pra tudo na vida, pra trabalhar, estudar, fazer qualquer atividade complexa. Não fazemos tudo junto. Isolar partes é fundamental, e elas devem conversar por poucos detalhes não pode haver um comunicação sem querer. Não pode pegar o dado sem ser o que deseja.

Vou dizer mais, o jeito que esse código está escrito passa uma ideia errada, o mais correto seria isto:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos <= 1) return 'Iniciante';
    else if (anos <= 3) return 'Intermediário';
    else if (anos <= 6) return 'Avançado';
    else return 'Jedi Master';
}

var anosEstudo = 1;
console.log(experiencia(anosEstudo));
```

Porque assim fica claro que a variável faz parte do algoritmo de baixo que é completamente isolado da função, por acaso as duas coisas estão juntas, mas poderiam não estar.

Do jeito que está na pergunta parece que a variável `anos Estudo` precisa existir antes da função para funcionar, mas não é o caso, ela não é enxergada pela função, mesmo tendo sido declarada antes, poderia estar até em outro arquivo. A comunicação do dado poderia ser por cópia.

Na verdade a variável nem é necessária porque o que vale é o valor:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos <= 1) return 'Iniciante';
    else if (anos <= 3) return 'Intermediário';
    else if (anos <= 6) return 'Avançado';
    else return 'Jedi Master';
}

console.log(experiencia(1));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Escope3.js).

Há casos que precisa de uma variável, mas isso é mais avançado e não vou falar aqui.

Agora vou mostrar algo que funciona, mas não deve fazer:

```js
function experiencia() {
    if (anos <= 1) return 'Iniciante';
    else if (anos <= 3) return 'Intermediário';
    else if (anos <= 6) return 'Avançado';
    else return 'Jedi Master';
}

var anos = 1;
console.log(experiencia());
```

Sim, a variável externa pode ser vista pela função (desde que seja no mesmo local onde está a função, nesse caso é o escopo global), e isso chega ser quase um erro da linguagem. Nem tanto, porque tem situação que isso é interessante. Mas não nesse caso. A não ser por um conceito de *closure* que não vou falar aqui, não faça código de função que dependa de uma informação externa sem a comunicação por parâmetro. Isso quebra o isolamento da função e normalmente não é o que quer fazer, mesmo que pareça mais fácil é complicado administrar em códigos um pouco maiores.

Acho útil ler [Parâmetros em funções em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284804/101).

Comment: Obrigado! Sobre a parte de o código passar uma ideia errada: de fato, no original ele está do jeito que você colocou, fui eu quem alterei, por ignorância mesmo. Mas, não entendi qual seria o problema em colocar a variável antes. Se pudesse me clarear mais, eu agradeceria muito! Mas desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Beleza, são coisas completamente diferentes. Então como eu informo que o valor de anosEstudo é 1 e isso é reconhecido na função experiencia? Claro, sei que tem algo a ver com a ultima linha do código, onde chamo a função com o parâmetro anosEstudo, mas não consigo compreender como isso funciona e o que está acontecendo alí.

Comment: Não é problema, mas passa ideia errada. Agora pelo comentário, parece que usou mas não sabe o que é passagem de parâmetro. Leu tudo na resposta? Seguiu os *links*. Se ainda não souber provavelmente está aprendendo do jeito errado e está pulando passos, isso não dá certo, eu sugeriria pegar coisas mais simples antes, e aprender de forma estruturada, não tem como fazer o teto de uma casa sem alicerce.

Comment: Cara, valeu pelas dicas, fui estudar mais como voce falou e agora entendi muito mais! Mas aí surgiu mais uma duvida: se eu quisesse utilizar a mesma variável anosEstudo como parâmetro da função, eu poderia sem problemas? Ou estaria errado?

Comment: Acho que não entendeu. Ou eu não entendo.