# Por que recomendam usar let se a maioria dos plugins/aplicativos/libraries ainda usam var?

Tags: javascript, html

Por que recomendam usar `let` se a maioria dos `plugins/aplicativos/libraries` ainda usam `var`? Devo começar a adotar em minhas aplicações usar ou não?
Alguns exemplo de plugins/aplicativos/libraries que ainda não adotaram `let`:

[Jquery 3.3.1 CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)

[Angular 1.7.0 CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular-animate.min.js)

[React](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js)

Comment: "Por que recomendam usar `let`"... Fonte?

Comment: `let` e `var` apesar de servirem para declarar uma variável, tem um comportamento um pouco diferente: [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) e [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: Provável dup https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101