# Explicação do funcionamento de declaração de variável de loop For/In

Tags: javascript, variáveis, for, declaração-de-variável

```js
var meusDados = {
    nome: 'Bruno Coelho',
    email: 'brunobcoelho.94@gmail.com',
    idade: 23
};
var dados;
for(dados in meusDados){
    console.log(meusDados[dados]);
}
```

Por que declarar a variável dados antes do for/in é necessário?

Comment: Use `for(let dados...` porque é sempre melhor evitar escopo global. Mas o `let` pode não ter suporte em navegadores mais antigos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque se não declarar, onde irá armazenar o conteúdo durante o laço? A variável precisa existir para receber o valor. Mas não precisa ser necessariamente antes do laço; pode ser dentro dele também, o que, particularmente, acho mais legível.

```js
var meusDados = {
    nome: 'Bruno Coelho',
    email: 'brunobcoelho.94@gmail.com',
    idade: 23
};

for(var dados in meusDados){
    console.log(meusDados[dados]);
}

// Perceba que dados continua existindo fora do laço
console.log(dados);
```

Coloquei um `console.log` ao final mostrando que a variável `dados` continua existindo mesmo fora do laço. Dependendo do seu gosto, pode achar que isso polui o escopo global, pois uma variável que é utilizada em apenas um local específico continua existindo fora dele. Se assim for e deseja evitar tal ocorrência, pode utilizar o `let`:

```js
const meusDados = {
    nome: 'Bruno Coelho',
    email: 'brunobcoelho.94@gmail.com',
    idade: 23
};

for(let dados in meusDados){
    console.log(meusDados[dados]);
}

// Perceba que dados NÃO continua existindo fora do laço
console.log(dados);
```

[Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando let e var?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/5878)

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa, pode ser dentro do laço, é até o ideal:

```js
var meusDados = {
    nome: 'Bruno Coelho',
    email: 'brunobcoelho.94@gmail.com',
    idade: 23
};
for (var dados in meusDados) {
    console.log(meusDados[dados]);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Traverse.js).