# Fazer consulta com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho os seguintes objetos abaixo e preciso verificar quais candidatos atendem a vaga solicitada.

```
var vaga = {"language":"javascript","courses":["information systems","programming"]}

var candidatos = 
[
{"name":"luis","course":"programming","languages":["c","javascypt"]},{"name":"ana","course":"information systems","languages": "php","javascript","java"]},{"name":"pedro","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","java"]},{"name":"paulo","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","php","java"]},
{"name":"barbara","course":"information systems","languages":["php","javascript"]},
{"name":"camila","course":"programming","languages":["java","javascript"]},{"name":"cesar","course":"fashion","languages":["java","javascript","c"]},{"name":"cleber","course":"programming","languages":["reggae","javascript","dogs","football cards"]},{"name":"bruno","course":"programming","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"]},
{"name":"joana","course":"web design","languages":["java","javascript","c"]}
]
```

Para isso, criei a função abaixo que retorna um array com todos os candidatos, porém, queria fazer isso utilizando `filter()`, `map()` e `reduce()`, mas não sei como.

```
function retornaCandidatos(vaga, candidatos) {
    var x = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < candidatos.length ; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < vaga.courses.length; j++){
            if(candidatos[i].course === oportunidade.courses[j]){
                for(var k = 0; k < candidatos[i].languages.length; k++){
                    if(vaga.language === candidatos[i].languages[k]){
                        x.push(candidatos[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Está tendo algum problema? Isto É EcmaScript. Algum motivo pra trocar uma rotina que acredito esteja funcionando bem, você conhece e é eficiente por outra que você desconhece e é ineficiente?

Comment: De onde vem **oportunidade.courses**?

Comment: @Maniero acho que deve ser por questões de estudos mesmo, acho esse por esse *script * ser de certa forma simples, talvez ele tenha feito um curso antigo e quer se atualizar.

Comment: @Maniero, na verdade isso era um exercício que eu precisava fazer, porém não podia utilizar o for, então estava procurando uma forma de fazer isso utilizando filter() ou map().

Comment: @Luis geralmente exercícios que proíbem usar `for` pedem para usar outro controle de fluxo, ou seja, reduzir a abstração e não aumentar. O exercício deixava isso claro? Se não deixava, o exercício é falho.

Comment: @Maniero, não deixava claro, apenas dizia para utilizar filter(), map() ou reduce()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, segue resposta usando função nativa "filter" como solicitado. Fica mais elegante e mais fácil de entender. Obs: seu array de candidatos tinha um erro de sintaxe que corrigi.

```js
var vaga = { "language": "javascript", "courses": ["information systems", "programming"] };

        var candidatos =
                [{ "name": "luis", "course": "programming", "languages": ["c", "javascypt"] },
                { "name": "ana", "course": "information systems", "languages": ["php", "javascript", "java"] },
                { "name": "pedro", "course": "programming", "languages": ["javascript", "java"] },
                { "name": "paulo", "course": "programming", "languages": ["javascript", "php", "java"] },
                { "name": "barbara", "course": "information systems", "languages": ["php", "javascript"] },
                { "name": "camila", "course": "programming", "languages": ["java", "javascript"] },
                { "name": "cesar", "course": "fashion", "languages": ["java", "javascript", "c"] },
                { "name": "cleber", "course": "programming", "languages": ["reggae", "javascript", "dogs", "football cards"] },
                { "name": "bruno", "course": "programming", "languages": ["regex", "javascript", "perl", "go", "java"] },
                { "name": "joana", "course": "web design", "languages": ["java", "javascript", "c"] }];



        let retornaCandidatos = candidatos.filter(item => {
                if ((item.course == vaga.courses[0] || item.course == vaga.courses[1]) &&
                        item.languages.filter(item2 => {
                                if (item2 == vaga.language)
                                        return true;
                        }))
                        return item;
        });

        console.log(retornaCandidatos);
```

Comment: Adjair Costa, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tudo bem?

Eu faria da seguinte forma

```js
let vaga = {"language":"javascript","courses":["information systems","programming"]}

let candidatos = [
  {"name":"luis","course":"programming","languages":["c","javascypt"]},
  {"name":"ana","course":"information systems","languages": ["php","javascript","java"]},
  {"name":"pedro","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","java"]},
  {"name":"paulo","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","php","java"]},
  {"name":"barbara","course":"information systems","languages":["php","javascript"]},
  {"name":"camila","course":"programming","languages":["java","javascript"]},
  {"name":"cesar","course":"fashion","languages":["java","javascript","c"]},
  {"name":"cleber","course":"programming","languages":["reggae","javascript","dogs","football cards"]},
  {"name":"bruno","course":"programming","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"]},
  {"name":"joana","course":"web design","languages":["java","javascript","c"]}
]

const retornaCandidatos = (vaga, candidatos) => {
  return candidatos.filter(candidato => {
    return candidato.languages.some(lang => vaga === lang)
  })
}

let aprovados = retornaCandidatos('php', candidatos)

console.log('Aprovados: ', aprovados)
```

Resumo das mudanças feitas no código:

Onde você colocava `var` eu troquei por `let`, nas novas versões do **EcmaScript** também temos disponível o `const`, talvez ele se encaixe melhor em alguma situação para você, inclusive poderia ser usado nesse caso.

A diferença nessa questão está principalmente no **escopo**, você pode ver mais [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-vari%C3%A1veis-usando-let-e-var), mas de forma resumida e rude o `var` tem escopo *global* ou de *função*, enquanto o `let` tem escopo "local", o `const` por sua vez é similar ao `let`, porém é usado para definir constantes.

A segunda mudança principal foi na forma de declarar a função, para isso eu usei **arrow function** , você pode ver mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Novamente de forma resumida e rude, é uma forma mais simplificada de declarar funções.

E na função eu usei dois métodos nativos bem usados nos dias de hoje. O `filter` e o `some`.

Mais uma vez de forma resumida e rude, `filter` retorna o objeto do array em que alguma condição se satisfaz, saiba mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), e o `some` se algum item do array se satisfaz ele retorna `true`, caso contrário `false`, você pode ver mais sobre ele [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

**Bônus**
Se você quiser algo mais dinâmico, como por exemplo, que vá filtrando os candidatos enquanto alguém digita em um *input*, você poderia criar um `RegExp` (**Expressão Regular**) simples. E implementar da seguinte forma.

```js
let vaga = {"language":"javascript","courses":["information systems","programming"]}

let candidatos = [
  {"name":"luis","course":"programming","languages":["c","javascypt"]},
  {"name":"ana","course":"information systems","languages": ["php","javascript","java"]},
  {"name":"pedro","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","java"]},
  {"name":"paulo","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","php","java"]},
  {"name":"barbara","course":"information systems","languages":["php","javascript"]},
  {"name":"camila","course":"programming","languages":["java","javascript"]},
  {"name":"cesar","course":"fashion","languages":["java","javascript","c"]},
  {"name":"cleber","course":"programming","languages":["reggae","javascript","dogs","football cards"]},
  {"name":"bruno","course":"programming","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"]},
  {"name":"joana","course":"web design","languages":["java","javascript","c"]}
]

const retornaCandidatos = (vaga, candidatos) => {
  let exp = new RegExp(vaga.trim(), 'i')

  return candidatos.filter(candidato => {
    return candidato.languages.some(lang => exp.test(lang))
  })
}


let aprovados = retornaCandidatos('java', candidatos)

console.log('Aprovados: ', aprovados)
```

Nesse caso ele irá retornar programadores *java* e *javascript*, pois com esse **RegExp**, ele **não** irá **diferenciar maiúscula de minusculas** e ainda não irá importar se a palavra buscada está no *inicio, meio* ou *fim* da string, basta que contenha aquele trecho para ele retornar. Lembrando isso seria útil em uma pesquisa dinâmica, talvez não seja o seu caso.

Comment: Eduardo Ribeiro, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Precisando, estamos aqui para ajudar :D

Answer (score 1):

Talvez essa modificação na função lhe ajude, ficou bem menor e, na minha opinião bem mais fácil de entender:

```js
function retornaCandidatos(vaga, candidatos) {
        var x = 
        candidatos.filter(function(candidato){

           //Retorna true caso o a vaga.language exista na lista de linguagens do candidato e o curso feito pelo candidato estiver na lista de cursos da vaga
           //DICA: Caso queira que os candidatos no array só precise atender uma das condições, basta trocar o and(&&) por or(||)

      return candidato.languages.indexOf(vaga.language) > -1 && vaga.courses.indexOf(candidato.course) > -1
     })
        return x;
    }
    var vaga = {"language":"javascript","courses":["information systems","programming"]}
    
    var candidatos = 
    [
    {"name":"luis","course":"programming","languages":["c","javascypt"]},{"name":"ana","course":"information systems","languages": [ "php","javascript","java"]},{"name":"pedro","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","java"]},{"name":"paulo","course":"programming","languages":["javascript","php","java"]},
    {"name":"barbara","course":"information systems","languages":["php","javascript"]},
    {"name":"camila","course":"programming","languages":["java","javascript"]},{"name":"cesar","course":"fashion","languages":["java","javascript","c"]}, {"name":"cleber","course":"programming","languages":["reggae","javascript","dogs","football cards"]},{"name":"bruno","course":"programming","languages":["regex","javascript","perl","go","java"]},
    {"name":"joana","course":"web design","languages":["java","javascript","c"]}
    ];
    console.log(retornaCandidatos(vaga, candidatos))
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Comment: edson alves, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

quero agradecer a todos que me mostraram soluções para a minha pergunta, era isso mesmo que eu precisava, uma forma de percorrer array sem a utilização de laço "for", somente utilizando filter() ou map().