# Como colocar parênteses ou colchetes em expressões regulares em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Se faço algo como:

```
var word='carro';
var re = RegExp( '\\b'+word+'\\b','g' );
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas o que segue:

```
var word='[';
var re = RegExp( '\\b'+word+'\\b','g' );
```

Retorna:

> Invalid regular expression: /\b[\b/: Unterminated character class

Como posso passar parênteses ou colchetes para a expressão regular sem erros?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basta escapar o caractere com `\`. Só lembrando que dentro de uma string, o próprio caractere `\` [deve ser escrito como `\\`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation):

```js
let word = '\\[';
let re = RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'g');
console.log(re);  // imprime "/\b\[\b/g"
```

Isso acontece porque parênteses e colchetes são [caracteres que possuem significados especiais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) em regex. Se você quiser que eles "percam seus poderes" e sejam interpretados como os próprios caracteres, deve escapá-los com `\`.

No caso dos colchetes, eles definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a`, **ou** a letra `b`, **ou** a letra `c`" (somente uma delas). Se uma regex possui um `[`, deve ter o `]` correspondente.

Quando você não fez o *escape*, o resultado foi um `[` sem o fechamento correspondente (o caractere `]`) e isso dá erro, já que é uma expressão mal formada.

Usando o *escape*, ele é interpretado como o próprio caractere `[`, sem significado especial (e por isso não precisa ter o `]` correspondente), e aí funciona.

---

Com parênteses é a mesma coisa:

```js
let word = '\\(';
let re = RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'g');
console.log(re);  // imprime "/\b\(\b/g"
```

De maneira similar aos colchetes, os parênteses [possuem sua função](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) em regex: servem para agrupar uma sub-expressão e também formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). Por isso um `(` deve ter o `)` correspondente.

Mas usando o *escape*, ele passa a ser interpretado como um caractere comum, e por isso não precisa do respectivo fechamento.

---

O *escape* funciona para qualquer outro caractere que possui significado especial em regex, como o ponto (`.`), que significa "qualquer caractere", o `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", entre outros (todos citados [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)).

Um detalhe a se atentar é que nem sempre a expressão sem *escape* dará erro (como aconteceu com os colchetes e parênteses), mas acabará gerando uma regex diferente. Ex:

```js
// usando o "+" sem escape
let word = 'a+b';
let re = RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'g');
console.log(re);  // imprime "/\ba+b\b/g"

// usando o "+" com escape
word = 'a\\+b';
re = RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'g');
console.log(re);  // imprime "/\ba\+b\b/g"
```

A primeira regex é `/\ba+b\b/g`. No caso, temos `a+b`, que significa "uma ou mais letras `a`, seguido de uma letra `b`" ([exemplo desta regex funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/Ed4tcR/1/)).

Já a segunda regex é `/\ba\+b\b/g`. Como agora o `+` está escapado, ele não significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" e é interpretado apenas como o próprio caractere `+`. Por isso o trecho `a\+b` significa "a letra `a`, seguido do caractere `+`, seguido da letra `b`" ([exemplo desta regex funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/BymWgI/1/)).

---

<sup>Repare que usei `let` em vez de `var` para declarar as variáveis. Se não conhecia e ficou curioso, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052) para entender a diferença.</sup>