# Dúvida sobre declaração de variáveis

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável

Olá!

Antes de abrir essa pergunta, pesquisei para saber se tinha alguma similar aberta, mas não consegui resolver minha dúvida. Caso haja uma e você possa me disponibilizar o link, agradeço.

Eu não sei muita coisa ainda, estou aprendendo. No momento, estou estudando 'Browser Object Models' e num curso que estou fazendo e estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Qual a diferença entre essa atribuição/declaração:

```
function abrirPopUp() {
            janela = window.open('http://google.com', 'nova_janela', 'width=200, height=100');
        }
```

E essa aqui embaixo?

```
 function abrirPopUp() {
                var janela = window.open('http://google.com', 'nova_janela', 'width=200, height=100');
            }
```

Na primeira forma, tudo acontece como deveria. Na segunda, porém, não tenho resultado. Vou colocar todo o código aqui embaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <script>

            function abrirPopUp() {
                var janela = window.open('http://google.com', 'nova_janela', 'width=200, height=100');
            }

            function fecharPopUp() {
                janela.close();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="abrirPopUp();">Abrir janela</button>
        <button onclick="fecharPopUp();">Fechar janela</button>
        <button onclick="window.print();">Imprimir Página</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tentei ser o mais claro possível.

Desde já, muito obrigado pela força.

EDIT1: O problema acontece quando faço uso do método close do BOM. Na primeira declaração, tudo funciona normalmente. Na segunda, não.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, jezq!

Eu não tenho experiência com Javascript, mas até onde sei, em

```
function abrirPopUp() {
   janela = ...;
}
```

A variável `janela` é global o que significa que ela é acessível em qualquer parte do seu código. Já em

```
function abrirPopUp() {
   var janela = ...;
}
```

A variável é local, significando que ela é acessível apenas dentro da função em que foi declarada. Para que a função responsável pelo fechamento consiga acessar a variável, declare ela de forma global.

Comment: Boa noite, Ivan. Muito obrigado pela resposta! Nem passou pela minha cabeça esse conceito de global e local... nossa!

Comment: Fico feliz em lhe ajudar =) Se possível, marque minha resposta como correta caso seu problema tenha sido realmente resolvido. Boa noite