# Dúvida sobre closures, função dentro de loop

Tags: javascript, variáveis, for, closures

Estou estudando sobre *closures* no Javascript usando como base o livro "You Don't Know Js" do Kyle Simpson.

Eu entendi o conceito de *closure*, que ele consegue "segurar" a referência ao escopo léxico fora da função e mesmo depois daquela função ter sido executada, e como existe uma referência pra ela o *garbage collector* não a remove.

Só que em uma parte do livro ele dá um exemplo que me *bugou*, é sobre um `setTimeout()` dentro de um *loop*.

```
for (var index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(index)
    }, 1000);

}
```

A saída disso é: `"4 4 4 4"`

Não consigo entender porque não exibe `"0 1 2 3"`, em tese, a variável `index` não seria redefinida/sobrescrita em cada iteração como normalmente funcionaria?

Tanto é que se eu usar o `let` ao invés de `var` o código funciona .

Comment: Só é preciso tomar cuidado com a original porque as respostas lá não consideram a evolução do JS.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Vou tentar ser muito detalhado porque em comentário foi dito pelo AP que não entendia a explicação inicial. E vou explicar porque realmente ocorre, não vou falar um coisa que não mostra de fato o motivo disto acontecer porque seria algo como "é assim e pronto" que foi o que o AP conclui, um dos motivos da pergunta estar sendo feita é que o livro usado que se propõe explicar JS em pontos obscuros não deixou claro o motivo disto acontecer. Eu tentei deixar o mais claro possível, se não serviu ao AP pelo menos pode servir a outras pessoas. Depois procurando *links* percebi que isso até já foi respondido.</sub>

Funciona justamente porque ele guarda uma referência. Sabe o que é uma referência? Se não entender isso não vai entender a explicação. Falo em referência porque é o que a pergunta falou. Eu poderia falar de escopo, que é algo colateral ao assunto se a pergunta falasse em escopo e fosse mais importante que entender a referência.

Uma [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) é um valor endereçando um local onde ele tem um outro valor, então no contexto geral da programação (pode ser diferente em contextos específicos) é sempre um endereço de memória onde tem um valor. É uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

A primeira coisa que precisa entender sobre *closures* é que elas são [funções anônimas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101) que não são executadas até serem invocadas, o que está vendo aí é uma definição dela, não sua execução, não é chamada, a execução ocorrerá internamente dentro da `setTimeout()` no seu exemplo, no momento oportuno. Esquece a ideia que a função está sendo executada aí, você não está vendo sua execução, ela está escondida de você.

Outro ponto importante é que o `setTimeout()` nada tem a ver com a questão, ele apenas está usando um mecanismo de *callback*, algo comum em funções anônimas que possuem *closures* ou não.

Então este código está criando 4 *closures* diferentes, uma em cada passagem do laço, todas as 4 tem uma **referência** para o mesmo endereço da [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) `index` (caso não entenda o que é uma variável é importante ler esse *link*), note que não tem o **valor** de `index` no momento da criação desta *closure*, em uma referência, são coisas diferentes. Podemos concluir que os 4 valores que entrarão nessas *closures* são o mesmo, ou seja, os 4 serão o endereço da variável `index`, afinal o endereço onde está a variável `index` está não muda em cada passagem pelo laço.

Depois que o laço acaba, e ele acaba conforme a condição (o AP demonstrou não entender porque ele acaba), ou seja, `index` não é menor ou igual a 3, portanto ela vale 4 (isto é condição básica, só acaba quando a condição se torna falsa, e para se tornar falsa ela não pode ter mais o valor que a fazia verdadeira, então ele não pode valor nem um valor menor que 3 nem o valor 3, isso só acontece quando ela se torna 4, se não entende isso faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101), que existe justamente pra entender o funcionamento do código), em algum momento pra frente (1 segundo pra frente no exemplo, note que todos executarão quase encavalados porque todos demoram o mesmo tempo) estes eventos configurados no `setTimeout()` através de *closures* serão executados com o valor que estiver na referência usada, ou seja usará o valor que está em `index`, **neste momento**, que já será (1 segundo) depois que já encerrou o laço, portanto tem o valor 4 em todas as execuções.

Quem sabe isto ajudará entender pelo menos a condição:

```js
for (var index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
    console.log(index); //varia de 0 até 3 porque esses valores dão condição verdadeira
    console.log(index <= 3);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(index)
    }, 1000);
}
console.log("fora do for");
console.log(index); //houve 4 incrementos chegando neste número
//quando começa em 0 e vai incrementando a única forma de dar falso aqui é chegando no 4
console.log(index <= 3);
console.log("1 segundo depois vai executar o abaixo");
//note que não tem código aqui, é o setTimeout() que vai chamar a função com closure
```

Não esquece de mandar executar os códigos para ver os resultados.

Existem algumas técnicas para solucionar isto. Uma delas é encapsular em uma função, esta funciona em qualquer versão do JS:

```js
for (var index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
    function timer(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i)
        }, 1000)
    };
    timer(index);
}
```

Outra técnica é usar o `let` (citado na pergunta) que faz com que a variável deixe de ser uma referência natural porque [a variável passar ser local ao bloco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101) (não esqueça de ler esse *link* que explica o funcionamento do `let`, é importante, lá eu falo de escopo), aí a referência passa ser criada no momento que está sendo capturada pela *closure*, então cada *closure* terá uma referência para uma "nova variável" que é criada só para isto, esta variável não existe no seu código, ela é interna da *closure* e o valor dela será o que está valendo no momento da criação da *closure*.

Note que sendo local não dá para demonstrar tão facilmente quando a variável fica falsa porque ela não existe mais fora do escopo (o `for`). O escopo é solução, não a explicação de porque dá aquele problema citado na pergunta. O AP não entendeu isso.

```js
for (let index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(index)
    }, 1000);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ClosureFor.js).

Esta técnica não era possível há alguns anos. Um dos motivos do `let` ter sido criado é justamente resolver essa questão e criar suas próprias referências, eles não podiam mudar a semântica da linguagem em algo que já existiam, eles criaram algo novo, assim a nova semântica seria *opt-in*.

Isto é explicado por algo chamado [*binding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) que é a forma como a variável vincula seu valor. O `var` faz isso de forma universal a sua existência e o `let` faz isso local ao contexto.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas eu entendo e não entendo nada ao mesmo tempo. como assim "4 sinalizações diferentes"?, também não entendi "não tem o valor de index no momento da criação desse sinal", e também não entendo como o valor pode ser 4 já que o loop só executa até i ser menor ou igual a 3, isso tem a ver com o setTimeout ser assincrono e o loop continua?

Comment: Eu tinha colocado no corpo da dúvida que já sabia que o let funcionava... Minha dúvida era o 4...

Comment: E isso não explica o que perguntou, o `let` é apenas a solução, não a explicação. O 4 será melhor entendido se fizer o teste de mesa.