# Remover elementos criados dentro de uma função

Tags: javascript

Estou começando nos estudos de Javascript e várias duvidas vem surgindo conforme vou fazendo exercícios, esse em específico eu não consegui achar um conteúdo em português que explicasse bem.

Seguinte, tenho dois botões: um que adiciona um item e outro que remove esse item adicionado. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo achar uma maneira de remover sempre o último item adicionado ao clicar no botão de remover. Só consegui fazer funcionar removendo todos os itens de uma vez.

```
<div class="adicionar-produtos">
<button id="remove-vip" class="btn-produtos"> - </button>
<button id="add-vip" class="btn-produtos">+</button>
</div>
```

Ao clicar no botão o item é adicionado aqui:

```
<div class="item-adicionado">
 <p class="item-adicionado-main"> </p>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var botao_adicionar_vip = document.querySelector("button#add-vip");
var containerItemAdicionado = document.querySelector(".item-adicionado-main");
var botao_remover_vip = document.querySelector("#remove-vip");



botao_adicionar_vip.onclick = function() {

item_vip = document.createElement("p");
item_vip_text = document.createTextNode("Item Vip 1");
item_vip.className = "teste1";
item_vip.appendChild(item_vip_text);
containerItemAdicionado.appendChild(item_vip);

};


botao_remover_vip.onclick = function() {
document.querySelectorAll('.teste1').forEach(e => e.remove());
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wjykgxdn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu `forEach` está removendo todos.

Pode fazer assim para remover o último:

```
botao_remover_vip.onclick = function() {
   const itens = document.querySelectorAll('.teste1');
   if(itens.length){
      itens[itens.length-1].remove();
   }
};
```

Primeiro cria uma variável `itens` que seleciona todos os elementos criados:

```
const itens = document.querySelectorAll('.teste1');
```

Depois um `if` para verificar se existe pelo menos um item:

```
if(itens.length){
```

Se existir, você remove o último, que é o tamanho da variável `itens` `-1`. O `querySelectorAll` cria um nodelist onde cada elemento possui um índice com base `0`, igual a uma array, onde o número de elementos no nodelist é igual ao tamanho total `-1`:

```
itens[itens.length-1].remove();
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
var botao_adicionar_vip = document.querySelector("button#add-vip");
var containerItemAdicionado = document.querySelector(".item-adicionado-main");
var botao_remover_vip = document.querySelector("#remove-vip");

botao_adicionar_vip.onclick = function() {

   item_vip = document.createElement("p");
   item_vip_text = document.createTextNode("Item Vip 1");
   item_vip.className = "teste1";
   item_vip.appendChild(item_vip_text);
   containerItemAdicionado.appendChild(item_vip);

};


botao_remover_vip.onclick = function() {
   const itens = document.querySelectorAll('.teste1');
   if(itens.length){
      itens[itens.length-1].remove();
   }
};
```

```html
<div class="adicionar-produtos">
<button id="remove-vip" class="btn-produtos"> - </button>
<button id="add-vip" class="btn-produtos">+</button>
</div>
<div class="item-adicionado">
 <p class="item-adicionado-main"> </p>
 </div>
```

Procure declarar suas variáveis com `var`, `let` ou `const` (dependendo do caso. Veja mais informações [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/8063)) para evitar variáveis globais. Por exemplo:

```
let item_vip = document.createElement("p");
```

Answer (score 4):

Você está removendo todos os elementos por causa deste excerto do seu código:

> ```js
> document.querySelectorAll('.teste1').forEach(e => e.remove());
> ```

Ele basicamente irá selecionar **todos** os elementos adicionados e iterar sobre cada um deles, removendo-os individualmente.

Você precisa selecionar o **último** elemento dentro do elemento `.teste1`. Existem diversas formas para selecionar o último elemento.

## Utilizar o pseudo-seletor [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.teste1 > *:last-child');

if (element) {
  element.remove();
}
```

Isso fará com que você selecione o *último filho* que estiver dentro do primeiro elemento encontrado com a classe `.classe1`. Para isso, utilizamos o pseudo-seletor `:last-child`.

Se o seu ambiente [suportar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility), você pode inclusive utilizar a nova sintaxe de [encadeamento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (*optional chaining*), introduzida na versão mais recente do ECMAScript:

```js
document.querySelector('.teste1 > *:last-child')?.remove();
```

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.remove');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const element = document.querySelector('.teste1 > *:last-child');
  
  if (element) {
    element.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="remove">Remover Último</button>

<div class="teste1">
  <div>Filho 01</div>
  <div>Filho 02</div>
  <div>Filho 03</div>
  <div>Filho 04</div>
</div>
```

## Utilizar a API [`ParentNode.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild)

Essa é uma API "nativa" do JavaScript. É mais antiga, o que dá um suporte maior para ambientes legados. É também um pouco mais simples, já que não são envolvidos pseudo-seletores CSS.

Veja:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.remove');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.teste1');
  const element = parent.lastElementChild;
  
  if (element) {
    element.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="remove">Remover Último</button>

<div class="teste1">
  <div>Filho 01</div>
  <div>Filho 02</div>
  <div>Filho 03</div>
  <div>Filho 04</div>
</div>
```

Se o ambiente suportar, você também pode fazer o uso da nova sintaxe de encadeamento opcional para evitar a declaração `if`.

## Obter todos os filhos e selecionar o último elemento do array

Por fim, você pode obter todos os filhos utilizando a API [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), que retorna um [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (um tipo de array, mas com algumas diferenças). A partir dessa coleção, basta obter o seu último elemento.

Assim:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.remove');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.teste1');
  const children = parent.children;
  const element = children[children.length - 1];
  
  if (element) {
    element.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="remove">Remover Último</button>

<div class="teste1">
  <div>Filho 01</div>
  <div>Filho 02</div>
  <div>Filho 03</div>
  <div>Filho 04</div>
</div>
```

Com certeza existem mais formas de se fazer isso, mas pararei por aqui. :)