# Erro ao converter string em valor numérico

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma string e preciso convertê-la em número, no caso preciso converter em um valor real, mas não estou conseguindo. Abaixo está um exemplo onde eu tento converter o conteúdo de uma string em número para que possam verificar.

```js
const valor = parseFloat("109,99").toFixed(2)
console.log(valor, typeof valor)
```

Além de não converter o valor em um número, o código também me retorna o valor errado pois era para retornar `109.99` ao invés de `109.00`.

Answer (score 6):

O que ocorre é que [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) aceita uma string em um formato numérico válido do JavaScript. No seu caso, a *string* é inválida, já que o separador da casa decimal é uma vírgula. Isso fará com que todos os caracteres depois dela sejam ignorados. No JavaScript, esse separador deve ser um ponto.

Então, antes de fazer o *parse* da string, você deve garantir que a vírgula seja trocada por um ponto:

```js
const valor = parseFloat("109,99".replace(',', '.'));
console.log(valor, typeof valor); // 109.99 "number"
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que para tornar um valor em um *float*, o separador do decimal deve ser sempre um ponto ao invés de uma vírgula.

Quando você tenta converter a sua string sem tratá-la adequadamente, o resultado é este:

```js
console.log(parseFloat("109,99")); // Output: 109
```

No código que você usava, o resultado vinha com zeros depois do ponto porque você estava utilizando o método [`toFixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp), que mostra os números depois do ponto decimal de um valor.

```js
console.log(parseFloat("5.4372").toFixed(2)) // Output: 5.44
```

O que você pode fazer então para solucionar o problema, é substituir a vírgula para um ponto com o método [`replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) antes da conversão.

Veja este exemplo abaixo:

```js
var valor = "109,99";
var novo_valor = parseFloat(valor.replace(",", "."));

console.log(novo_valor, "|", typeof novo_valor); // Output: 109.99 | number
```

Comment: Não esqueça de declarar as variáveis. ;)

Comment: Mania de Python kkk Mas colocar `var` ou não no escopo global não faz diferença né ?

Comment: Vi agora a edição no comentário. :) Em tese, `var` hoje em dia está caindo em desuso. `let` e `const` são preferíveis. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-vari%c3%a1veis-usando-let-e-var).