# Mostrar resultado do laço 'for' JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e estou tendo problema para mostrar na tela o laço dos números colocados dentro dos inputs.

```js
function contar(){
    var inicio = Number(document.getElementById('inicioNumero').value)
    var fim = Number(document.getElementById('fimNumero').value)
    var passo = Number(document.getElementById('passoNumero').value)
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    
    for(var i = 0; i <= fim; i+= passo){
      res+=(`=>${i}`)
    }
    document.getElementById('contar').innerText = res

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Super Contador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Vamos Contar
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            Início: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicioNumero">
        </div>

        <div>
            Fim: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="number" name="fim" id="fimNumero">
        </div>

        <div>
            Passo: &nbsp;<input type="number" name="passo" id="passoNumero">
        </div>

        <div id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" onclick="contar()">
        </div>
        <div id="res">Calcular:</div>
    </section>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tem alguns erros no seu código: 1) nessa linha `var res = document.getElementById('res')` está pegando o elemento, mas na linha `res+=(`=>${i}`)` está adicionando algo, que não pode se feito no elemento, acho que deseja o conteúdo, certo? então faltou pegar o conteúdo do div: `var res = document.getElementById('res').innerText` por exemplo. 2) depois do `for` está tentando usar um elemento que não existe no html, o "contar". Aqui não seria o elemento "res"? ou então crie o elemento com ID="contar"

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui alguns erros.

No **HTML** você possui uma tag `</script>` a mais.

No **JavaScript**:

- Opte sempre por usar o let, minha opinião esqueça que o `var` existe. Veja mais sobre isso [variáveis usando let e var](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-vari%c3%a1veis-usando-let-e-var)
- a variavel `res` (que alterei o nome para `lista`) não deve armazenar nenhum valor inicialmente.
- Seu laço `for` deve:

  - começar com o valor da variável `inicio`;
  - ir até o valor da variável `fim`;
  - e ser incrementando com valor da variável `passo`
- Depois o valor da variável `lista` deve ser inserido na div com id `res`

```js
function contar() {
    // Valor de inicio
    let inicio = Number(document.getElementById('inicioNumero').value);

    // Valor final
    let fim = Number(document.getElementById('fimNumero').value);

    // Valor do passo (valor que será incrementado)
    let passo = Number(document.getElementById('passoNumero').value);

    // Variável onde os valores serão armazenados.
    let lista = "";

    for (let i = inicio; i <= fim; i += passo) {
        lista += (` =>${i} `)
    }

    // Inserir valor da variável lista na div com id res
    document.getElementById('res').innerText += lista;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Super Contador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    Vamos Contar
</header>
<section>
    <div>
        Início: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicioNumero">
    </div>

    <div>
        Fim: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="number" name="fim" id="fimNumero">
    </div>

    <div>
        Passo: &nbsp;<input type="number" name="passo" id="passoNumero">
    </div>

    <div id="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular" onclick="contar()">
    </div>
    <div id="res">Calcular: </div>
</section>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```