# Pegar resultado de função e inserir em um Input type text (html)

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá, estou com um leve problema em meu código HTML e JS. Eu preciso inserir o resultado de uma função(JS) em um input(HTMl). Mas não estou conseguindo... Eu tentei dessa forma:

HTML:

```
<p>Preço USD$: <input type="text" id="preco"  ></p>
```

JS:

```
 function total(){
            var quantidade = Number(document.getElementById('cQtd'))
            var tot = quantidade * 500
            document.getElementById('preco').value = tot
        }
```

Não está funcionando o código acima...
Alguma ideia de como resolver tal problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só faltou o `.value` no seu código

Exemplo aplicado a uma lista suspensa:

```js
function total(){
    let quantidade = Number(document.getElementById('cQtd').value)
    let tot = quantidade * 500
    document.getElementById('preco').value = tot
   }
```

```html
<p>Preço USD$: <input type="text" id="preco"></p>

<p>Quantidade: 
<select id="cQtd" onchange="total()">
   <option>Quantidade</option>
   <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Em JavaScript, um objeto é uma entidade independente, com propriedades e tipos. Compare-o com uma xícara, por exemplo. Uma xícara é um objeto, com propriedades. Uma xícara tem uma cor, uma forma, peso, um material de composição, etc. Da mesma forma, objetos em JavaScript podem ter propriedades, que definem suas características.

**Utilizando a propriedade value**

Pensando em um controle HTML do tipo textbox, password, textarea ou select, poderemos utilizar a propriedade `value`, ela refere-se ao valor do campo.

Se não houver a necessidade de utilizar uma variável poderemos , então, acessar a propriedade diretamente, veja exemplo:

```
variavel = document.getElementById('cQtd').value
```

Caso contrário

```
quantidade = document.getElementById("nome-identificador");
```

Recuperando o valor:

```
variavel = quantidade.value
```

[**Objetos e propriedades**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)

[**document.getElementById()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando a query do elemento de maneira incorreta

```
document.getElementById('cQtd')
```

Esse código acima você apenas está recuperando e a variável do elemento DOM, e não o valor interno em si.

Para recuperar o valor númerico desse elemento, você precisa entender se ele é um input ou se o valor está como texto internamente (HTML interno)

Caso esteja como valor, você pode recuperar da seguinte forma:

```
var quantidade = Number(document.getElementById('cQtd').value)
```

Caso seja um elemento como um span e você quer recuperar o valor dentro dele, você pode utilizar isso aqui:

```
var quantidade = Number(document.getElementById('cQtd').innerText)
```

Exemplo do uso acima:

HTML

```
<span id="idSpan">123456</span>
```

JS

```
const valorDoSpan = Number(document.querySelector("#idSpan").innerText)
```

ou

```
const valorDoSpan = Number(document.getElementById("idSpan").innerText)
```

Pode estar ocorrendo também de existir mais de um elemento com o id preco e você estar alterando um outro elemento, porém, acredito que o mais provável seja a recuperação desse valor quantidade

OBS: Evite usar var, prefira usar o [**let** ou o **const**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-vari%C3%A1veis-usando-let-e-var/47170#47170) (dependendo da necessidade, claro)