# Variável definida com let/const não é "identificada" pelo this

Tags: javascript

Quando eu executo uma função direto do escopo global que faz referência à uma propriedade qualquer por meio do `this` usando `var` a variável é exibida de forma correta, porém quando eu declaro a variável com `let/const` o valor é `undefined`, por que isso ocorre? pensei que pode ser hoisting, mas eu executo a função após a variável já ter seu valor atribuido.

Exemplo:

```
function myFunc() {
   console.log(this.name)
}

var name = 'MEU NOME';
console.log(myFunc()) // MEU NOME;
```

--

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log(this.name)
}

let name = 'MEU NOME';
console.log(myFunc()) // undefined
```

Comment: O `this` deve ser utilizado para se referir a um contexto de execução, e não ao escopo da execução. Utilizar o `this` como mecanismo para acessar variáveis só é possível em algumas situações (que tendem a se tornar menos comuns com o avanço da linguagem).

Comment: Fora que o `this` pode ser modificado em _runtime_ utilizando métodos como `call` ou `apply`, o que torna essa abordagem extremamente pouco confiável e propensa a erros.

Comment: mas a variável não vira uma propriedade do objeto global?

Comment: o call-site da myFunc é o objeto global, logo o this seria o objeto global, por que não funciona com let?

Comment: A pergunta duplicata marcada responde isso — veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124190/69296). Em resumo, `var` e `let` têm comportamentos diferentes no que tange ao `this`. Reitero o que disse em meu comentário anterior: a função do `this` não é de referência ao **escopo**, mas sim ao **contexto**. É diferente. Tanto é que os novos recursos da linguagem (como `let`) deixam esse comportamento (antigo e com pouco sentido) para trás. Novamente insisto para que leia atentamente as perguntas marcadas como duplicata, uma vez que esses detalhes do JS são particularmente confusos.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você acessa "this.name", está na verdade acessando "window.name" (fora do contexto de um objeto, "this" é simplesmente a janela).

A palavra-chave "var" no escopo global adiciona a variável como atributo do objeto "window", enquanto a palavra-chave "let" não adiciona.

Há algumas outras diferenças entre let/const e var, descritas neste artigo: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/

Comment: por que o let/const não adicionam ao objeto global?

Comment: Acredito que a ideia é evitar que uma parte "distante" do programa, fora do contexto de onde a variável foi criada, mexa no seu conteúdo. O texto a seguir tem uma longa descrição das diferenças entre let e var, que vão além do caso concreto da sua pergunta: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/