# Passar objeto javascript por parâmetro no callback do ajax

Tags: javascript, funções, callback

Sei passar string:

```
onclick="popularEdicaoRetrofit(\''+data[i]+'\');"
```

e número:

```
var criarRetrofit = onclick="criarRetrofit('+data[i].idRetrofit+');"
```

Gostaria de saber como passo um objeto como parâmetro da função javascript.
O código é gerado no retorno do `callback` do AJAX.

O código é este na imagem abaixo (i é a posição do vetor que está sendo percorrido pelo for):

[image: trecho do código]

[image: funcao que irá receber o objeto]

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código do que você fez até o momento?

Comment: Felipe, por favor poste o código como texto (depois selecione e digite CTRL+K para formatar como código).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução é simples:

basta fazer assim:

```
onclick="popularEdicaoRetrofit(meuNamespace.data);"
```

Porém na volta do dado via Ajax faça isso:

```
var meuNamespace = meuNamespace || {};
meuNamespace.data = meuObjetoDataRecebidoDoServidorRemoto;
```

Nesta abordagem você está salvando os dados num objeto global que chamei de meuNamespace o que não é uma solução muito boa mas deve atender neste seu caso.

O ideal é rescrever o código para que ele fique mais robusto.

Answer (score 3):

Quando usas JavaScript *inline* no HTML dessa maneira ficas limitado. Seria melhor criares o objeto com JavaScript e juntares um oscultador de eventos onde podes passar o tipo de objeto que quiseres.

Repara que há aqui outro problema [que o bfavaretto reparou e eu não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72425/passar-objeto-javascript-por-parametro-no-callback-do-ajax/72448?noredirect=1#comment148498_72448). [Podes ler mais sobre o problema aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1238/129), mas no fundo esse `i` tem de ser guardado em memória para não ser sobreescrito pelo loop.

Assim sugiro algo do estilo:

```
var botaoMaisInformacoes = document.createElement('button');
(function(){
   var index = i;
    botaoMaisInformacoes.addEventListener('click', function(){
       popularEdicaoRetrofit(data[i]);
    });
})();
```

em vez de `onclick = "popularEdicaoRetrofit(\''+data[i]+'\');"`

**Contudo** se estás a usar Objetos que podem ser convertidos em JSON podes fazer

```
`onclick = "popularEdicaoRetrofit(\'' + JSON.stringify(data[i]) + '\');"`
```

Assim o objeto é passado como JSON/string e dentro da função só tens de fazer

```
var objeto = JSON.parse(dataString);
```

Comment: Eu *acho* que esse `data` só está disponível no callback do ajax, e que está sendo feito um loop nele. Então nenhuma dessas alternativas devem funcionar.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu também acho que sim, mas na primeira imagem da pergunta dá para ver o `ess:` que penso ser o resto da palavra "success" da callback. Ou seja esse código está a correr dentro da callback.

Comment: Nesse caso ainda precisaria de uma closure a mais pra evitar que `i` seja sempre o último valor.

Comment: @bfavaretto bem visto. Juntei isso para a minha sugestão de usar `addEventListener` para a outra o `JSON.stringify` já usa o `i` no lugar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite galera,
acabou que passei os parâmetros dessa maneira mais simples mesmo:

```
'<td align="center"><button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarRetrofit" onclick="popularEdicaoRetrofit('+data[i].idRetrofit+',\''+data[i].nomeRetrofit+'\'
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Felipe.

JavaScript não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, o que lhe permite receber qualquer objeto por parâmetro em sua função. Aparentemente você pode passar o próprio objeto `data`, porém verifique o formato desse objeto para ter certeza de que é o que você deseja.