# pq tá aparecendo 8 e não o número referente ao i?

Tags: javascript, array

```
<style>

.menu > li:hover .sub-menu{
    display:block;
}

</style>

<ul class="menu">
    <li>li 1</li>
    <li>li 2</li>
    <li>li 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>li 1</li>
            <li>li 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>li 4
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>li 1</li>
            <li>li 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var i;


    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].className == "sub-menu"){
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){

        if(y[i].childElementCount > 0){

            y[i].onclick=function(){
                console.log(x[i]);
            }

        }
    }



</script>
```

Comment: Acho que é uma duplicata desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1237/129, o problema é o mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repara que o `i` é uma variável que muda nesse escopo. Quando o `console.log(x[i]);` fôr corrido o `i` já recebeu outro valor porque estava dentro do `loop`.

Em ES6 (a nova versão do JavaScript) podes usar o `let` e o teu problema desaparece. O `let` cria uma variável no escopo desse bloco de código e portanto não interferindo com a variável global. 
Dá uma olhada aqui:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }, 500); 
  // dá sempre o numero certo, apesar de ser meio segundo depois
}
```

**exemplo online: http://www.es6fiddle.net/inyva5bh/**

Mas no teu exemplo, usando a versão que os browsers antigos usam, tens de passar esse `i` a uma função para ele ficar guardado com o valor que tinha no momento. Por exemplo:

```
function handler(index){
    return function(){
        console.log(x[index]);
    }
}
```

e dentro do `for` fazer assim:

```
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
    if(y[i].childElementCount > 0){
        y[i].addEventListener('click', handler(i));
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skuvhffg/1/

ou ainda, mais próximo do teu código:

```
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].childElementCount > 0) {
        (function(ind) {
            y[ind].onclick = function() {
                console.log(x[ind], ind, i);
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/skuvhffg/2/

Tens uma explicação deste problema e soluções alternativas [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1237/129) também.

Answer (score 4):

Como o @Sergio mencionou, o problema é similar ao desta pergunta:

> [Como usar o valor atual de uma variável numa função mais interna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1237/70)

Entretanto, talvez as soluções de lá não sejam adequadas para a sua solução específica.

Basicamente o que acontece é que quando o loop termina, o valor de `i` permanece no último depois do loop, e as funções chamadas vão utilizar o `i` atual (e não o `i` do momento do loop).

Uma alternativa seria guardar o valor individual no próprio elemento, e para isto o `dataset` é uma ótima solução:

```
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
  if(y[i].childElementCount > 0){
    y[i].dataset.myId = i;              // Gravamos o i no próprio elemento, como myId
    y[i].onclick=function(){
      console.log( this.dataset.myId ); // Recuperamos o valor com this.dataset.myId
    }
  }
}
```

Assim, para cada elemento do seu loop, estamos criando um atributo `myId` dentro do próprio elemento, e ao clicar no elemento, recuperamos seu valor individual com `this.dataset.myId`.

### Exemplo simplificado:

Seu código original gera um function único para os submenus, fiz uma versão individual por `li` apenas para ilustrar:

```js
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i;

for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
  y[i].dataset.myId = i;
  y[i].onclick = function(){
    alert( 'Voce clicou no li ' + this.dataset.myId );
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>li 0</li>
  <li>li 1</li>
  <li>li 2</li>
  <li>li 3</li>
  <li>li 4</li>
  <li>li 5</li>
  <li>li 6</li>
</ul>
```